# My comment was removed. Is it moderation activity?

Tags: discussion

As the title says, just now while I was trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370334/extenstion-methods-distinct-and-tolist-could-not-be-found) my comment was removed automatically. I have seen such activity before for being sarcastic. but trust me honestly this was really trying to answer, not rude, not offensive and nothing.

I don't remember what was the comment exactly but it was something like this "*accepting a first argument of type*? What type? Post the full error message. Don't trim the error messages as it will help us to find the problem. One thing is clear you can't use `Select(string)`. What are you trying to achieve?"

Why would someone remove this comment? Isn't this trying to help? I can guess some kind of flagging or moderator activity. but Why? If am violating any rules it would be good to know it so that I won't repeat it.

PS:If anybody having access to view deleted comments you're free to update it here.

Comment: The comment sounds obsolete, as the information you're requesting is in the question.

Comment: @Servy No, It looks like partial error message. Did you see the error message?

Comment: Yes I did, and I see no reason to believe it is not the complete error message.  About the only thing missing would be the line number, which won't be helpful to you.

Comment: The OP removed it himself.  Wait, [how does that even work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZjlyDbRVpg)?

Comment: @Servy Fine, At first it appeared to be partial but it is is full error message. I stand corrected. I thought they are two seperate messages. but there is no reason to remove my comment for this. Isn't it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The OP here or the OP there? Was it self deleted?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can't get you. You mean it is not possible to remove by OP but somehow he did? Or you mean I deleted it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Generally that would happen if some of the auto-removal criteria were met, such as words on the blacklist being in the post.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your comment was:

> accepting a first argument of type ? What type? error is not fully posted here. Don't trim the error messages. That is what going to help us to find the problem. One thing is clear Select(string) is wrong. what are you trying to achieve? –  Sriram Sakthivel 57 mins ago

This comment was flagged as Not Constructive and it was deleted instantly because it contains the word *accepting*.

Comments with the word **accept** and its variations are removed when flagged due to the high number of comments we used to get that stated "Work on your accept rate." or "Please work on accepting answers because you accept rate.... sucks".

Comment: @Shog9 How could I forget that one?  I'm trying to find the MSE post about these words....

Comment: @Servy: aw, a non-c flag on that didn't insta-nuke it. That's no fun!

Comment: Expression is not *quite* that naive, @Martijn.

Comment: As usual, if you have something you want to stick around, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: @Shog9: I know :-P Just having some (acceptable?) meta fun.

Comment: Does that was auto flag(script) or a person? If person why would he did that? My comment was really trying to help isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Comments with stop words in them can be deleted by a single community member.  The OP apparently felt that your comment was either unhelpful or no longer needed.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It was flagged by another user and it was removed because it contained that word.  As to why it was flagged... _shrug_

Comment: Who knows, @Sriram; folks flag comments for all sorts of reasons - mostly frustration that they exist, I suspect.

Comment: now we sort of know why it got nuked, is there any way to tell if this single-user no fly list is being abused or is this so rare that we should not care?

Comment: @jball: It does only affect comments, after all. AFAICR this is the first meta post I've seen about unintended consequences.  [see also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252761/my-comment-was-removed-is-it-moderation-activity#comment9754_252765)

Comment: Meh, I know comments are second class citizens and all, but they are useful contributions and the unilateral nuking of them by random users seems potentially harmful to the community and morale...

Comment: @RobertHarvey In the end this comment is not that important but there are many comments which is very valuable. There should a toll gate to check before removing the comment IMHO. Or after removing also if the comment is really helpful we need to put them back in place. What's your view in this?

Comment: My view is *meh.*

Comment: Just wondering if shouting _why the downvote on my answer_ sort of comments should also be deemed not constructive.

Comment: Is this even a legitimate issue/use-case anymore since Accept Rate isn't visible to other users?

Comment: @bluefeet: Let's just not confuse "telling users to accept an answer" with "telling new users **how** to accept an answer, and the benefit future readers derive from finding a checked answer"

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, the problem is that these comments are typically worded in such a way that they come across negatively which is partly why they wind up being removed.

Comment: Here's an example where it was worded badly and [still turned out well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630886/help-with-bitwise-operations#comment7832070_6630886) (because the OP was able to laugh at himself)

Comment: It seems that such comments are no longer "not constructive" if somebody has upvoted on those.  Is that correct?

Comment: @devnull Upvotes on comments don't really matter when it comes to something being not constructive.  I've seen plenty of rude, not constructive comments upvoted - that doesn't mean they shouldn't be removed.

Comment: The idea of removing a post based on existence of a word seems very blunt. Pragmatically strengthful but, oh boy, so indiscriminately blunt. (Adding the condition that the post needs to be flagged tackles a bit of that but we all know there's a **lot** of trigger happy users chasing the flagification badges).

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, I flagged that one about "accepting" for `It's no longer needed.` and it instantaneously got removed.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy: The one I linked to or the one this question is about?  Did you find the comment from this page?

Comment: @BenVoigt The one that you linked to. I actually flagged the one with "accepting," which instantaneously got removed, and the one in which the OP laughed at himself.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy: It makes it difficult to discuss on meta when the comments we are talking about vanish :(  If you went and flagged them because you saw them cited as an example I would consider that mildly malicious.

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't flag them because you cited them; I flagged them only because they were unnecessary. I'm not trying to be malicious. P.S. Our comment discussion here may also get flagged for removal at some indefinite time in the future.