# Is asking reasons for downvote in comments non-constructive?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvote-reason

Several users tend to scream in comments *Why was my answer downvoted* and such whenever their post is downvoted.  (The reason for downvote might be legitimate or not, that's not the point.)

My question is are such comments constructive?  I might have deferred asking but [the official stand on *urging* to accept an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252761/my-comment-was-removed-is-it-moderation-activity/) prompted this.

Should such comments be flagged as non-constructive or are these considered good?

---

Another trigger for this post is that a comment on one of my posts suddenly vanished.  I presume that it was deleted by a mod.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23371962/2235132) is the post in question and the comment read something like: *Somebody came.  Downvoted both the answers quietly and went away.*

Comment: Also: [Is it now discouraged to ask for reasons for downvotes as a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson There are occasions when you downvote because the post doesn't make sense whatsoever.  It _feels bad_ to see the OP go berserk due to the downvote.  At other times, you haven't voted on the post but the reason is pretty much the same.

Comment: I down vote my maximum allotted down votes and close votes every day I have time to use SO. It is my *duty* so to say, I never feel compelled to leave a reason, because the majority of the time the OP didn't feel compelled to put in even the minimum effort to their question. And I certainly never feel bad about their inappropriate reaction, that is their problem.

Comment: If you feel like downvoting, you'll probably agree that there's something to improve on the question, so why not tell what it is so OP gets a chance to improve? I don't know any good reasons *not* to comment on a downvote, except if someone else has already given that comment.

Comment: And I would care, since I care about the quality of my questions. Shouldn't that be self-evident?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It can be quite simple: maybe there is something wrong with your post that you genuinely want to fix, but haven't figured out. It has happened to me a few times and when I have asked it is for this reason. But I don't expect that people should feel constrained to answer, and I also don't assume that whoever comments on the reason for a down-vote is the same person that down-voted.

Comment: I suppose that this depends on the circumstances. Sometimes the downvoters follow a sheep-effect: the first who for whatever reason didn't like the post triggers an avalanche of other lazy downvoters and the post might be downvoted several times without reason. I agree it's a rare occurrence but in such a case OP could reasonably ask why. On the other hand writing "why the downvotes?" it's often useless with regard to the original downvoter, just triggers some comments from other better-behaved users who realized (assuming OP is in good faith) that OP didn't understand the reason himself.

Comment: I got a comment-less down-vote today; I left a 'Why' question because I don't think it was a fair down-vote.  I want to know why people think my answers, which I put effort into, are so bad that they warrant a down-vote.

Comment: It's case-by-case so it'll be impossible to give a single answer. Some questions are poor and show no sign of "effort" as @JarrodRoberson also mentions. Writing why you downvote such a post would likewise be a waste of effort because the author wouldn't learn from it anyway. Downvoting a post where the poster obiovusly has made an effort in a higher degree warrant an "explanation". So in the former case, I'd ignore the "why the downvote" as well, in the latter - if I downvote, I'll also say why. It's case-by-case.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: pass-downvote-and-go-away users won't even care if you edit your post (I've seen this several times). That is discouraging for new users or people who care for rep. A "why the downvote?" in such occurrences is a way to vent that fact.

Comment: I sometimes post the "Well, I didn't downvote, but it might be because..." type comments that Grant referred to above. I (generally) do so when I think the OP deserves some kind of explanation. "Deserves" is, of course, subjective, but I'm talking about cases where I get a sense the OP is making a genuine effort and doesn't understand what they've missed. (Of course I don't post an explanation if I can't actually imagine one, something that does happen frequently given how many _good_ questions and answers get downvotes for no apparent reason.)

Comment: If leaving a comment for downvote is a waste of time, wouldn't a nice checkbox list of common downvote reason be a nice way forward with the current situation?  As a site improvement suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure if everybody takes a downvote reason positively.  There are many who rush to find your posts in order to downvote.

Comment: @devnull: could this be achieved by simply masking the name of the commenter ? Then there would be a comment associated to the downvote, and no possibility of retaliation. Best of both worlds. (Not that I care much about retaliation as it usually costs more to the downvoter than to myself relatively speaking...)

Comment: @Jace Requiring downvotes to be accompanied by a comment has been suggested several times, and as I recall [status-declined] each time in part because of the privacy aspects. Votes are supposed to be anonymous, unless the voter *chooses* to make themselves known. (That said, I've received a number of inexplicable downvotes as well, and in some cases really would have wanted to find out what the reason for the downvote was.)

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is like yelling, "You're wrong!" and then walking away. It's just bad form. If you're going to downvote, explain why. Don't be so damn lazy and callous. This counts for downvotes on both questions AND answers.

Comment: **What part of the default reason for the downvote isn't good enough?** It says in a general way why they failed, 99.999999% of the cases for a downvote that is actually the reason. They were lazy. Nothing I can say will add anything to the default reason. Thus it would be a waste of time on many levels.

Comment: @Trilarion your opinion is your own, I am doing these people a favor in answering questions as a general rule, the least they can do is show a modicum of effort. As I said, if they don't show the effort and get a downvote/closevote and VLQ flag, then then why should they deserve any effort past that on my part. **They are ruining it for everone else, and they don't care.** Why should I care what these anonymous people think? [My closevote research proves this!](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/186827/closed-reopened-after-lastedit-by-owner-after-closed)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - post the link to the question! If it is good one I am sure the meta readers will upvote it for you. If it is a bad reason the alturistic might take a shot at guessing for you, the rest of us will probably downvote it mercilessly if it deserves it. :-)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I would say that you don't have to care if you don't want. But this is a Q&A site and telling someone why the question is not useful could be seen as part of the A of Q&A. But of course it should be voluntary. I personally like close votes more than downvotes because there you get a hint what went wrong in the end.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I have read many answers written by JonathanLeffler and they reflect a consistently high level of expertise. In all likelihood, those who downvote him know _far_ less than he does on whatever the subject. If they had the courage to leave a comment, they would likely learn something from him.  Their anonymous downvotes, by contrast, contribute nothing positive to SO.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I understand the privacy part, my suggestion is to add categories to down vote. Like "lazy down vote" or "bad question down vote".  The system would not require users to comment or even associate a down vote to a user.

Comment: @John1024 - I am not questioning his reputation or capabilities, I just want to see what he is talking about for context and a reference point, jeez. He has crazy rep, I wonder what he asked that could have been so terrible. **This is referring to a question he posted not an answer!**

Comment: @JarrodRoberson [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23375601/2235132) appears to be the post in question.  I'd refrain to comment on the answer.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Downvoting doesn't necessarily imply that the answer is "wrong".  It implies that the answer is "not useful".  The two are different.  Usefulness is also determined by the context.  I don't, usually, downvote wrong answers.  However, I do prefer to downvote answers that do not seem helpful or useful in the given context.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson OK.  "This is referring to a question he posted not an answer!"  I don't think so: He wrote about a downvote 'today' (yesterday now) and he hasn't posted a question since [April 11](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler?tab=questions&sort=newest).  I believe that he was referring to responding to the downvote (on his answer) by leaving a question (in the comments).  My larger point is that it is not unusual for downvoters to know less than the person writing the answer and everyone would benefit it they instead exposed their thinking in the comments.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: The relevant answer is the one identified by [devnull](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) [above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive?cb=1#comment11334_252826) — to whit [Warning passing argument 3 of `os()` with different width due to prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370823/warning-passing-argument-3-of-os-with-different-width-due-to-prototype/23375601#23375601). I disagree with the analysis by [ldav1s](http://stackoverflow.com/users/425738/ldav1s), but haven't voted on it.

Comment: @devnull You're only thinking about your own perspective. With no comment, downvoting can be fairly ambiguous and come across as purely negative to the receiver. Not exactly constructive. However, downvoting with a comment provides a signal to the individual as to what is awry with their question/answer and offers them an opportunity to fix it.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Aren't you making an assumption here?  The whole point of this post for me was to understand what the community thinks about it.

Comment: @devnull I'm just responding to your comment. "Downvoting doesn't necessarily mean that the answer is 'wrong'". The downvoter (the proverbial "you" in my last comment, not "you" personally.) usually has a clear reason for downvoting. The downvotee on the other hand, having made the mistake is likely to see the downvote as a signal that something is wrong, but without feedback they are unlikely to figure out WHAT is wrong leaving the downvote as either ambiguous or unclear.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I guess that what's implicit in the question is that much of such comments come from high rep users.  Given that they are not new to the site, I'd assume that they should be seasoned enough to figure what's wrong with their answer.  I find those comments to be noise.

Comment: @devnull: On the other hand, if seasoned users can't figure out what's wrong with their answer, it's quite possible that the downvote is noise.

Comment: Answers and questions are getting conflated here.  @JarrodRoberson said he downvoted *questions* without a minimum of effort.  I think a lot of active users dislike *answer* downvotes w/o comment, because the answer may be correct, just not the best.

Comment: If a comment like this is to get constructive criticism, fine. But too often it's an excuse for the OP to berate the downvoter in attempt to protect rep and/or find who did it so they can take revenge.

Comment: I would rather suggest downvoters to leave a comment before downvoting. If the user does not improve the question, you can downvote then...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I think there are some 9s too much. Maybe for 99% it is the case, not more.

Comment: Highly relevant: [Revisiting Optional Explanations for Downvotes (on Questions)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/456814).

Comment: I'll inject here that on several occasions I've been subjected to "serial downvoting" in situations where it's pretty clear the downvoter was someone I criticized (and who asked who downvoted him), even though I was not (always) one of the downvoters.  Not that I mind -- 23K points and about two bucks will get you a cup of coffee at Starbucks.  I find it all rather amusing, in fact.  But I do think it's not productive when most ask why they were downvoted -- in maybe 10% of the cases I wonder too, but in most the reason is pretty obvious and the OP is just being an ass.

Comment: There are many people on here who downvote really good questions because they either dislike the way in which something is being done (personal opinion = subjective, probably). This immediately has a negative effect on the question and its potential to get any answers. As soon as there is a downvote with no answers, I know, and I'm sure many others do too, that you may as well just close the question, reword it and try again. Downvotes should cost more.

Comment: Upvotes should cost more too.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree.  But the community appears to [disagree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253815/upvote-should-have-its-cost-too), unfortunately.

Comment: @devnull - The "community", alas, wants perfection without pain.

Comment: when I got down-voted I always look for the reason why? so I can fix the answer or question if possible (I often overlook something...). I am not too long here but mine experience here is that legit down-voters leave a comment what is wrong and when not they (or someone) usually answer such why comment (usual reason for me is that markdown hides part of text thinking it is some kind of formating, or typo ... which is easily fixed by adding few lines or spaces). No response usually mean no just votes. Few (even accepted) answers of mine was down and up voted  from -5 to +5 without any edit !

Comment: I downvote because bananas

Comment: Most answer downvotes are for one of two reasons:  1) The answer has a serious flaw, 2) the answer rubs someone the wrong way.  Generally #1 should be obvious to the answerer, based on comments and other answers, but a surprising number of answerers refuse to recognize a flaw even when it's waved in front of them.

Comment: @HotLicks The attitude is more like: _If my answer is wrong, don't downvote.  Fix it instead._.  The same folks would never complain about upvotes on a wrong answer.  They wouldn't even ever remove their incorrect answer (if it has upvotes).  Nobody shouts: _Look ma! Why was this upvoted?_

Comment: @devnull I have been known to post "upvoter please explain" when an answer is obviously wrong, is very poor quality, and has 3 upvotes.  I don't mind people posting nonsense - that's what downvotes are for.  But endorsing nonsense by upvoting it is a much greater sin in my book.  No upvoter has ever provided an explanation, when I do so.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm not sure if it was your own answer when you posted this.  In my opinion, the biggest sin is to keep an obviously wrong answer simply because it has been incorrectly upvoted.  There are many who argue that even if the post does not answer the question, it might help somebody else.  They refuse to delete it simply because a robo upvoted it.

Comment: @devnull No, I don't post wrong answers.  :-)

Comment: @devnull Seriously, though, if I find I have posted something wrong, I will either delete it or correct it.  If I find I have posted something that is correct but not exactly what the OP was after, I will sometimes label it as being "not what was required", and leave it, even if it has downvotes, because I think it might be useful to someone else.  I don't do that often though.  I figure it's not right to clutter up somebody's question with answers to something else.  Frankly, I'm not scared of losing an upvote or two if I delete something.

Comment: Can 1-rep users see any pending close votes on a question?  Generally, the only time I don't comment when downvoting is if I'm casting a close vote on a particularly bad question with little hope of being salvaged.  But when my answers get downvoted, particularly when downvotes are the only votes, I like to know why so I should know whether I should delete/improve my answer.  However, when an answer like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446018/when-a-subclass-overrides-a-method-how-can-we-ensure-at-compile-time-that-the-s/21446076#21446076 gets downvoted (has 1), I don't bother asking

Comment: I think it's kinda destructive for the stackoverflow system when users are not forced to provide a (plausible) reason for downvoting or even close-voting.

The author of the question has no chance to improve the question, so it'll probably stay unanswered forever, AND the author cannot learn from the "mistakes" and might make the same "mistakes" again

Answer (score 346):

I believe it is constructive as it shows that the OP wants to know what went wrong, and how to correct it. It's so discouraging for new users to just be down-voted. From some of the comments here, I get the idea that some here think that people who post questions/answers of low quality are just bad people in general who are of low quality, who will never contribute to Stack Exchange. This reeks of arrogance. It also gives a false impression of cliques. If somebody is asking, they care. If they don't have a reason for that downvote, what choice do they really have but to come to a wrong conclusion? Sure a few hardy stubborn souls might hang on, perhaps discover the respective Meta site, thoroughly re-read the FAQ and help sections, and go on to be solid contributors. Most I think will just leave, though. Stack Exchange is in a good place now. The site is growing. That might not be the case forever. People asking for reasons for their downvotes is entirely reasonable, and I think the response should likewise be reasonable.

My own first question was not of particularly good quality, as is evidenced by all of the unrelated answers. It took me several edits to get it right. Fortunately the voting members involved with the question (reviewers, and answerers alike) were patient and genuinely trying to help, not only me, but the site in general. Comments helped in that case. Any downvotes would have been irrelevant as I wouldn't have understood what the downvote was for anyway.

Comment: On the other hand, when you do leave a comment why you downvoted, you occasionally get a rant on how you are not welcoming to new people, and if you clarify your position you get asked if you are picking on them. Whether you explain your downvote or not, someone will disagree either way.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel true, but it shouldn't discourage you to do _the right thing_, even if there are people speaking against you. They are wrong, not you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Someone will disagree but they cannot unchange your downvote. So what bad can really happen? The only real bad thing should be retaliations downvotes, shouldn't it? Everything else should be harmless.

Comment: While this is certainly a fine theory, I find it not the case in practice.  Most of the people who go "OMG downvoters explain!!!" in comments 5 seconds after seeing a downvote are dramatically more likely to get into an unconstructive argument in the event it is explained than someone who doesn't comment at all.

Comment: I've always thought that people who down vote and don't state a reason why are just cowards afraid of confrontation. Some people have down voted questions/answers that I've put effort into it, and if someone down votes a clear a question/answer it should be explained why to understand why my content does not pass the high quality bar here.

Comment: A lot of it also depends on the tone of the comment asking about downvotes. If someone is polite and genuinely confused I'll usually leave a comment explaining why or guessing why I think someone else downvoted. If someone is angry or accusatory I ignore them, since I just risk making myself a target. If someone put no effort into their question, then there isn't really anything constructive to say. "You just pasted 1000 lines of code and didn't bother to ask an actual question" is not going to garner a welcome reply.

Comment: @AlanChavez: Dang, even the content of your comment there sounds defensive.  I'd never explicated my downvote if I saw a comment like the above in your post history.  It's not because I'm a coward; it's because I can improve StackOverflow better by commenting where I'd expect a constructive response to what I have to say.  If I get the sense I'll just annoy someone trying to explain, I downvote and move on.  Only so many hours in the day.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the intent of asking is always to _fix_ the answer.  High rep users manage to gather upvote on obviously _unhelpful_ answers by making such comments.  Note that an answer may be technically correct, but it should be _helpful_ to the OP.  If the OP doesn't exhibit basics of integer addition and you dump an answer that requires understanding of advance calculus, I'd say that it's a terribly unhelpful answer worthy of downvotes.  Moreover, it should have been obvious before posting such an answer.

Comment: @devnull I am curious do you have any good examples of this? I always attempt to answer the question as generally as possible since the answer really is not just for the OP. If it obvious that the OP will need a bit more hand holding I will add the details at the end with a simpler example first but there may well be details that go over the OPs head but I don't think that is a problem. Trying to figure out if a correct answer helps and OP without them saying so sounds a bit hard to get right in general.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'd refrain from citing specific examples.  Regarding your curiosity, I've observed it several several times.  There have been occasions when I've left a note suggesting that the answer isn't really helpful (without voting).  There have been occasions that I've downvoted and moved on.  Regarding the point that it might not be possible to correctly conclude whether an answer is _helpful_: I presume that it's not too tough to determine where the OP stands given the question and that should give one a pretty good sense of whether a given answer would help.

Comment: `Some here think that people who post questions/answers of low quality are just bad people in general who are of low quality, who will never contribute StackExchange` -- That *would* be arrogant, if it were actually true.  It isn't.  The truth is much more mundane; the folks who seek to keep the site clean are far outnumbered by the ones who litter the site with vague, underspecified questions riddled with spelling and grammatical errors, and the broom sweepers are getting worn out.

Comment: This answer appears to reason that explaining downvotes is constructive, whereas if I'm not mistaken, the question at hand is whether asking for an explanation of downvotes is constructive. The crux of the answer, that *"if somebody is asking, they care"* is hopeful but fictitious as a blanket statement. In my experience, about 1/2 of the time they are asking because they want to argue. The truth is that if a post can be improved folks will comment on it regardless. You haven't explained why you think asking for a reason is constructive, only that you think folks should explain downvotes.

Comment: @Radiodef, if I had actually gotten a downvote on that question, asked for an explanation, and gotten the feedback that I did eventually get from the comments, comments which helped me improve that question to finally be clear and precise, then absolutely my asking would have been constructive.

Comment: "...about 1/2 of the time they are asking because they want to argue..." I guess it's a glass half-full sort of thing. If that's how you feel, then downvote and run. Those of us who are more optimistic downvoters will stick around and try and help on the assumption that 1/2 of the time they want to improve their contribution. And let's keep in mind that none of us have to put up with abuse. If you think the conversation is getting out of hand, walk away and report it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was "are comments _asking_ for comments non-constructive?" not "are comments explaining downvotes non-constructive?"

Comment: I've had downvotes where the other user felt my answer was wrong by "design" not aware that it was done intentionally to overcome a not-known-to-everyone IE bug.  I usually try to add a note as such to my answer but it isn't always read (or I only think to add the clarification after getting the down vote)  Sadly in most cases I've asked the user was a drive-by... and they are not around/don't care to explain why anyway.  That all said, I don't see the harm in asking why... we all have the same goal of "correct answers" so working together to get them is critical.

Comment: For one of my answers I have had both up and down votes with a new result of +2. I have no idea how to measure how useful my answer was or what I could do to improve it. Down votes are useless unless a reason is given; they add no value other than to discourage. (I have no problem with voting being anonymous).

Comment: Why does this have sooooo many upvotes? * mind boggled *

Comment: Lately moderators tend to delete comments asking for reasons because such comments are attracting downvotes (don't know why) and removal is seen as a service. I recommend to change wording and make the request more interesting (add some propositions of what could be wrong, add a please ...) to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Most of us have seen folks dig themselves in pretty deep with such comments, @Trilarion - seeing them flagging for revenge voting after spending hours arguing over a vote is just sad. I talk a bit more about this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post/37123#37123

Comment: @Shog9 Yes it's sad but it also shows how deep downvoting hurts. The reason of asking is to improve yourself, not to send signals of frustration. That's actually also what you said already in 2010. Asking for suggestions is good, asking for reasons for downvotes shall be bad? I actually think the difference is not that big. It could be seen as almost the same although the first is probably better. Of course some people will actually really want to have a fight over downvotes. But do you advocate pre-emptive downvoting just because somebody might search for a fight? That would be unfair.

Comment: I'm saying life is too short to argue over downvotes, @Trilarion. I got drawn into entirely too many unproductive discussions before realizing this, so I do what I can to spare others the trouble; still, every day we get emails from someone upset over an unnecessary argument that started this way. If you're honestly looking for advice, then ask for it, and accept it from whoever is willing to provide it *regardless of if or how they voted* - that simple rule can avoid soooo much drama...

Comment: @Shog9 I agree with what you say but I also see how so much on SO depends on scores and how so many people take them so seriously, probably too seriously. The only point I really want to make is that I think it is very unreasonable to downvote just because somebody asked "why the downvotes" which means I'm a supporter of this answer here. When you see unreasonable behavior of course you can decide to comply and just not ask the question anymore - social dynamics. But in my book then the bad guys have won.

Comment: We're all bad guys, @Trilarion. Everyone who has ever felt attacked or put-down and responded in kind is a bad guy/gal. It's human nature; you gotta just work around it if you want to accomplish anything.

Comment: @Shog9 It's not only human nature, it's also the system. Just to give some examples: make close voting or downrepping more expensive in terms of rep and you'll see much less of it. Almost like magic. The current system here deliberately sets the treshold very low. I agree that people aren't nice the whole time. I guess that's okay as long as it doesn't play out always on the same kind of victims. I guess the best improvement in the future regarding this situation will come from better personal filtering technology making part of the voting obsolete and from more balanced rules.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937219/why-do-we-need-a-weakself-for-functions-methods-within-closures/40937220#40937220) I asked for why I got downvoted, instead my comment got deleted. Is that right or wrong? This answer ie the will of SO says I deserve to ask... @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 171):

The assumption appears to be that downvotes are on "obviously" wrong answers.  There are ample situations where I've seen downvotes on both questions and answers that (in my opinion) do not deserve them.

On more than one occasion, I've had downvotes on answers that I'm pretty sure are the correct answers. Sometimes, these are part of "serial downvoting" on a question, where similar answers were also downvoted.  In those cases, I tend to upvote the other answers.

I have also had downvotes on questions where there really was an error.  Unfortunately, with no comment, I am left as clueless as before the downvote.  In some cases, leaving a comment has enlightened me -- such as the time I left the `on` keyword out of an `on` clause.

So, I see nothing wrong with asking for comments.  The original downvoter may not see it, but someone else may be able to explain the problem.  I strongly wish that Stack Overflow required a comment with a downvote -- even if the comment is anonymous, protecting the downvoter.

By the way, I personally no longer downvote either questions or answers.  I have made mistakes in the past and I find that leaving a comment often has the same or better effect.  For instance, [this answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387283/alter-function-sql-server/23387348?noredirect=1#comment35828307_23387348) responsibly deleted his/her answer after being informed that it is incorrect.

Comment: leaving a keyword out should not solicit a down vote it should solicite and `edit` for the minor correction, with an explanation, it would most likely get approved

Comment: THIS.  I don't down-vote.  I think it's a bad feature of the SE system.  I vote to close if the question is a duplicate or is so flagrantly in violation of the rules that it can't be saved.  But voting to close requires a reason.  Since down voting requires no reason it is just negative, not constructive.  I've been down voted by people on questions and answers not because there's anything wrong with them, just because someone doesn't like my answer.  If you disagree with me then have the guts to put your name to it.  Let other readers decide who's right.

Comment: I would like to also see that it is forced for a downvoter to leave a comment. The person who got downvoted would not see who downvoted but a moderator might be able to see it.

Comment: A BIG UPVOTE from me for your insight: *By the way, I personally no longer downvote either questions or answers. I have made mistakes in the past. And, I find that leaving a comment often has the same or better effect.* --  this has become my own principle, wrote it in my profile.

Comment: we all make mistakes but its disappointing to disengage with the voting system that benefits all of us. fair disclosure - i downvoted this post because of this position of not voting on answers or questions which i feel is fundamental to highlighting quality. hypothetically, in rare occurrence of finding an answer of yours with a syntax issue, i would comment on the issue and have high confidence you would edit fairly fast. after fair time though ( maybe half an hour if user is active ) has elapsed though, i would downvote ( as quality is important and a syntax error is still an error )

Comment: *I find that leaving a comment often has the same or better effect* I completely agree. For example, today someone commented on one of my answers showing the problem (*even without downvoting the answer*) and I immediately understood it, and deleted the answer. But a few weeks ago I had a downvote on an answer, and I still don't know what it was for, so decided to leave it there. Downvotes without a fair comment are half-measures.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  - Leaving a comment is fine, but that shouldnt be condescending or rude or discouraging.  Something you have done in a question that I asked.  When I responded to your rude comment you deleted it.

Comment: In the case of downvoting when your answer is mostly correct, but something small is incorrect about it, I would say this is not a case when someone should downvote, and SO actually recommends [an edit as opposed to a downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down#:~:text=When%20should%20I%20vote%20down,also%20need%20to%20be%20closed.) in this situation

Comment: @Sam . . . I (and others) regularly get downvotes on answers the that the OP has already accepted *and praised as being helpful*.  This is a sufficiently common occurrence that I (and no doubt others) simply take it personally.  If someone cares to downvote, they should care enough to leave a comment.

Comment: (+1) _" I strongly wish that Stack Overflow required a comment with a downvote -- even if the comment is anonymous, protecting the down voter."_.  I strongly agree with this wish, and if asked in a survey whether such a feature should be added to the site, I would support it, but perhaps with a caveat that it _would not_ provide the option of ambiguity.  One observed component of human nature is the difference in behavior between actions believed by a person to be performed in ambiguity, or transparency. A comment left in transparency comes with accountability. Not so with ambiguity.

Answer (score 56):

First of all voting is secret (to the majority of people on SO) for a reason, and asking for the downvoter to explain himself is also (or maybe for some the major reason to ask for a comment) asking the people that downvoted to reveal themselves.

People have the right to have their own reasons to {up,down}vote, and that is what makes up a lot of the freedom on this site.

People do not want to reveal themselves for various reasons, including problems like serial downvoting; **and it is of absolutely not concern for anyone else what these reasons are**. This is a fundamental property of all (real) democratic processes. A lot of people that are just asked -- even in a relatively nice way -- feel harassed for revealing their decision making process. Especially when this happens over and over and over again. People are fed up with this question, and automatically snap into some nonconstructive mode. Either by never visiting that post again, or by actively fighting the question for why something was downvoted instead of the content of the answer.

That said, what is a real good, understandable reason for a question of why it was downvoted? The only reason that this community should care about is: Whoever was downvoted wants to learn.

So: Why not ask what you want to learn. Instead of asking

> Why was this answer downvoted?

better ask

> Did I miss any important point here? can this be improved?

this may transport about the same message by the commenter, but is totally differently perceived by whoever reads that comment. Mostly, most will not (directly or indirectly) feel like they are revealing their vote. And also this is much more constructive. It is actively asking for what can be changed, not for why something was perceived as sub-optimal. Think about the solution, not the problem.

Comment: Your abridged question might not sound the same but may well serve the same intention as before. The problem could easily be solved by allowing anonymous downvote comments that are not displayed publicly but only to the user. IIRC there was/is a message when downvoting that says "please give a comment on how to improve", why not replace this message with a text field to give the opportunity for this feedback?

Comment: @Nobody: interesting idea, you might want to elaborate that into a feature request. However for people that like to use up their daily downvote quota on questions that deserve no further explanation, such a feature should not impair their workflow.

Comment: Just for reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes#comment4016_2373 So this already has been said before but obviously not approved.

Comment: I disagree with your whole reasoning here. It is no feature of a real democratic process that no-one should care what the reasoning behind a decision is. On the contrary, I would always argue you should keep in mind the reasons behind a decision and not just the plain statement. Context matters, always. Of course you have no right to get the answer, but to _want_ this answer is very valid.

Comment: @Nobody: Well, it was just a comment, not a feature request...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: It has gained many upvotes and was there before the current system was implemented, so I assume it has been considered. You may go on with a feature request but I will not.

Comment: @Nobody: As mentioned on meta numerous times: comments are second class citizens. If you want something to stay around, or trigger some action, make it a question/answer. I would never assume it has been considered by those that have the powers to make it happen, simply because its in a comment.

Comment: @dirkk: Maybe as a non-native speaker the fine nuances of the words are interpreted a bit differently. Another property of a free system is that in your mind you can want anything that you want. What I mean is that your actions should not be in that way. "Did you vote democrats or communists?" "That is nothing of your business". To protect the weak; even such seemingly innocent questions can be so intimidating that people will reveal things that when they felt save, they would never have done.

Comment: What about people who comment like so - _-1 Your post is so and so..._. That becomes public voting, isn't it?

Comment: @AwalGarg: You are always free to tell everyone what you voted. If this is your free will, there is no big deal at all. It is your right to keep your vote to yourself, no matter how much anyone else insist on you revealing it; it is not your duty to keep it secret. You can always run around and scream into everyones face "I voted for the republicans" ... Its just that you need to live with the consequences then.

Comment: You don't have to explain, but the poster should be free to ask for an explanation.  It's no more harassment than the downvote was in the first place, given there was no attempt to educate with a comment.

Comment: I think allowing something to do anonymously is nothing to do with "freedom". If one have an opinion, it is preferred to take the responsibility for it. Also this site has a well defined goal which is related of the quality of Q/As. (At the same time I understand and admit that human nature can cause downvote "wars" and revenge type actions when downvoter is known: Here is where moderation go in the picture)  I think referring to "freedom"  is a misinterpretation of freedom and community (society)

Comment: @g.pickardou you are by writing this comment also benefiting from a certain level of anonymity, nobody here knows who you are in the real world. If people would come to your home and berate you about any vote you do, you would probably not find that funny. For a lot of people the perception about getting the same flak "only" online is not much different, and they would think twice expressing their opinion and submit to peer pressure voting differently or not at all

Comment: @g.pickardou what would you want to do with that information anyways, other than asking/harassing the person about the motives? Do statistics about how they always downvote only? I have never had a single time where I wanted to know *who* the person was

Answer (score 52):

Comments asking for explanations of down-votes are not constructive for the simple reason that the down-voter is unlikely to see the comment. As such it is just noise.

Unless someone is actively monitoring the post they won't see the comment as they don't get notified of said comment - [see here on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post) form more information.

All that you'll get is someone else explaining why they *think* someone else down-voted the post which is just speculation on their part and won't be the real reason someone down-voted.

I'm **not** saying that people shouldn't explain down-votes, or add a comment to say what **they** think is wrong with the post. Anything that can help improve questions and correct answers is to be welcomed.

Comment: Disagree with `the down-voter is very unlikely to see the comment` - this might be the case for downvotes on bad questions where people just fire and forget, but in the case of a fresh answer, the downvoter is more likely to still be around if the comment is posted reasonably fast. Based on personal experience, in the rare case one of my answers was downvoted I asked for reasons and got an answer in 2 of 3 cases. Still, I'd agree that the comment becomes pure noise if nobody answers it after a few minutes and could then be deleted.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be useful if someone else explains a down-vote? The question in almost all cases is "**Why** was this downvoted?" not "**Who** downvoted that?" If I know the answer to the first question, why shouldn't that be helpful to the OP?

Comment: @dirkk - Explaining downvotes **is** useful, but unless it's the down-voter doing the explanation it's just speculation.

Comment: Even then, the explanation will highlight how the post could be improved, enabling the poster to do better next time.

Comment: I highly doubt that, in a more practical sense. Of course I'll never know the exact thoughts another human being had, but for a majority of the questions the reason is quite obvious to a more experienced user. This is not always the case, of course, but to the standard low-rep user asking why is low quality question was downvoted, it most likely is.

Comment: If you're looking at a post and there are obvious problems with it that would attract downvotes, you shouldn't need the OP to demand to know why it was downvoted before you tell them how to fix it. It shouldn't even need to **have** any downvotes yet to prompt a helpful comment.

Comment: @Wooble In theory I agree, but this is simply impossible - There are many posts that could be improved, but I an not comment on all of them. And then I think it is reasonable to comment on these post, where the OP seems to care enough to at least ask what is wrong - I very much doubt that many users actually care about the quality of their question. So I think it is valid filtering criteria.

Comment: I disagree with this, there have been times when asking for feedback I received helpful comments from someone other than the downvoter that helped me fix issues that I missed in my answer or question. Many times the downvote was removed once I fixed the problem. Of course downvotes especially on questions may not always be about the content and so there may be no reasonable helpful comment but I see no reason to damn the whole practice.

Comment: I think the conclusion that if the original downvoter doesn't see the comment, the comment is "just noise" is flawed. More than anything else, the comment says "See, others have downvoted without leaving an explanation, but this users would like to get one. If you consider downvoting them, *please* add an explanation." So, even if the original downvoter may or may not see the request for an explanation, it is a sign to other downvoters that the respective user does care and would appreciate one.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: The original downvoter is likely long gone and has forgotten about it all. When you downvote a question, it doesnt even show up in your history. Answer downvotes do

Comment: Well, I saw a question with only 3 views, and a downvote, and someone asked, why the downvote, a person had replied _I didn't do it, but may be because..._. 1 view of the person who asked, 1 of the downvoter, and 1 of mine. So, it seems, he was the person who downvoted and was trying to hide the fact, I don't know why?... But, he did contribute by stating what can be improved.

Comment: @AwalGarg - you can't know that. **This** is exactly what I mean by speculation.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, I agree with your point. I was just trying to state that **This** also happens... rather, his downvote is non-constructive, isn't it? He didn't bring anything to the table by downvoting, did he?

Comment: I respectfully disagree with you. I always check my inbox constantly; it's kind of hard to miss the white-on-bold text telling you that something has happened. I've found that people who explained their downvotes to me seemed like people who were legitimitely offerrring constructive criticism, whereas those who downvoted without reason seemed more like people having fun with the powers that come with 125 rep.

Comment: @l4mpi if you ask for explanation immediately after getting downvoted and receive it, consider the possibility that the explanation may have been on its way anyway. I've posted explanations of my downvotes following requests for them half a dozen times or so, but in every case I was already in the process of writing my comment at the moment that the request for explanation appeared. It just takes longer to write an explanation of what's wrong with a post than it does for the post's author to see they got -1ed and write 'why the downvote?'

Comment: @MarkAmery Sure, that's a possibility. Happened quite a few times to me after downvoting an answer when I was in the process of writing a comment. Still, I'm rather sure that on one post of mine the downvoter (who was the author of another answer to the question) wouldn't have explained himself without my comment. Also, it lets the downvoter know that the post author is interested in knowing what's wrong with his post and currently being attentive and not afk, which might give the downvoter additional motivation to explain himself.

Comment: I think that if someone downvotes an answer because it's wrong, they have a responsibility to stick around for a while, to see if the respondent corrects the answer.  I frequently remove my downvotes after the respondent makes a remedial edit; and I _never_ just walk away from a question after I've downvoted one of the answers, unless I believe the answer is truly unable to be repaired.

Comment: @staticx here is an example of [someone asking why and getting an explanation from the downvoter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296571/why-does-this-code-output-more-than-4-lines#comment37585623_24296629) later on.

Answer (score 38):

For new users to the site, downvotes are frustrating - they didn't do things wrong on purpose and they'd like to get some information on why they occurred.  It's asking for feedback.

If the site's response to this is to then mark even that request for feedback as 'non-constructive' then that takes an already frustrated user and makes them much much less likely to come back to the site.

I think there is a difference between 'non-constructive to the person answering the question' and 'non-constructive to the person asking it', and when the answer to 'hey, what rule did I break?' is the equivalent of 'This is your second warning', then we've got a site that doesn't reward people for trying to become more helpful contributors.

Comment: If we lost 99% of new users and only kept the new users that did not get down voted, SO would be a better place.   So driving away new users could be seen as being very positive.

Comment: @Ian, that attitude is fine right now. StackExchange is growing in popularity and use. But that situation isn't eternal. There is no doubt that your approach would drive away loads of potentially good contributors. When the day comes that StackExchange reaches a zenith, many will point right back to this policy of commentless downvotes and finger this as a reason why that's happened. I've been through this before (with Wikipedia). I know that of what I'm speaking.

Comment: @ouflak, "potentially good contributors" are unlikely to get many down votes, given how few down votes there are.

Comment: And that is the attitude of arrogance that will come to haunt this site if it prevails.

Comment: @ouflak: "But that situation isn't eternal." But only because one day SO/SE will cease to exist. Until then we will always have tons of people not putting enough effort into writing up a coherent questions.

Comment: @IanRingrose I think such elitist views are very harmful to SO. It is based on the assumption that there are 1% of good new users and 99% of bad new users - This is simply untrue. There is a lot of gray area in between and a lot of these 99% you want to kick out will actually get used to the site and the standards and turn out very valuable input. No one is born knowing everything and we all started at some point in time - And everyone started with so called stupid questions.

Comment: @ouflak `There is no doubt that your approach would drive away loads of potentially good contributors` - I do highly doubt that. This would be the case for a startup site but not for SO. I'd say a "potentially good contributer" has the ability to understand that downvoting is nothing personal and just indicates something is wrong with the question. They would also understand that SO is a valuable resource and not be deterred by a few downvotes. I'd also expect them to invest some effort of their own to find out why they were downvoted, and not to expect to be spoon-fed this information.

Comment: @Plasma, Maybe SE will continue to grow ad infinitum until the internet simply stops. But how will commentless downvotes *help* improve quality? Look I'm fine with anonymous comments and downvotes. I love the idea of a template response such as for flags. I wouldn't even make it mandatory. Just for those who want to toss in a quick downvote and move on quickly with a basic best-fit reason. 

The site can get better. And those who make posts of low-quality can get better. I'm surprised at how many feel that the latter isn't true or possible.

Comment: @ouflak: Have a look at the downvote button texts: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and "This answer is not useful". Most of the time this is exactly what I want to express. Do we really want 10 comments saying "I can't see any research effort" for a useless question? Or can we please try to focus on increasing the SNR, either by using that time on writing more answers or sweeping out more noise by downvoting/close-voting/flagging?

Comment: and @dirkk `everyone started with so called stupid questions` - no, there are still people decent enough to first check if a question is on-topic, do some research, create a minimal example, find out how to format their post correctly and how to interact with the site and its users in general. And IMO, this should be the expected minimum for someone asking a question. If it's their first question and they get one or two points wrong one should be lenient and guide them, but if it's the second or n-th question, they should be downvoted to oblivion and I'd doubt it would be a great loss.

Comment: @Plasma, **WE** might not want that. But the OP might. And further, this site would probably like the result of that feedback (better quality questions and answers). There no reason to clutter the site. There are many great suggestions on how to do this without adding more burden to users and moderators.

Comment: @ouflak: We are in no way obliged to fulfill whatever wishes the OP has. If **we** as the community do want to have something (or not) then we should just do that. SO is not a place for everyone where we have to make everyone feel welcome by all means. It is a place where all those people that have the potential to be good citizens of the community are very welcome, and those who just waste time without the potential of contributing can go elsewhere.

Comment: @Plasma, agreed. But I do think we all want a better quality site. I think we disagree on how someone, who might initially not be a very quality poster but potentially could be, is made to feel 'very welcome'. I believe this comment section is dragging out a bit, so I won't comment here anymore. If you or anybody are interested in continuing this in chat, I'm game.

Comment: @dirkk we're talking about SO here, not generalized concepts - everyone sh*ts their pants as a baby but this doesn't mean it's an acceptable thing to do in public as an adult. And as I said, if the user is brand new and there are signs that there's still hope, he shall receive guidance. I do comment on most of my downvotes (unless of course I can simply upvote an existing comment expressing my opionion of the post), but for some posts the OP is just so hopelessly far away from help that I downvote and move on, because I couldn't possibly write anything non-offensive as a response.

Comment: @l4mpi Actually, I think we totally agree and arguing about it seems quite silly. I do the same as you describe and my point was not to say that there are no bad, inconsiderate new users or users we actually do not want on the site. My point is that this is not everyone or even a vast majority, whereas Ian suggested to drive away 99% of new users.

Comment: +1 Completely agree with you that there are different perspectives of the person of posted and the person who downvoted... And, not to mention, the latter is a bit wrong.

Comment: There's more to this - new users don't have a lot of rep to burn - I don't think it's overly fair that one bad question can contribute negative rep without moderation being involved.  Perhaps negative rep could be ring fenced to any amount gained by the question to start with.    NB: Answers a completely separate matter.

Answer (score 21):

I feel like I have to give an answer too. From my few days on Meta I have sensed the enormous sentiment of more active users towards what is received as a giant wave of low quality questions from unskilled and probably also ungrateful new users.

Still I can fully understand that somebody wants to know the reason about a downvote. The downvote itself (Question is not useful) does not explain anything. The reasons for a closure explain much more although maybe not always enough.

The important thing is: Sometimes users really have no clue why their question has been downvoted. They might be angry but foremost one must assume that some just might be curious`and want to learn. Or do we want to be pessimists?

Now voting is anonymous and retaliation downvotes is a real risk. I would probably not admit directly that I downvoted a specific question but I would be willing to give hints what I think what is wrong. And why not? It doesn't really hurt anyone.

So summarize:

Asking what is wrong should be constructive and legitimate. But you don't have a right to get an explanation. I might give one if I see such a situation and have enough time. It should depend on the willingness of the involved people to give an explanation but nobody should be regarded less because of asking why something was downvoted.

So basically it should be left as it is but questions for reasons should be seen as opportunities to teach and if this turns out to be impossible, well ignore it at will.

Comment: Exactly. "I noticed the downvote, how can I improve the question?" is constructive; "Care to explain the downvote?!" is not.

Comment: Also, "retaliation downvotes is a real risk". Retaliatory downvotes aren't really a big risk nowadays, because [there's a serial voting algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/163250) that undoes any instances of it.

Comment: Good to know. A single retaliatory downvote is still possible but no excesses.

Comment: @Cupcake There are smart folks out there who would downvote one or two of your posts a day.  It's trivial to conclusively deduce who it is in certain cases.  For example, there's one chap who would downvote one of my posts every couple of days.  (And I'm not the only one.  This guy does the same to a few other folks too.)  What do you do about it?

Comment: I guess any algorithm would fail in this case because of too many false positives. It's too close to the usual pattern of up and downvoting if you do it slowly. Maybe the algorithms can still be refined a bit, but in the end you have to resort to human judging (aka a public discussion here about the case).

Comment: @devnull I don't suppose you could just report the person to a mod, could you? Would it be hard to prove that this person is downvoting you strictly out of retaliation? Also, at our reputation levels, a downvote or two a day would slow us down a little (me more so than you), but it's not going to make our overall rep drop over time `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake I've so far chosen to ignore it.  It's a bit annoying though, that someone would drop by and keep downvoting your answers (for a reason that doesn't have anything to do with the post _per se_).  I thought about reporting it but then this chap was suspended (don't know why) for a couple of months.  Now he's back and started it all over again.  Thinking about how to take it forward.

Comment: @devnull I'm sorry, but for the longest time I thought you were a mod, but I just noticed that you don't have a diamond...did you used to be a mod? Maybe I just used to see you hanging out at [meta.se] a lot?

Comment: @Cupcake Nah, never!  Had I been the mod, I'd have suspended that chap until 3014.

Comment: @devnull well anyways, maybe just start another Meta discussion about it? I know I would certainly find it helpful if someday I suddenly found myself being harassed. Also, are you British?

Answer (score 17):

There have been several occasions when my questions have received a downvote and I am left scratching my head trying to work out why.

How am I supposed to make sure I don't make the same mistake again if I don't know where I made the mistake?

Also, here have been times when the question was downvoted by someone who didn't read the question properly because if they had they would've known that it was a duplicate question etc but didn't stick around long enough for a response and realise their error.

Answer (score 17):

**It would be constructive if the downvoter were presented with a "why?" window at the time of the downvote.**

I'm never angry at a downvote but when it happens I'm surprised and alarmed. When my answer, which I think is valid and good, is downvoted, I would like to know why, because I wouldn't have answered if I didn't think my answer was great. Sometimes it seems like someone was just being a troll (asking why wouldn't be beneficial for these cases, obviously), but if the downvoter had a real reason and I couldn't guess what it was, getting the reason would be useful for me as a developer.

It would also help others to evaluate my answers.

Comment: I know you're talking about downvotes on answers, not questions, but I actually opened a feature request for optional downvote explanations on questions, if you want to check it out and comment or vote on it: [Revisiting Optional Explanations for Downvotes (on Questions)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/456814).

Answer (score 16):

**No**, it is not non-constructive.

Stack Overflow is about making this site the best resource for questions and answers by professional programmers. Asking why a question or answer was downvoted can lead to an explanation and might lead to a subsequent edit and therefore to a better question/answer.

I see absolutely no harm in asking this question. At best case, a downvoter him/herself explains the reasoning, making it clearer to the OP. Otherwise, someone else might try to explain why he/she thinks that someone else downvoted it. The reason might be true (in most cases I have seen I guess it is) or false, but it will always result in a comment telling the OP how the post could be improved. In the worst case, simply no one responds.

In conclusion, I don't see how this question could lead to any harm, but I see potential benefits to the site in general.

Comment: I think your view of what StackOverflow is about is slightly off-target "[Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers...With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)" It's all about questions and answers provided by professional and enthusiast programmers. It's _not_ about being a general programming resource. Questions and answers that don't meet the quality standards should be voted off the site to make room for the ones that do.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I agree to your statement what SO is. However, I didn't really say anything against that in my answer as stating "programming Q&A" is just a more general case. It does not say we have to exect each and every programming question. In no way I am saying we should allow all sorts of stupid questions, I agree with you that this would be harmful. I edited my question a little, hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 11):

They're not constructive, but why does it matter?  "Why did I get downvoted" comments are the easiest thing there is to ignore.

The principal problem with "Why the downvote" comments is that the downvoter does not get notified of such comments, so they are unlikely to ever see them.

Comment: You seem to suggest that it's noise.  Should those be flagged?

Comment: You can if you want to.  But mods are not going to lose sleep over these.  See my edit.

Answer (score 9):

It can be constructive if the point is to actually improve the answer.

However, we should all already know that explaining downvotes is a controversial subject to begin with. Some folks are adamant that they should not have to.

It is unfortunately common for an explanation request to look like this:

> Downvoters: please explain.

And no, that's not constructive. If they did not explain their downvote before, why would they do it now? Anyone that's responded to one of these comments would also know it's likely going to instigate an argument.

#### If somebody is angry I downvoted them, I'm not going to talk to them about it.

Furthermore, if they're angry because I didn't comment initially, they should get over it because I don't have to.

What could be constructive is something more along the lines of this:

> Can anyone tell me why this was downvoted? If it's wrong, can it be corrected?

This could be constructive because:

- It's polite.
- It's directed at anybody.
- It clearly states its intent is correction.

#### What is constructive is providing a high-quality Q&A. To this end, asking for a downvote explanation is constructive.

For answers in particular it is important to understand that nobody *has* to tell you why your answer is bad. By posting something wrong or low-quality and then asking about it the Q&A is derailed.

It's also important to understand that in many cases when your answer is being downvoted, what you should be doing is deleting it.

Remember, there is a place for asking questions and ideally it's not the comments:

[image: Ask a Question]

#### Now, my personal opinion is this type of comment should not be *flagged* as 'not constructive' because I like to think the moderators have better things to do with their time.

But sure, posting this type of comment may be a bit foolish. I've personally done it a couple times but I don't anymore because I've realized there were other things I could have done. It's also typical for somebody else to come by and leave a comment anyway so you probably don't have to ask.

Additionally, if the comment is very inflammatory (very occasionally they are), then do flag it as 'rude'.

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to figure what the community, at large, feels about asking the reason for downvotes.  Hence the question.  The post didn't quite make it explicit but such comments usually come from relatively high rep users.  I haven't run into newbies or even *relatively* newbie folks making comments like: *Why was this downvoted*?

I find it a bit surprising to see that an overwhelming proportion of folks feel that it's necessary or correct to ask for the downvote reason.  Their reasons might vary, but most seem to suggest that it *gives an opportunity* to improve upon the answer.  For a seasoned user posting an answer that is unlikely to help the OP<sup>1</sup>, regardless of whether incorrect or not, would not seem to be useful.  Very often the *unhelpful* (or even incorrect) sort of answers emerge due to the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).  If they are a bit careful to read the question before answering, there would be far lesser instances of downvotes.

Moreover, I cannot help wondering that nobody came out and argued that if one posting an answer would never ever ask or argue why her post was upvoted, then what sense does it make to ask for the downvote reasons.  I have run into several several *incorrect* answers that have managed upvotes for whatever reasons and those are not removed despite possible comments suggesting that the answer is incorrect.  (*Somewhat* related: [Should answers that do not answer a question be preserved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252404/should-answers-that-do-not-answer-a-question-be-preserved))

Some talk about the *herd effect*, note that it applies to upvotes too.  Perhaps more often than in the other case because downvotes on answers cost a penny and only few are willing to shell it out.  Yet one would never hear anyone (there may be exceptions) complain about being upvoted for an incorrect answer even if a brave soul comes out and comments about it.

Aside from what others have mentioned who don't quite find such comments to be constructive, I'd say that such comments **do** indicate that one is attempting to say that *I can never go wrong*.  It doesn't seem give a very good feeling -- one might go wrong regardless of reputation or experience or whatever.  Perhaps reading the question and one's own answer before hitting <kbd>Post Your Answer</kbd> would reduce the *opportunity* to ask the question drastically.

---

<sup>1 It's not quite hard to figure that.  The question would tell a lot about how one needs to answer so that it's *useful* to the OP.  If the question is terribly vague, then it doesn't deserve an answer anyways.</sup>

---

### Does leaving a comment for a wrong answer make any sense?

I'm not sure.  A number of incidents appear to suggest that it is best to downvote and move on.

Reason: I've often observed that leaving a note to indicate that the answer is wrong often leads to snippets from an existing correct answer to the same question being blatantly copied into one's own answer.  (This would invariably happen if the incorrect answer has managed upvotes.)

Moreover, there are some who wouldn't even prefer it to be obvious that that an incorrect answer was fixed using other answers.  As such, they would even flag such comments as obsolete after having utilized the [creative commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) advantage.

Moreover, if people don't expect to be a given a reason for upvotes then asking reasons for downvotes appears to be highly irrational.

Answer (score 7):

I'll downvote if I can see the answer is wrong. Sometimes I used to comment explaining why, sometimes not. Strategy is this:

Does it look like a crap and far away from what is being asked? Downvote and move away. (I believe more downvotes will be fired on the same answer and eventually will be deleted.)

Does he/she try to answer, but something wrong with the answer? I'll downvote and explain why. Sometime I'm lazy to comment, I'll downvote and wait for OP to see whether he edits/deletes/ask for reason? If he asks for a reason, I'd provide reason.

I guess most of the people follow some kind of strategy in downvoting. It really hurts if someone doesn't explain a downvote. *They don't give us a chance to learn if at all we're wrong*. So, **I'd not say it is not constructive**. It sometimes helps you to learn the reason for a downvote.

Last but not least: I've seen [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) asking for "@Downvoter care to comment?". If asking reason for downvote is just noise, I don't think Jon will add noise to the community :)

Comment: Rather than downvote answers that are correct but for a small error or typo or something you should **edit** instead of downvote.

Answer (score 6):

Asking for reason why post was downvoted doesn't sound like something nonconstructive, since the author wants to know what he did wrong (and hopefully improve it). However is there any way for such comment to reach the downvoter? If not, then the comment ends up serving no purpose and is in fact redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Asking why they got downvoted is not not-constructive. The user obviously thinks his answer is alright, and doesn't know why it'd be voted down. So he asks why it was, because he doesn't know if he's made a mistake or not. And if he has made a mistake, he wants to know about it, so he can learn what he did wrong, and then possibly update his answer too. Also, it can benefit other users than the answerer, since they may see nothing wrong with the answer either, and be wondering why it was downvoted too.

Obviously there are exceptions to this. Like if a user has +4 or more already on an answer and he gets 1 downvote.. It is rather annoying for people to complain about receiving a downvote on posts that are already fairly or highly upvoted. And users shouldn't do this every time they receive a downvote. Only when they are really not sure if their answer is correct, and would like to learn themselves and possibly improve their answer.

Answer (score -10):

#### Not Constructive

Asking for something that was not volunteered is asking for **discussion** and **conversation** both of which turn into arguments and neither of which are on topic for Stack Overflow.

#### Ban boilerplate comments on downvoting as well

Boilerplate comments that say things like "read the FAQ", "show your work", etc are banned, I think we should ban the various whiny comments about downvoting as well. "downvoter explain", "why the downvote", "@Downvoter care to comment?" etc.

Comment: Goodness that's negative. Not all conversations will turn into arguments. I've had plenty of conversations that turned out to be good conversations, even if the beginning of the conversation was a critique on something related me. And if discussion and conversations are not 'on topic for stackoverflow', why have a comments section? Why have chat rooms?

Comment: @ouflak you are proving my point for me here with your judgement of my opinion, which is negative without any positive critique, this is why I never comment when I exercise my right to vote or moderate and never will.

Comment: It's a bit hard to have a discussion with polaric views (i.e. "negative without any positive critique"); that's not the same thing as pointing out (the obvious) failings in a post to an author who isn't aware of them. Sure some people won't take critizism gracefully but e.g. the majority of my "xyz -1" comments result in the post being edited, and (hopefully) the author learning something in the process.

Comment: Supporters of this answer may also be interested in my feature request for [One-flag deletion of "@downvoter", "why downvote", and similar comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175394). Detractors may be interested, too, I suppose.

Comment: If I submit an answer (implying that I assume both that it is a correct statement of fact and also that it answers the question), an uncommented downvote means to me that someone thinks I have got one of these two aspects wrong. In that case there is clearly an issue that needs fixing. So we end up with worse quality than necessary. I would expect the downvoter to tell me (briefly if they are busy) why they think I have the wrong end of the stick. I would always provide such a comment myself if downvoting an answer. If we end up having a constructive argument, that's fine by me.

Answer (score -13):

People who look for fairness on the Internet deserve neither.

I think there are people who downvote out of spite (if, say, their answer was downvoted, because it was wrong and the right answer is added shortly after).  I also think there are people who click around, downvoting everything just because. If I do downvote I try to mention the reasoning why (usually it's something like "This query does not give the intended results. It is missing X").

Comment: The first line seems nonsensical. So one deserves fairness only if one is not looking for it on the internet?

Comment: No, only if they expect to find it on the internet.  People are cruel animals, add in anonymity and you get the worst of people

Comment: Thanks, upvoted because I think I understand the answer now.

Comment: *Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.* - Hanlon's Razor

Comment: They're all morons - Dr. House

Comment: Your proposal that all or most (down)votes are borne of emotional reaction rather than critical judgement seems baseless, but if you have actual evidence that it's the case, you should really present it, because it would constitute a complete undermining of the fundamentals of the SE engine.

Answer (score -20):

Explanation of downvote is the way to be polite to other members of community. So all downvotes must be protected with explanation.
Ok, if to be polite is not enough for you one more thing, it looks like coward behavior - hit and run and yes that's another way to keep the discussion constructive - hold off from unreasonable downvotes.

Comment: You dug up an _old_ meta question to post an answer that's simply missing, completely, how the SE network works... In broken English.

Comment: Yes, English is not my native language. But what's wrong with exactly this answer regarding grammar of my "broken" English?

Comment: The first sentence is simply incorrect. Sure, it would be nice to give an explanation for the downvote, but it's not something users "must" do. Second one: _"here one more point"_ _"way to keep discuss"_ ... What?
English ain't my native language either. That's no excuse.

Comment: Current edition of my answer - this is translation by Google Translate. Big difference, yeah? And you know what - in this world there is lot of opinions different from your.

Comment: "Google translate" doesn't know English grammar, just English words...

Comment: There are plenty of opinions. Yours just isn't a popular one, as has been established time and time again.

Comment: @Bart: for a second there, I thought andrey replied that to me xD _"wtf o.O"_

Comment: Regarding opinions, yes, to Cerbrus.