# Should we edit questions that will be definitely closed?

Tags: discussion, edits

I always face questions that will be closed for sure. For example:

---

> Hi all i want a code that finds the maximum number in array in Java. I
>   write the following:
>
> public static void main(String args[]) { //stuck here }

---

This question can be edited like this:

> <strike>Hi all i</strike>  I want a code that finds the maximum number
>   in array <strike>in Java</strike>. I <strike>write</strike> wrote the
>   following:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String args[]) {
>       //stuck here 
> }
> ```

But it's obvious that the question *will* be closed. Now the question is, should I edit/approve edits on questions like this one? IMHO it's redundant because it'll be closed/deleted anyway..  What do you think?

Comment: There are no questions which will definitely be closed, because people persist in answering questions which don't deserve the effort.

Comment: Sometimes you just know that the question will be closed, regardless if it's get answered or not.

Comment: No.   I've seen questions worse than the one above get answered (and not closed).

Comment: I edit them some times, because I secretly (and vainly?) hope that a minor improvement as an edit may lead the author to reformulate and improve its own question.

Comment: @Larme I tend to do that sometimes.. But the more you stay on Stackoverflow the more you know when to lose hope on some questions.

Comment: Yep, it's getting worse here. I've flagged hundreds of questions but I'm getting bored of it now.   We need a plan b.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#comment11155_252531

Comment: "How can I programmatically determine the maximum possible length of an array in Java?" would be an on-topic question.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327885/is-it-useful-to-edit-a-question-i-will-vote-to-close

Comment: I think Shog has said, at one time or another, "don't try to predict the future of questions; just act on it based on its current state". He wasn't talking about editing questions specifically, as I recall, but the guidance still applies IMO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think it is worth editing. It ties into another question on meta [Is asking reasons for downvote in comments non-constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive?cb=1)

Sure the question will be closed but the edit and giving reasons for why a question is downvoted create a feedback loop which in the best case nurtures better use of SO by the OP.

For example, I used to say "Hi" in my questions because I thought I was being polite but after being edited out of my question twice I stopped - simples.

Comment: So is it OK fro you to edit a question and then vote to close? Once I was told that I shouldn't do that.. I'm really confused.

Comment: I think we should think of editing and voting to close as two isolated decisions. Therefore, yes, edit and then vote to close. That's like correcting someone's English grammar and saying "Well, but that is not a great question anyway".

Comment: I also edit to be able to better understand the question, to see if there is anything to salvage and so on.

Comment: Agreed. However, a closed question should not be edited unless the edits bring it in shape to be reopened. Only the first edit to a question puts it in the reopen review queue, editing the question robs the OP of the chance to get their question reopened.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - I've seen this sequence of events: low rep user edits question that should be closed. Then question is closed. Reviewers (or quite often the OP) accept the useless edits. Question now appears on the reopen queue. After 5 further reviews question stays closed.  Editing questions that *should be closed* just risks going through this pointless cycle

Answer (score 6):

Expanding a bit on [Peter's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253077/should-we-edit-questions-that-will-be-definitely-closed/253080#253080), I do edit this type of questions if there is hope that the OP will learn from the edit. Factors that weight in my decision:

- It's not a help vampire.
- It's not the first question.
- It's not a *userXXXXX* (in hand with being vampire).
- It's just missing more information and an OP edit will save the question.

Normally, I try to give a good edit summary, so as to educate the OP, and considering that they will follow the notification *"An edit was made to your post"*. In some cases (all factors were met), a comment to reinforce.

Comment: "It's not a userXXXXX (in hand with being vampire)" this seems completely unfair -- users are assigned a username in that format upon registration. We shouldn't malign them or falsely associate them with a certain subgroup of bad users just because they haven't or don't care to select a custom username.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to **not** edit questions that should definitely be closed. The reasons:

- pops the edit onto the edit review queue. This is a waste of reviewers time if the question is going to be closed anyway.
- If the edit is approved *after* the question has been closed, it then pops the question onto the reopen queue. Most likely with edits that will *not* mean it can now be reopened, but just further wasting reviewers time
- An edit that pushes the question onto the reopen queue (with pointless edits that do not save the question) then prevents any later, more substantial edits made by the questioner from appearing on the reopen queue.

The only exceptions might be if:

- the editor has enough reputation points that the edits don't get pushed to the review queue OR
- edits will save the question from being closed

Anything else isn't just wasting your time, but also the time of several reviewers. It also possibly **prevents** the questioner's chances of making a 'Hail Mary' edit that could legitimately save the question, as the second batch of edits will [not push the question to the reopen queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue).

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't edit the question.

I would just leave a comment asking them to improve the question. And then if they ask how then I might provide some suggestions.

But of the times I've done this, an answer was provided, and they just marked it as correct and disappeared.