# Is this really what we should consider "unwelcoming"?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, welcoming

Quoting from today's blog post [*"Welcome Wagon: Classifying Comments on Stack Overflow"*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/07/10/welcome-wagon-classifying-comments-on-stack-overflow):

> According to those of us deeply involved here and familiar with Stack Overflow, about 7% of comments on Stack Overflow are unwelcoming. What did some unwelcoming comments look like?
>
> - “No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.”
> - “And this is tagged Javascript why?”
> - “Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design.”
> - “For the last time, use the serial number code and replace kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey with kIOPlatformUUIDKey“
> - “Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I have already told how you can bind to the property. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”

The second example aside, ***this*** is what's (supposedly) unwelcoming and what is now banned under the new code of conduct? We cannot tell people anymore that they need to provide an MCVE? That they're obviously doing something wrong they didn't tell us about? That they're not listening to what has been suggested¹? Or that their general approach to a problem is misguided?

## Are you kidding me?

Please tell me what we're supposed to be doing instead then. Walk away and don't provide any help at all rather than call a spade a spade?

---

**Update**

Apparently the original examples in the blog post have been updated with more generic ones:

> According to those of us deeply involved here and familiar with Stack Overflow, about 7% of comments on Stack Overflow are unwelcoming. What did some unwelcoming comments look like? These combine elements of real comments to show typical examples.
>
> - “This is becoming a waste of my time and you won’t listen to my advice. What are the supposed benefits of making it so much more complex?”
> - “Step 1. Do not clutter the namespace. Then get back to us.”
> - “The code you posted cannot yield this result. Please post the real code if you hope to get any help.”
> - “This error is self explanatory. You need to check…”
> - “I have already told how you can… If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”

Some of these I'd be more on board with (like the first one), but with others (specifically the third one) I'm not. If somebody is lying about their code they need to be told exactly that. We cannot help with fabricated examples that won't demonstrate the actual problem.

---

¹ Had a case like that just today.

Comment: [comments archived](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/174741/discussion-on-question-by-ansgar-wiechers-is-this-really-what-we-should-consider); this is an honest question, please try to provide an answer rather than arguing with the asker.

Comment: It looks like for the last example they just chopped up the comment to remove a bunch of context relevant context that greatly impacts how the comment reads.  Honestly that just makes SO look bad in my eyes that they'd resort to something like that.

Comment: @Servy Exactly, I find it rather egregious, I mean, if there really are so many unwelcoming comments, other than the anonymity aspect, why make them up at all?

Comment: Because, @DavidG, the purpose of the blog post wasn't to initiate some sort of witch-hunt against specific comments or their authors. Ideally, we'd have picked some examples that weren't quite so easy to find (let's be honest: how many people are answering COM-in-C# questions here anymore) but what's done is done.

Comment: As mentioned below, we should be addressing the issues, all of them, not just one aspect of them. SO (SE?) should be saying 'new users need work harder on their questions and older users need to work on their snark' not 'older users are unwelcoming and here is a tiny amount of one sided data to prove so'. I do believe SO (SE?) made a mistake when trying to address this issue by making it about one side rather than being neutral and trying to work amongst the community to solve the issues on all sides.

Comment: @Shog9 but the witch hunt seems to be of a much larger group, the "old" users, this ties in with my comment above, in trying to solve the issue SO (SE?) have started a witch hunt themselves and it seems that a lot of people are quite offended / hurt by that.

Comment: See... that's an easy story to tell, ain't it @Script47? The paternalistic "experts are being mean to new users" thing has been cropping up since the day SO launched. But... Is it true? I sure as hell see an awful lot of pretty vile stuff from new users... And that's the point of doing a project like this: separate anecdotes from what's actually happening on the site.

Comment: should be rosecoloredoverflow.com

Comment: For the third comment, a little bit of rewording would make it less confrontational. "The code you posted cannot yield this result. Please post the exact code so that we can better help you." might be a better wording.

Comment: Maybe we should consider the possibility that *any* comment that isn't an all-out praise or pat-on-the-back for the intended receiver is automatically an unwelcoming comment. IOW, it's impossible to make a comment both useful and welcoming without jumping through creative literary hoops that only experienced writers are capable of.

Comment: To me it is a matter of "snarkiness." If a poster made a naive, even "bone-headed" mistake, why assume that they made that mistake *knowingly* or by apathy. Anyone in the world can post on SO and the best thing we can do to harbor a productive community is to redirect *without making someone feel stupid.* Making someone feel stupid is communicating the message *and adding insult* and that last part is superfluous. Let others with cooler heads educate the poster if you can't see fit to yourself. "Snarkiness" can only upset and/or make a poster leave. Is that really what we want?

Comment: @Mysticial we all need to learn from [UK's Members of the House of Commons](https://www.c-span.org/video/?c4657788/trumps-intellectual-capacity-protozoan)

Comment: @Braiam "Would the right honourable gentleman please fix his shoddy code"?

Comment: @DavidG: now that you mention it, I've seen more than a few posts where I thought the poster was *tired and emotional*. But I've always been too polite to comment on it.

Comment: The only comment you'll ever need is, _"My responses are limited. You must ask the right question."_

Comment: And that would not be perceived unwelcoming ... how?

Comment: @Shog9 Then why aren't the truly vile comments being singled out?  Posts like this make it seem like such comments don't actually exist.

Comment: Umm... I certainly did not mean to give that impression. And I for one do flag such comments when I come across them. I wouldn't agree, however, that this kind of comment is as rampant as some people make it out to be.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry, I meant the blog post.  If the point of this project is to separate out and classify the "vile" comments as Shog9 suggests, then posting a summary of results _without_ such comments gives the impression that such comments don't exist.

Comment: How much of that would you feel comfortable saying to your super-naive-and-innocent 12-year-old niece, or your CEO or president?

Comment: @Dukeling What makes you think family or people who actually pay for my time don't get special privileges?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Are politeness and respect special privileges for you? (Of course in some cases you might actually want to help those you wouldn't help here, and thus avoid some of what was said that way, but I'm talking about how you phrase the same basic message, not which message you want to communicate.)

Comment: Respect is something that must be earned, but common courtesy (I think that's what you're actually referring to) is indeed something everyone is entitled to. At first. Courtesy is not in unlimited supply, however, and I don't believe it should be.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Well, my point was that, if you wouldn't say those things to those I mentioned, it would presumably be because you realise there's at least *something* "off" about them (which may also lead you to thinking maybe you shouldn't go around saying such things to strangers). Although, if you think you should **not** (try to) treat everyone with the same amount of respect when speaking to them, I can't really argue with that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Please don't claim "Respect is something that must be earned" as a cold hard fact. Perhaps *your* respect must be earned, but there are many people who freely [give their respect to people first](http://thepositivitysolution.com/respect-is-not-earned/), then perhaps a person may later lose their respect through poor actions or words, but they simply choose to respect a person at first sight. Not everyone lives by your "Respect is something that must be earned" ideology.

Comment: @DavyM What other people want to give freely is for them to decide. What I'm saying is that respect is not something someone can *demand* from you. Common courtesy is (under normal circumstances).

Comment: @Izkata: "*Then why aren't the truly vile comments being singled out?*" Because nobody's *defending them*. You don't see heavily upvoted MSO posts debating whether some new user's rant on people who are trying to help them is worthwhile content. And the site has never *condoned* such behavior either. The point of all of this is to bring to light things that some people seem to believe is OK behavior, but it really shouldn't be.

Comment: @NicolBolas You haven't addressed Shog9's comment, what I was replying to, which seems to be conflating these mild comments with those "vile" comments no one would defend.

Comment: @Izkata: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. The behavior is inappropriate, whether "mild" or "vile". That's the point being made. The goal is not merely to remove the lowest of the low and then pat ourselves on the back. We *already do that*. The goal is to let everyone know that these kinds of "mild" comments are not considered "mild" and won't be tolerated.

Comment: In my opinion this is worth tackling if and only if the much more prevalent trend of new users insulting and belittling curators has been curbed to acceptable levels.

Comment: When I see questions like this, I really wish that SO also had a proper *discussion* forum without voting.

Comment: Part of the misunderstanding here is that "respect" has (at least) two different meanings. One is usually extended to all people: the "treating others with respect" thing (though some people may forfeit being treated with respect by their own actions). This meaning of respect, which is usually synonymous with "common courtesy" is a thing that does not need to be earned. The other is the sense of "I have a lot of respect for that guy". *That* one is definitely earned: if I know nothing about you, I have no reason (yet) to respect you, though I should still treat you with respect.

Comment: @NicolBolas - If examples #3 and #5 (in the original set) are not to be tolerated, then what you're going to see is people refraining from criticising other people's code. There is nothing, repeat NOTHING, that can reasonably be considered a personal attack in those two examples. When I see comments like yours ("these kind of "mild" comments are not considered "mild" and won't be tolerated"), I get worried. Because if criticizing someone's design or asking for the *real* code is going to be considered equivalent to a personal attack, experienced coders are just going to stop helping people.

Comment: I actually received these kinds of comments a few times, it actually justifies that, what I am actually doing is wrong. I personally want to here something like this as blunt as you can give without any shortcuts. atleast, the commenter, or the person actually trying to help me, helps me learn something. I might even disturbing his time so, I should be grateful.

Comment: Just stop commenting completely, _someone_ will always be offended, only flag and close - and then see how welcoming it will to new users that the question will be closed or simply be ignored without any helpful comment.

Comment: As an example of the misunderstanding caused by the two meanings of "respect", the article that @DavyM linked misleadingly conflates the two. The author starts out by asking her friend to look at two groups of people, and ask which deserves "respect *and admiration*" (emphasis mine). This is clearly the "earned respect" category: professionals like doctors earn respect by completing a grueling course of education. Then the article goes on to condemn *treating people with disrespect*, which is the "common courtesy" category. Conflating two meanings like that always leads to confusion. Avoid it.

Comment: I would rather see someone get the message that they should never use [non-parameterized SQL](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) because several people were really adamant (even snarky!) about it, and walk away a better programmer, than making sure they don't get their feelings hurt.

Comment: @LukasGraf I prefer the option where we try to make them a better programmer *and* not chase them away by being snarky.

Comment: @Dukeling - Someone could be offended by some of the other comments, yes. But I was only taking about #3 and #5 (of the original comments), and Kendra agrees with me that *neither of them is offensive*. #5 fails to be as helpful as possible because "you are doing something wrong" doesn't explain *what* is wrong, and #3 says "your design is wrong" without explaining *how* the design is wrong. So re the specific comments I'm referring to as unoffensive, Kendra also agrees that they are unoffensive. Yes, they could be better... but they are not **unwelcoming**, and that's the point of contention.

Comment: @Dukeling The problem is that nothing anyone could write will ever be "entirely inoffensive". There's always a chance that *someone* will take offense.

Comment: I would see a problem if the users we actually *want* here (those who are willing and capable to learn) felt unwelcome. I do not see a problem if those who we don't want here (mostly the ones who are unwilling to learn and are just looking for someone to do their work for them) felt unwelcome. Because they are. One of the problems I have with the current "Welcome Wagon" initiative is that I don't see any attempt to distinguish one from the other.

Comment: So how should I deal with someone who is actually really wasting my time because he does not listen to the suggestions? Should I simply stop interacting? How can he than improve? How can he understand that the answer is right before his eyes already? Do we really want to start a tap dance for someone who might not be able to deal with critics? `"You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress."` is criticism and it is constructive as well. Why consider it unwelcoming?

Comment: @Dukeling But, as I already mentioned elsewhere, those are the ones complaining about how unwelcoming SO is. Which brings us full circle. And FTR, I usually don't go and try to hurt someone's feelings. But with some people I really couldn't care less how they're feeling. And I really do not feel like going above and beyond trying to *avoid* hurting their feelings.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: "*Should I simply stop interacting? How can he than improve?*" If he's not listening to you, then you're not going to make him improve. That means it's time to disengage.

Comment: @rmunn: "*If examples #3 and #5 (in the original set) are not to be tolerated, then what you're going to see is people refraining from criticising other people's code. There is nothing, repeat NOTHING, that can reasonably be considered a personal attack in those two examples.*" There are several answers here that explain what the problem with those two comments is, and each of them provide less aggressive alternatives. If you cannot find a way to criticize other people's code without being aggressive about it, then it's best if you let someone else do it.

Comment: @NicolBolas That is a perceived problem, particularly for #3 (after the update). I do not agree in the least that there is any actual, arguable problem at all with that wording. Could it be worded differently? Sure. But if someone perceives a response like #3 as offensive the problem is with *them*, not with the person stating the fact.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: "*One of the problems I have with the current "Welcome Wagon" initiative is that I don't see any attempt to distinguish one from the other.*" How do you know which users we do and don't want until they actually start posting? If users are scared off from SO due to aggressive behavior from its userbase, how do you know that it's only bad users who are not posting? Unless "good user" is defined by the ability to tolerate jerks, being jerks is not an effective tool for culling good users from bad.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is not about allowing people to be jerks, and never was.

Comment: I don’t understand the answers to this question. Dissecting those particular comment examples is not really helpful especially not when done in a huge walls of text. – The originally mentioned comments clearly lack the context in which they were taken from, so discussing them is not really getting anywhere. At least three of those have previous discourse which is likely some going back and forth that didn’t lead anywhere because OP is not considerate or understanding. Sounds more like we need to stop doing exactly *that* back-and-forth talking, and should close questions faster to move away.

Comment: @poke Well, part of the problem with the comments might be that they're part of an extended discussion, but the other part is that they're just not very nice. Both parts require fixing (if you prevent extended discussion, you'll still have people leaving unwelcoming first comments, and if you prevent unwelcoming comments, you'll still have people engaging in extended discussion).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: "*This is not about allowing people to be jerks, and never was.*" That's only true if you start from the premise that these comments are OK. If someone looks at these comments and see that they're not OK, then  from their perspective, you're effectively arguing for the right for people to post non-OK stuff: being jerks. So the question really comes down to which perspective should be accepted. Why is your perspective good, when the same information can be communicated in a way that *everyone agrees* is OK?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Or to put it another way, why is "arguably acceptable" better than "certainly good"? Because you don't personally agree with the argument?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's better. But I would definitely say it isn't worse.

Comment: @NicolBolas Because not everyone agrees that they are OK.  Adding artificial politeness instead of getting directly to the point dances around the issue instead of actually helping the person.

Comment: @Izkata: What "artificial politeness" is being added by the answers? And these comments *don't* get directly to the point. They dance around the issue by saying things like "This is now rather a waste of time.", "For the last time", "I have already told".\

Comment: I really don't think *"“The code you posted cannot yield this result. Please post the real code if you hope to get any help.”* is unwelcoming... They're clear, concise and even say please! Aren't there any better examples to use?

Comment: A big part of the argument seems to stem from the misunderstanding between the definition for "unwelcoming" being interpreted as "rude". Rudeness is part of it but I've seen extremely polite comments that are still completely unwelcoming. The focus should be on things that are "papercuts", i.e. a first experience on the site that leaves the user not wanting to come back. This may or may not be down to rudeness.

Comment: These kind of posts always make me sad.  It seems like more energy is spent trying to justify being anywhere from slightly prickly to outright rude than people trying to dial back their 'snark'.  The examples given suck, but there are some very rude people on here.

Comment: @NicolBolas - "why is "arguably acceptable" better than "certainly good"?" Simple: *because it takes less time to write*. Comments are dashed-off kinds of things. If every time I leave a comment, I have to stop and spend 15 minutes trying to parse it to ensure that my blunt, factual sentence can't be misunderstood as hostility... then I'm not going to bother leaving a comment at all if it take that much work, and then newbies won't learn what they're doing wrong. As I said earlier, I fear that experienced coders are just going to stop helping people, and that will harm Stack Overflow.

Comment: In other words, *don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good*. Could some of these questions have been rephrased? **Absolutely**. But what I don't see the blog post considering **at all** is what it *costs* to write a perfectly-phrased comment. It costs far more time to write something perfect than something that's good enough. And if the standard for comments is being raised to "nobody can possibly misunderstand this as a personal attack", well, that's making the perfect the enemy of the good. The standard for comments **needs** to be "good enough" or almost nobody will write them anymore.

Comment: @NicolBolas That you've singled out those particular phrases proves my point.  Those are not dancing around the issue, those are the meat of those comments - they all mean the same thing and have already been sugarcoated from the direct response of "You've already been given an answer/way forward/thing to try.  Instead of ignoring it, go and actually try it before responding again.", but aren't recognizable as such because they've already been restrained by such artificial politeness.

Comment: @rmunn: If it *genuinely* takes you 15 minutes to remove the hostility from a post, I'm concerned about how useful your comments are being. And why are these comments "good enough"? Who made that decision? Can that decision be appealed? Who is the final arbiter of that choice?

Comment: @Izkata: "*have already been sugarcoated from the direct response of "You've already been given an answer/way forward/thing to try. Instead of ignoring it, go and actually try it before responding again."*" Then the comments are without content and thus do not need to be posted. If you've said X, then you've said it. Saying it again provides no useful information compared to saying it the first time. The comment is therefore *not being helpful* to anyone.

Comment: @Izkata: And to call comments like "For the last time" artificial politeness is pretty ridiculous. That's what you say when you're *frustrated*, not when you're being helpful or even neutral. It's what you say when you're done with being helpful and just want to vent. There is absolutely nothing polite about that, artificial or otherwise. The fact that you consider this to be the "polite" form of address suggests that we have a fundamental misunderstanding of the word.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Okay, 15 minutes is probably an exaggeration, but I don't think 5 minutes would be exaggerated. If I write a comment that isn't intended as hostile, but I have to stop and parse it... that's not something you can do quickly. Note that I'm not defending "This is a waste of my time" comments; I'm specifically defending "something’s gone very, very wrong with your design" and "If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.” Neither of these are hostile. The latter *could* be read as hostile, but if I had written that, my intention would be to help. (Continued...)

Comment: And while the problem with the "doing something wrong" comment is that it's too vague, the big problem with the *blog post*, which is what so many people are complaining about, is that it has lumped in hostile comments ("this is a waste of time") with non-hostile ones ("you're doing something wrong", which is only a problem due to vagueness). **This implies that these vague comments are seen as hostile**. THAT is what I've been objecting to from the beginning. I don't want to have to take X number of minutes to make sure that nobody could POSSIBLY misread my short, factually-based comment.

Comment: @NicolBolas - To make sure that we're not arguing past each other: do you consider "something’s gone very, very wrong with your design" to be hostile? If so, why? And do you consider "if you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong” to be hostile? If so, why? If you don't consider either of *those two* examples, which are the specific ones I mentioned in my first comment, then you're arguing against a position that I'm not actually taking and we're more in agreement than it seems. I'm not saying that hostile comments are okay, I'm saying that *those two comments aren't hostile*.

Comment: @rmunn: Look at Izkata's comments here. *You* may not be defending "This is a waste of my time", but Izkata (and others) very much *are* defending them. To them, these comments are perfectly fine, and you (and I) are the ones conflating non-hostile comments for hostile ones. Basically, you're using the same argument as they are, just with a different set of comments. So who's right here? Me? You? Izkata?

Comment: @NicolBolas - As far as I can tell, Izkata is never claiming that "this is a waste of my time" is not a hostile comment. Rather, he's claiming that *some hostile comments are necessary*. I.e., the comment that said "This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice", while hostile on its face, is a *kinder thing to do* than walking away and not leaving a comment. If you never tell someone they're making a mistake, they have no opportunity to learn, so a comment like that one is **kinder than silence**.

Comment: One more thing: after reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252235/2314532, I think I'm coming to agree with the position that a borderline-hostile comment is **kinder than silence**. Note the accepted answer to that question. The user who write it, who describes herself as a "*clear* noob" (emphasis in original), explicitly states that she would rather receive "mean" feedback than NO feedback. Note that her examples of "mean" feedback  are  "too long", "already asked". "google search this", and "obvious homework problem", none of which are snarky: snark may harm rather than help.

Comment: @rmunn the people that come to Meta (who are students at Berkeley, no less!) and post well-crafted messages are in the *vast* minority. Instead you should rely on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311504/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-or-discourage-a-second-question by Jon Ericson (that's not to say Jon's post comes to a different conclusion, though; I leave that to you).

Comment: @DrEval The comment was given as an example of being unwelcoming, not offensive. Also, your comment *is* highly offensive by both the old Be Nice standard and the new Code of Conduct.

Comment: @TylerH As I understand it, this is one of the most popular resources for programming on the Internet.  What's behind this "let's be nice" thing? Are we losing users, chasing new ones, what?  We need to be careful not to replace too many long standing, experienced developers with..uh...people who don't fall into that category.

Comment: The real question here is: why is there always a massive clash between the community and SO staff every time any of the latter is making a blog post? That's been going on the past 1-2 years. But perhaps that's a topic for another post...

Comment: @DrEval Well, the purpose of all this is to be more welcoming so that we don't chase away new/unexperienced developers, who might become contributors to the site at some point, and that's all fine and dandy. However, I fear that the measures that are being put in place now will not have that effect, but will instead lead to more silent down-/closevotes, more frustration on all sides, and in the worst case an exodus of experienced contributors.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Exactly.  There are already sites in SE which I can't post to because I can't just type what I feel for fear of triggering someone. I hope SO doesn't end up like that otherwise I'll just stop helping altogether.  Let's not be rude, of course, but let's also make people aware that the statement "there are no stupid questions" is not true. At least, there are lazy, sloppy questions which treat the site like a code-writing/debugging add-on.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, another thing I see a lot of is cold, matter of fact answers that state with certainty that things cannot be done. When they can. Almost anything can be done, some things are just an unreasonable amount of work.

Comment: I fail to see how this is related.

Comment: @DrEval Basic human decency and the entire history of social science are behind the "let's be nice" thing. You get better results and have nicer things by being nice. The concerns over this have been covered exhaustively in blog posts and meta discussions so I won't spend time in a comment rehashing them.

Comment: @BobJarvis There is nothing racist about the phrase ["call a spade a spade"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_a_spade_a_spade).

Comment: On the contrary - I was nearly court martialed in the Navy for (unwittingly) using that phrase. A lesson I learned the hard way...

Comment: ***Best. Meta. Post. Ever.***  This is a topic where SE the company totally takes for granted their community in favor of maximizing the # of new users. They seem to forget the curation is what makes this site popular and useful. Can they pursue maximizing the # of new users to the point where it destroys their community or sets them up to be disrupted? I have a feeling we'll find out...

Comment: @BobJarvis Well, we're not in the Navy here.

Comment: @BobJarvis Sorry that you had to suffer from that, but I reject the idea that words have to be tabbooed because a very small subset of humans decided to use them wrongly. Spade have a definition, that is not racist, and it's that one that humans on earth searching for its definition will understand.

Comment: @Hack-R I just had a few very reasonable comments removed from this thread.  I spend quite a lot of time on SE sites, and have done over the years, but I think from now on I'm going to stop answering, commenting, voting etc on SE sites from today, and just come here when I need help. Actually deleting your account is pretty easy here. See ya.

Comment: [Some more real comments](https://postimg.cc/gallery/zvneclem/) :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is unwelcoming, you have high reputation that is why this question is not downvoted.

Comment: @Lundin Everyone dislikes change, compounded by the fact the current users are the subset who *likes* the status quo. My hypothesis anyways.

Comment: @SurajJain That's just plain nonsense. People don't seem to have problems downvoting answers of mine on the main site, where it actually costs them reputation, so why would my reputation matter on meta where votes come at no cost at all? And since votes are anonymous, what would people hope to gain from sucking up to me?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I meant that people usually go in herds here, if see one downvote on the post they will downvote it without bothering what it is. On stackoverflow people when downvote my answer and then give me stupid reasons they ignore those reasons when the same is posted by high reputation person.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Your question was spot on, and was good. I only meant that if I wrote that question It would have gotten more downvotes than upvotes.

Comment: @SurajJain - So what you find unwelcoming is when people downvote your answers without leaving a comment explaining how the answer could have been improved? I agree, and so does [this person](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252235/2314532). Yet the blog post that we are all discussing here was suggesting that *comment about what is wrong with the user's code* are seen as unwelcoming, and that instead of leaving a comment on a bad question, you should just downvote it without comment. Which is precisely what you find to be unwelcoming! They're getting it the wrong way around.

Comment: As for downvoting *questions*, remember that [downvotes mean something different on the Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites) than on the main Stack Overflow site, and downvotes on Meta don't affect your reputation at all. If someone downvotes your question on Meta, they probably won't leave a comment explaining why. But *don't take it personally* because it does not harm you at all.

Comment: @rmunn I'm not a fan of silent downvotes myself, b/c if someone thinks there's anything wrong with my answers I'd like to know what that is, so I can either fix it or explain their misunderstanding. However, I also see the other side of this. I tend to comment when downvoting, explaining what I consider wrong with a post, and I have received my share of revenge downvotes for doing so. I can see why people prefer silent downvotes. And I don't think making a downvote reason mandatory would help in the least. IMO that'd only lead to less downvotes, and in turn to decreased content quality.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Re: the feat of revenge downvotes, [there's a feature request from 2014 (!)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280040/raise-flag-for-obvious-revenge-downvotes) that would solve that. Implementing that feature would be a FAR better use of the Stack Exchange staff's time than trying to police comments for tone. But it's only received 15 upvotes to date (now it has 16 because I just upvoted it) so I doubt much attention is being paid to the request. Which is a shame, because automatically catching revenge downvotes wouldn't be hard and would do a LOT to fix SO's problems.

Comment: @rmunn The behavior I usually see is that I downvote an answer, explain my reasons, and in turn get a silent downvote on my own answer. I doubt that the requested feature would be able to catch that (after all a single downvote, even if it comes from the person whose answer I just downvoted, might be perfectly legitimate). Still, I agree that the requested feature would be a lot more useful than what we'll probably be getting here.

Comment: That is nonsense @SurajJain. Low reputation users get upvoted posts on a weekly basis (see a few of the other questions about the comments, for instance). I mean, look at the first answer in this very Q&A!!!! A super highly voted answer by a low reputation user!

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou could you please give some examples of comments that are polite but unwelcoming? Also you might like to add your own answer.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier You did not get what  I said, they get upvoted but chances are that people will also downvote them more than they will if it was by hig rep person. I wrote a answer it got upvoted but many downvotes too, I asked reason people gave all sort of reason, but answer below me was having all those reasons and much more but was high rep person, so people overlooked those mistakes. That was what I said.

Comment: @SurajJain - You have mentioned several times that people have downvoted your answers on SO and upvoted other people's answers with similar problems. On which question(s) did this happen? I looked through your SO user profile and I can't find any answer of yours that has received a significant number of downvotes. So if you could point me to the answer(s) you're talking about, that would help.

Comment: @smci this is the kind of thing one sees all the time but cannot recount specific examples because one does not take notes at the time. The only specific case I can remember is from 3-4 days ago, when a new user seems to have made an account specifically just to ask if there was any progress with an issue (on one of my questions). Since he's a new user with a rep of 1, he could not comment or otherwise interact in any other way other than to ask this in the form of an answer. This prompted another user to give the knee-jerk reply of "this is not an answer, this should be a comment bla bla"

Comment: @smci (cont'd) which, while not rude, was frustratingly pointless, like when one gets stuck in an automated support call, only to keep ending up back at the main menu again, which can be very frustrating. Also, the person who commented knew this is the case because they said something along those lines in the comment (i.e. "if you contribute to SO a bit more you'll have enough rep to come back and ask this as a comment").  In the end I replied to their 'answer' to say "thank you I will update my question with progress made" and asked them to delete their 'answer' to appease the commenter.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I would consider either response absolutely appropriate. Not having enough reputation to comment is not an invitation to go ahead and do what you already know (or at least should know) you're not supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm replying to a question of "show an example where a first user feels unwelcome even though no rudeness was involved". I agree with you, and that they need to be informed. But the way it was stated is such that it would feel unwelcoming. I guess what I'm trying to say is, often a first user gets the same feeling like an amazon customer feels when calling automated tech support. The robot at the other end is polite af, but the experience is far from welcoming; especially if after 30 minutes on the phone you haven't actually progressed.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers also, I always view such interactions in light of how it would feel if this exchange had happened in real life. Imagine walking in a cafe saying "what time do you open". And instead, the person in there said, "It is inappropriate to ask barristas questions before opening time. Please come back when we're open and ask your question. Also, we expect people who ask questions to buy products from the shop as curtesy.". A polite answer, you will agree, but one that is unwelcoming and doesn't actually answer a simple question. Would you go back to that shop as a customer later?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I appreciate that, but I still don't see either response as anywhere out of line. If someone does something they're not supposed to do it's perfectly fine to tell them "you're not supposed to do that". And I don't believe we want to be welcoming to transgressions.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes I agree, and in fact I think this is the crux of the problem. On one hand, we are not 'customer service', and any expectations that we are should be remedied immediately and assertively, which may come across as rude. On the complete opposite end of the spectrum, for not necessarily wrong reasons, we may behave online in ways that would undoubtedly be considered rude in the real world, whereas online it is a matter of interpretation and 'online culture'. Effectively the problem arises when a large number rightfully perceives otherwise typical online behaviour as unwelcoming

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: ok but comment-as-answer-due-to-low-rep is one of several known-issues with SO's system. I was asking for more general examples of comments that are polite but unwelcoming (without referencing privileges, rep, etc.)? I totally agree they happen, it would inform this discussion to analyze some tractable examples.

Comment: @smci hm, it would be an interesting distinction, but I don't think issues relating to _known_ SO constraints (whether 'social' such as the requirement for an MCVE, or 'algorithmic' such as rep-restrictions) leading to experiences that can be deemed as unwelcoming should be discounted from this discussion. If anything, users who have managed to stick around the system long enough to gain rep and overcome these limitations, presumably represent 'survivorship bias' and thus not very relevant to the 'unwelcoming' problem. This might also explain why older ('survivor') users don't see a problem.

Comment: Related: *[Does Stack Exchange really want to conflate newbies with women/people of color?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665)*

Comment: "Walk away and don't provide any help at all rather than call a spade a spade?" - yes why not? Unless you have some compulsion to 'win'

Comment: @Mr.Boy I had some desire to help people solve their problems. Not anymore, I guess.

Comment: Something that really stands out to me about this Meta post is that there are many people who flatly disagree with OP and say that these comments are obviously unwelcoming; many of them especially seem focused on the idea that comments should be more *constructive*; but **most of them don't even attempt to offer alternative phrasings**, or even give any principled reasoning for finding the comments "unwelcoming" beyond personal, subjective judgment. It's quite impressively ironic.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**There is clearly a diversity of opinion among the people who participated in the comment-evaluation exercise as to what it means for comments to be "unwelcoming".**  This is demonstrated by the breadth of the result distributions: that aspect of the results is not plausibly explained by differences in interpretation of the subject text alone.  This is a problem that we really need to sort out, because we're going to have a hard enough time moving forward even when we all define the problem the same way.

And indeed, that seems really to be what this question is asking about.  Whether the examples should be considered unwelcoming depends on what we mean by "unwelcoming".  Plausible working definitions of an unwelcoming comment include those that

- expressly convey to the intended receiver that they themselves are not welcome to participate in the community, or
- demean or harass the receiver, or
- convey to the intended receiver that specific *content* (question, answer, or comment) they provided is not welcome in the community, or
- are *prone* to be perceived as negative by the receiver, or
- are *susceptible* to being perceived as negative by the receiver, or
- may make the receiver feel unwelcome, or
- are not "nice" (by some possibly subjective measure), or
- are impolite (by some possibly subjective measure), or
- are not sufficiently positive.

Choose one or more, and feel free to add your own.  My own list includes only a few of those.

Moreover, inasmuch as "welcoming" is pretty meaningless without the context of a "to", it is important to acknowledge that different communities have different expectations and standards.  Stack Overflow (SO) self-describes as a "site for professional and enthusiast programmers."  I have every reason to expect members of such a community to adopt a different attitude and tone than, say, folks over at Arts & Crafts SE.

**I welcome you to SO in part by treating you like a professional or enthusiast programmer.**  That doesn't mean others are unwelcome, but they might very well feel like they don't fit in.  And although I strive to be nice, and I'm prepared to help others fit in, I do not accept that it is incumbent on me or on us to deeply change the nature of the SO community and culture to make people who are not in SO's target audience comfortable here.

With respect to the particular comments highlighted in the revised blog post,

> - “This is becoming a waste of my time and you won’t listen to my advice. What are the supposed benefits of making it so much more
>     complex?”

The context indicates that the commenter has engaged the OP in a discussion of the question, including one or more recommended courses of action.  That seems welcoming to me.  If we are to take the comment at face value, the OP is ignoring the commenter's recommendations for no clear reason.  *That's* boorish.  Yes, the comment strikes a negative tone and criticizes the OP.  Yes, that might make the OP feel unwelcome.  And I'm totally fine with boors feeling unwelcome.  The OP here has *worn out* their welcome.

---

> - “Step 1. Do not clutter the namespace. Then get back to us.”

That's curt, certainly.  And it's not much help to an OP who does not understand what "cluttering the namespace" means or why it's a bad thing.  The commenter is without doubt criticizing the OP's question.  But does that make it "unwelcoming"?  I don't much care for the comment, but I don't think I'd call it "unwelcoming", and I don't think it rises to a level that we ought to be concerned with.

---

> - “The code you posted cannot yield this result. Please post the real code if you hope to get any help.”

Those may literally be my own words.  I know at least once I've posted a comment very much to that effect.  The main thing I find to criticize in it is the use of the word "hope", which carries the implication that maybe the OP won't get any help regardless.  But *that was the point*, at least in the instance I'm thinking about from my own history.  Posting a question on SO does not entitle anyone to help, and if that aspect of our community makes someone feel unwelcome then I'm not a bit concerned about it.

Coming at that after *not* having just invested my time in analyzing the code presented and comparing it to the output presented, only to discover that the question makes impossible claims about them, I might phrase it more gently.  Maybe, "The code you posted cannot yield the result you claim. If you have a question about a program that did produce the result then please edit your question to present *that* program instead."  Nevertheless, if indeed the original comment is my own, then I do not apologize or accept any fault for it.

---

> - “This error is self explanatory. You need to check…”

I may not have written those exact words, but I'm sure I have written similar comments.  Although what's "self explanatory" to one person is not always so to another, sometimes an error message really doesn't leave anything to be explained, at least to someone who is genuinely an enthusiast (or professional) programmer.  Questions that the OP should have been able to answer for themselves indeed are not welcome at SO, and I am perfectly satisfied with that.  If an OP is hurt by having that conveyed to them then my compassion for them is limited.

---

> - “I have already told how you can… If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”

And I've written comments using some of *those* words, too.  I won't claim the whole thing, but I'm sure most active members have been in the situation it evokes for me: you've answered their question (*that's* pretty welcoming); they've asked for clarification, and you've provided it (*that's* welcoming); they've asked the same thing a different way, and you've answered (*that's* welcoming); and then they insist it doesn't work for them, even though you have tested the very code or approach you provided.  The OP is either doing something wrong or flat out lying.  Calling them out on it is an effective and appropriate means to bring the situation to a resolution, and resolving the OP's problem is welcoming, too.

In my experience, such a comment is usually followed by an OP response along the lines of "oops, I copied your code wrong".  Problem solved! All is now right with the world.  Why is this something to be concerned about?  If it's unwelcoming to call out someone's error, then "welcoming" is not a trait that SO can sustain.

---

**I am not a helpdesk operator, and I reject any expectation that I should behave like one.**  I *prefer* to be nice, by which I mean gentle, helpful, friendly, patient, and kind.  IMHO, I'm good at it, though by no means perfect.  If SO wants to welcome behavior from others that tends to elicit non-nice behavior from *me*, then we may need to re-evaluate our relationship.  You can keep the ring, but the cat's coming with me.

Comment: *I am not a helpdesk operator, and I reject any expectation that I should behave like one.* This line summarizes my reservations about the whole "Welcome Wagon" thing perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @John: "*In my experience, such a comment is usually followed by an OP response along the lines of "oops, I copied your code wrong".*" In my experience, such a comment is pretty much *never* resolved that way. When things get to the "I already told you what to do" point, things never get better. Either the OP walks away, the poster walks away, or the OP/poster get into a fight. Learning has stopped by this point.

Comment: @John: "*If we are to take the comment at face value, the OP is ignoring the commenter's recommendations for no clear reason. That's boorish.*" What is the point of meeting boorish behavior with some from yourself? Disengage and move on. Nobody's asking you to be polite to such a person, but if things have gotten to the point where you feel someone is wasting your time, *stop talking to them*. Nothing you say will help, and you will accomplish nothing more than making yourself feel better.

Comment: "*But does that make it "unwelcoming"?*" ... yes. Without context, I can't comment on the accuracy of the comment. But unless the user's problem comes *because* they are cluttering the namespace, drawing attention to it is unhelpful. Now, as a C++ programmer, I see questions all the time where `using namespace std;` is used. But the right way to handle seeing that in someone's code is to say it's not a good idea and then link them to the question explaining why.

Comment: I stipulated that the "do not clutter the namespace" comment is unhelpful, @NicolBolas, but as I said, that does not rise to the level of "unwelcoming" to me.  That you disagree underscores my first point, that the community hasn't even a consensus on what "unwelcoming" behavior is or how to recognize it.  Is it unwelcoming that you comment on this very answer to contradict me three times?  That's rhetorical, of course.  I do not consider your comments unwelcoming, but that's because of my expectations for this forum, not because of the comments' content or how they make me feel.

Comment: @NicolBolas The idea is to ensure that the OP discovers that they have been deemed boorish by the people they're asking for help. This can lead to self-reflection and personal re-evaluation. Criticism is a key component of a successful life. If we all just ignore everybody we disagree with, and just ignore all actions we disagree with, then nobody is ever going to learn from anybody else.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings As Nicol Bolas said in his first comment *learning has stopped by this point*. If your counterpart perceives your comment as aggression, even if it wasn't meant that way, then most won't infer self-reflection from it. The idea of being able to "educate" others in this way is absurd. I understand John's point of view. It is a lot of work to help others, we all know that and of course that legitimizes some demands. I personally try to avoid such formulations. I think it's perfectly fine if others don't. But I definitely don't think they are helpful.

Answer (score 187):

TL;DR: Most of these can be shortened to remove what sounds like frustration. One of them really doesn't need to be posted at all. They really don't need to be deleted, just potentially edited to remove a line or two. I wouldn't actually *reword* any of them.

If you can't say something without adding a bit of sass to the end... Yeah, best not to help and just walk away.

---

Honestly, some of these are a little more hostile than needed. They can be re-worded to be less hostile, and more welcoming.

> No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.

Honestly, the main problem *I* see with this one is the second half. Calling something a waste of your time instead of walking away is *always* unwelcoming. You don't have to answer when someone replies, and you don't have to provide help if they aren't willing to accept it. Without seeing the rest of the chain, as the other user definitely had to have this user fed up by this point, the best I can say is leave the first two sentences, and then walk away. That would make this less hostile, and therefore more welcoming.

> And this is tagged Javascript why?

Without context, there's really no way to reword this one. The better comment to leave would have been to ask how JavaScript is involved in the problem, and re-tag if it's not (while politely explaining how tags *should* be used, in the edit summary most likely) or just remove the tag without the snarky question. Of course, from your question, it seems you see how this one isn't that great yourself.

For example of a better way to ask this:

> Hey, you tagged this JavaScript, but I don't see any in your question. If the problem doesn't involve, or seem to involve, your JavaScript code, it's best we remove that tag so that the right people see your question and can help with it. If it does involve JavaScript, can you share that code with us too, so we can better answer the question?

Or... *Just retag it.* Really, it's faster and less hassle.

> Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design.

Really, the only thing I see wrong with this comment is it doesn't try to educate the user for *why* the design must be wrong. They could have linked something, explained it, whatever. And if the user *must* use that design, for whatever reason, then this comment is only help for the "you're probably after `LEAST()`" part... Which would really better be put as an answer. Saying someone's doing something "very, very wrong" without explaining how or why it's wrong, and especially just assuming it's wrong, is... Well, most people don't like it.

Imagine I saw you and how you were dressed, and said that if you're wearing that shirt, you can be sure your wardrobe options must be very, very wrong. You... Would probably not appreciate me very much. This is very similar to that.

> For the last time, use the serial number code and replace `kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey` with `kIOPlatformUUIDKey`

"For the last time" implies impatience and irritation, not always at the same time. If the user here *really* wanted to repeat themselves and ignore DRY principles, they could have toned it down a bit:

> As said above, you want to use the serial number code and replace `kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey` with `kIOPlatformUUIDKey`

Doesn't that sound a bit more neutral? And if they didn't explain why above, they really should *expand* on why. Preferably in an answer, if this comment wasn't to suggest improvements to an answer. Really, if this was posted on a question, it should've been skipped and gone to an answer, but that's not the point of the question here.

> Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I have already told how you can bind to the property. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.

I think the only really "unwelcoming" part here is the last sentence. Of *course* they're doing something wrong, that's why they came here for help in the first place! No one needs to be told they're doing something wrong if they can't make it work. It could be that this user's prior explanation was insufficient or unclear. It's also true that if they were able to provide that much of an answer to the user's question... Did the user *truly* not have enough of an MCVE, or was this user just pushing for more than was needed? Unfortunately, without more context around this comment,t here's nothing more we can say. Leaving off the last sentence would have gone a long way towards making this better.

---

At the end of the day, yes, sometimes it's better to just walk away and *let someone else* handle the help from there. To be fair, most of these comments read as if they're from later in the chain, after at least one attempt to help. In those cases, I feel the real problem is just burnout and frustration of the comment poster.

In that case, yes, if you're getting annoyed or frustrated with a user you've already provided some help to, *walk away.* There's no point talking at a wall that doesn't want to listen, and if they do want to listen and just aren't getting it... Well, getting frustrated with them is never going to help them get it. Let someone else take a crack at it, or they may just search something you said that might lead them to the solution or understanding they needed.

Are these comments *deplorable* and outright atrocious? No, not really. Are they a bit more confrontational than need be? Yeah, a little. Can that make people upset? Oh, most definitely. Do these *need* to be deleted? I think it will depend. Some of these, no, they just need a sentence removed and not really reworded. In those cases, a mod could simply remove the unhelpful part and leave the rest, preferably. The second one really doesn't provide anything useful, so I'd say delete it and go, but otherwise it's a careful balance to strike.

Mods will have to act on these on a case-by-case basis. Hopefully, they will take/have the time to do that, rather than the current "If the comment has some reason it might need to be deleted, just delete it and go" style they use. At least I'm sure most of us can agree these comments don't warrant a *scolding*, more just a friendly, "Hey, if you're annoyed, it's probably less annoying to you and less a waste of your time to just walk away and let someone else handle it" whether from a mod or another user.

---

#### Post blog update

The comments the blog updated with are much more... Generically not welcoming. I only disagree with a couple of them, but... They also have the problem of *no context.* We can see several that are supposed to have had extra parts, but don't. The examples they've changed to are now stock and not *actual examples* of what they saw. The blog even calls out that they're typical of what's seen, not what was actually used.

I won't break those comment examples down here, both as this answer is long enough and as the new examples are not the data that was actually used. I won't use my time to analyze them when they aren't specifically what the team analyzed. Actually, I'd be much happier if they gave us the full sample set they used, and what votes each got. All data anonymized, of course, but this will give us a much clear picture of where the team in general stands.

Comment: I have a feeling the second comment was from a question posting Java code, which as you said should've just been edited.

Comment: @George That's what I'm thinking as well, that or it's just that the poster is _using_ JavaScript, but it's not actually related to the problem. Either of those seem somewhat common, just in my experience.

Comment: You'd be amazed the number of students or foreign individuals looking for help with java, that tag javascript. It's practically an all day job just closing them, I get them getting frustrated, and the comment doesn't help, nor should it be considered "unwelcoming". It's a total opportunity for dialog.

Comment: @Trasiva While it's totally an opportunity for dialog, it could also be reworded to be less confrontational. For example, _"Hey, you tagged this JavaScript, but I don't see any in your question. If the problem doesn't involve, or seem to involve, your JavaScript code, it's best we remove that tag so that the right people see your question and can help with it. If it does involve JavaScript, can you share that code with us too, so we can better answer the question?"_ Much more helpful, much more likely to get a non-hostile response.

Comment: Much easier: just edit the tags.

Comment: I personally agree with @Kendra that it's worth a little extra effort to "re-word to be less hostile, and more welcoming." As a dev-in-training SO can be intimidating and unwelcoming comments don't help one bit. People make mistakes, and I feel it's important to give the benefit of the doubt and encourage better practices rather than intimidate them out of newbies.

Comment: This post is effectively saying that all comments will be interpreted as uncharitably as possible, so you need to write out something 5x longer than needed with super fluffy language to combat that, rather than simply being concise and expecting readers to treat the comment professionally.  I think that's an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: @Servy Actually... A number of my suggestions were to write _less_ rather than reword to write more. The only one I really insisted needs expanded, if you _really_ want to post it rather than just retag, doesn't have much more than a "Are you dumb?" style question. Only reason to expand any of the others is to provide more information, and therefore be more helpful to everyone, not to make things fluffy.

Comment: I disagree with simply retagging, it really should at least be accompanied by a comment explaining that the tag isn't needed. Otherwise the user will never notice that they weren't supposed to include the JavaScript tag on that type of question, and will continue to post with it.

Comment: @Kendra Well in the first case you were suggesting removing important information from the post (namely the fact that they're approaching the problem in the wrong way), as in the last case (contrary to your claim that everyone knows they're doing something wrong, many people assert that something isn't working even when they're doing something correctly).  The rest of the cases you're claiming that the comments are missing information, but they're all responses, so we can't know what information that user (or others) has already said previously, to know if it is in fact missing.

Comment: @Servy _"If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong."_ How is this important information? _"This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress."_ The only part about this remotely helpful is the part about string allocation being needed to make progress. You can leave off the rest and say, _"Finding out how the string is allocated will help."_ There. Same information, less hostility. I still fail to see where I'm advocating making things fluffy and longer.

Comment: '*Hey, you tagged this JavaScript, but I don't see any in your question[...]?'* - This is extremely fluffy, you should *not* be expected to help write the question, include the relevant information and answer the question. There has to be some sort of effort from the questioner's side too which is where I feel we are lacking discussion on.

Comment: As for missing information, I'm suggesting they miss _helpful_ information, _or that they really should've been answers in the first place._ I'm not suggesting they make things "fluffy" and I do point out that the information is only useful _if they haven't explained it earlier._ I point out that they're responses, and I point out that information only _might_ be missing.

Comment: @Script47 As I said... Really, just retag the post. Less hassle, faster.

Comment: @Kendra that doesn't solve the problem of the OP mistagging in the future though does it? You can't expect people to tiptoe around questioners making mistakes especially when it is the same people cleaning up those mistakes. Don't misunderstand me, I'm not advocating snark, but saying all they need to do is retag the question is also not the whole solution.

Comment: @Script47 If you've got a better way to word it to invite learning and discussion, please, be my guest and edit my post for it. I won't claim to be the best author in the world, but if you're going to try to get someone who doesn't want to learn the system on their own to listen to you... Sometimes, you have to be fluffy to accomplish that much. =/

Comment: I agree with Servy that most of these suggestions by and large are longer than the originals. While I don't see a problem with that tone-wise, effort-wise it means the comment is less likely to be read, at least in its entirety. A lot of users may not bother reading a max-length comment reply, especially if it comes at the end of a discussion where tensions may be running a little high.

Comment: This is not a criticism of your answer, but... I feel like it's almost a waste of time to go into detailed discussions about how particular things could have possibly been said differently, if only the people who said them had a different mindset on how things ought to be said -- since they don't. I think people here are definitely smart enough to figure out how things could be said differently on their own, they just don't want to, as they fundamentally disagree with the need to, and see it as an attack on their values to imply they *should*. There's a lot of rationalization going on.

Comment: A better, less snarky, alternative to "And this is tagged Javascript why?" is just "Why did you use the JavaScript tag with this question?". That is assuming there's any reason to suspect it might be valid, otherwise just retag quietly. Saying more is waste of time because the original poster is unlikely to read it or understand the problem.

Comment: @Kendra frankly? No, I don't have a better solution. I'm sure if you were able to compare the amount of poor questions against the amount of snarky / harsh comments, it would come to a lot less (complete conjecture, merely based on what I've seen) yet so much focus is given on the aspect of people being "unwelcoming". I'm not bashing your answer, just disagreeing with parts of it and if I do think of a potential wording, I will edit.

Comment: There is nothing unreasonable about any of the assessments made here. For the sake of making a point: "Would it *kill* you to refrain from typing or at least deleting those bits of exasperation and ire before submitting your comment?"

Comment: @BoltClock Likewise, "would it *kill* people not to interpret comments as harshly as possible?"

Comment: @Script47 No bashing assumed, and I think the reason the focus is on these... Is that while they may be fewer, they are most definitely easier to notice, particularly if you're out to "prove" we're unwelcoming. On top of that, they're the "bad feeling" type of comments, so people, even reasonable ones, find them difficult to ignore. Throw in the current IRL culture in certain areas that everyone's out to get you and no one is ever being nice when they give advice, and you have a recipe for this situation.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: I don't think it takes any mental gymnastics to interpret any of these comments harshly. You try talking to everyone like that in person and see if any of them remain friendly with you for more than five minutes.

Comment: @Kendra but that is precisely my point, we should be addressing the issues, all of them, not just one aspect of them. SO (SE?) should be saying 'new user need work harder on their questions and older users need to work on their snark' not 'older users are unwelcoming and here is a tiny amount of one sided data to prove so'.

Comment: @Script47 Agree 1000000%

Comment: @BoltClock I see similar language used in my work constantly, from lots of different people.  Everyone stays quite friendly.  I've only ever seen people try to take offense to comments like those on the internet.

Comment: @Servy Just because "everyone is doing it" doesn't mean that it should be acceptable to be mean to others that use this site.

Comment: Let's not forget that in personal communication we're using a lot more channels than what is available in places like SO. Emojis help a little, but pale in comparison to facial expression, body language, tone of voice, etc. Not to mention that of course personal relation affects how we perceive and react to the other person.

Comment: @Servy: I can't imagine expressions of impatience like "For the last time" and "Would it kill you" being friendly unless they're being used ironically (maybe they are in your case, which is fair enough).

Comment: @Jo. BoltClock's point was specifically that anyone saying such a thing in "real life" and not on the internet, would result in it being received poorly.  I was providing experimental evidence (rather than just theory) that that is not the case.  And as has been said, *I don't see such comments as mean*.  You're claiming that those comments are being mean.  I see no such thing, nor do quite a lot of others.

Comment: @BoltClock You're the only one using "would it kill you" here, not the examples above, which is what I was referring to in my comment.  That said, I've never seen anyone consider the use of "would it kill you" to be offensive or rude.

Comment: @BoltClock Expressions of impatience are just that, expressions of impatience.  It's not something to take offense at, or something to be considered as being mean or insulting.  It's a sign that someone else is losing their patience at your behavior (or the situation they're in, or whatever else).  When I see others expressing signs of impatience it tells me that *I'm* probably doing something wrong, and that I should try to figure out how to correct *my* behavior, not as a  failure of them in some way.

Comment: @Servy "real life" and "on the internet" are pretty far apart.  In real life, we have the advantage of facial expressions, tone, and familiarity to help craft the context of the words.  On the internet, we have text and a very different setting with people we don't know.  Having a double-standard makes sense because the two situations are different.

Comment: @BoltClock "You try talking to everyone like that in person and see if any of them remain friendly with you for more than five minutes." --> In real life, if one repeatedly asks poor questions to frustrate others, as if it was others' obligation to teach them, you can see whether this person will get friendly response.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Boltclock was the one who said that such comments wouldn't be tolerated in an in person environment.  I merely stated that I have personally seen the opposite.

Comment: @Bolt - yes, it would kill them.  SO is a relentless source of exceedingly bad practices.  Surely you've seen your share of questions at which you thought "jeez, I hope nobody ever read this and assume it is a good idea".  When you can't explain why it is not then there are just not a lot of decent ways to stop that.  Even not responding to comment is a big problem since it *looks* like you give in and agree.  They'll have to care less, pretty hard to do for a dedicated contributor.  This is apt to turn into the summer of love disaster number 2, a lot less users that care.

Comment: What is common in the sample comments is that they are _responses_. I have to agree with the point there is no context. It takes 2 to tango

Comment: @Servy: It doesn't matter who's using or citing these examples. They're all examples. And as you've pointed out, these expressions aren't *offensive* or *rude*, but at the same time neither are they necessary to get a point across. I disagree that A making their impatience with B as conspicuous as possible is solely B's fault. I certainly didn't need to spell out in [**20 words**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47806530/3) my frustration with people not reading error messages in their entirety, as annoying as it is and even if I'll never know why the asker didn't in that specific case.

Comment: Do I have a problem if I'm finding myself exhausted trying to put up a similar tone in this very conversation? Maybe I do considering it still isn't very long ago I made comments such as these (the ones being highlighted as unwelcoming) myself and I'm still going through a phase of change since this whole saga started. What do you think, Kendra?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, I'll certainly agree that such phrases are *unnecessary*.  Such is the nature of comments that they do contain some noise; people often don't spend the time and energy crafting and editing them that they (hopefully) do for posts.  Comments in general do have a lower signal to noise ratio than posts do.  And I'm not saying that it's always entirely someone else's fault when someone loses there patience, merely that my reaction to someone else losing their patience is not to blame them for losing their patience and to look elsewhere.

Comment: @BoltClock I think it sounds like you need an all expense paid vacation. SO should totally cover that for you. ;) In all seriousness, though, I think your comments on this post at least have been fine, minus the points you were intentionally being "Not Fine" as defined by the study.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't understand why you're equating the ability to explain why a practice is bad with statements like "you won't listen to my advice", "for the last time", and the like. It is hardly impossible to explain why a practice is bad, even if it's just a link to elsewhere, without saying such things. You're confusing form with content.

Comment: You are missing the next step that turns it ugly.  Feeling *forced* to respond to a comment and knowing it won't do any good is exasperating to anybody.

Comment: @liliscent That would be all well and good if indeed these comments were solely aimed at people repeatedly asking poor questions (Although even there SO has mechanisms other than harsh language to discourage such behavior). However, at least the problem statement seems to indicate that the usual targets are first-time askers.

Comment: @Haem A first-time asker could still ask *a lot of* ridiculous questions in a single thread. There are some askers, when you tell them to "click the mouse", they will ask you "what is mouse? how to click? where to click? ..." After you thoroughly explain basic stuff, they still don't have the ability to follow. Then they copy-paste some new error message due to their own mistake and claim your answer doesn't work. The last cited comment in the post is very likely from such situation. Honestly, no one has infinite patience.

Comment: @Haem Of course the best way to handle is just to move on. But this blog extracts those comments out of context, and blame those commenters as "unwelcoming", this doesn't make sense.

Comment: On "No one needs to be told they're doing something wrong if they can't make it work.": That's not true. If you tell someone that they should be using the Spam library to parse spam objects instead of trying to do it with the Eggs library, and they respond "I tried Spam and it didn't work", then they need to be told that the problem can be easily solved with Spam, so whatever they tried was wrong, And, since they didn't give us any idea at all about what they tried, there's no way to be more specific. You can try to phrase it more nicely, but you end up saying the same thing in more words.

Comment: Of course that's not the _only_ reason someone would ever make that comment. But 90% of the time, that's what that comment means: The OP tried to do it the right way, did something wrong, doesn't believe they did something wrong and instead insists that the right way won't work, and wants help doing it the wrong way instead.

Comment: Not sure if this has been addressed but - isn't this becoming unwelcoming of  non-native English folk?  I can appreciate that 'And this is tagged Javascript why?' might not be the absolute nicest way to phrase something, but I've worked with many great developers who learned English as a 2nd or 3rd language and it very closely matches their writing style.  Maybe a bit direct, but certainly not wrong, insulting or unfriendly (IMHO).

Comment: @RobP. That's actually a really good point- Some of these could easily stem from ESL folks, just trying to translate things into English from their native tongue. That of course doesn't work for everything, but at least that one for sure that could make sense for. It's definitely something to keep in mind when handling these kinds of comments.

Comment: The "Welcome Wagon" insanity is going to be the ***end*** of Stack Overflow. It all comes at the cost of reducing quality by inhibiting community QA, which is in *extreme* demand when it comes to questions from new users. So less QA and fewer veterans will answer questions for noobs (welcomed new users). Then we code our own community to disrupt SE. Behold the future.

Comment: @Servy The takeaway ***I*** get from this answer is possibly even deeper here: **"Don't express any negative emotions (e.g.: frustration) as a part of comments."** I'm no sociologist but I wonder whether this ultimately leads to a healthy community, as it removes even more of the social cues lost in written communication already. Others have raised this also.

Comment: @Kendra Both you and others make clear that context is hugely important for evaluating what 'unwelcoming' is, but not all of these data-points are even (immediately) exposed to commenters e.g. ESL-status of OP? Does OP have rep on other sites? How long have they lurked the current one? Does OP have learning disabilities or social disorders which might make them more sensitive or inexpert at reading or writing? In turn, exposing those same stats about the commenters themselves to mods might determine how much punishment is warranted for the "repeat offenders" mentioned in draft CoC.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy No, it's okay to express negative emotions, but only if you're a new user asking an inappropriate question for the site.  It's only inappropriate if you're expressing a negative emotion if you're a long time user trying to help someone else out in improving their post.

Answer (score 100):

Honestly, a lot of those comments provide more specific guidance and read much kinder than what I see daily in my error logs. Programmers who get their feelings hurt by these types of comments will certainly be devastated when the parser says something to them like:

> *PHP Fatal error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use*

Totally unhelpful and snarky!  ***Check the manual?!?*** Seriously people, toughen up.  Is the tone & language used by your platform's error reporting going to be an obstacle to advancing your skills as well?  Being barked at in an unhelpful and uncaring manner is part of our culture. No apologies.

Comment: This is indeed one of the arguments occasionally iterated here: compilers don't show compassion to you, they just point the errors out, some better than others. However, our users are not compilers, and will not always phrase things in a way that a compiler would. In fact, none of the generic examples above would be a compiler's output.

Comment: This could be shortened to "Grow some balls", but it does make a valid point: If such comments upset or disturb someone emotionally, he'll have *much* bigger problems in life than those that can ... ehm... are supposed to be fixed by some Q/A-site-policy. (Although we also all know that *some* error messages can cause the strong desire to give the responsible developer a high five ... in the face ... with a chair)

Comment: I feel like this is an incredibly unhelpful post that does nothing to actually get at the heart of the problem.  Yes, the given blog examples suck, but I feel you're basically saying that all levels of rudeness are acceptable because it's 'part of our culture'.

Comment: @Froopy What **is** the heart of the problem, though? That's what all the welcoming-discussion is about. For some people, the problem is some vague form of "unwelcomingness". For others, the problem is that unrealistic and counterproductive expectations are made regarding "politeness and being welcoming", without even a speck of evidence that the usual computer scientist parlance actually is a problem, or that the established policies will do more good (politeness) than harm (lower quality). They will **not** achieve the utopia that they are looking for, that's for sure.

Comment: @Froopy - I'm sorry if I did not make myself clear, I'm definitely **not** saying that "all levels of rudeness are acceptable".  I've seen rudeness that I felt was totally unacceptable but it's far and few between.  I was specifically answering the OP's question regarding the examples given in that blog post and I don't really find any of those problematic.  To me, a low level of snippiness here is perfectly fine, if not beneficial.

Comment: I think that snark or 'snippiness' is unhelpful on a site like SO. The point is for people to get help learning. They will make stupid mistakes (sometimes repeatedly) and some users are not fluent in English. Adding barbs just makes them less likely to admit their mistakes in the future. This uncaring mannerism is part of our developer culture, because our culture is flawed. Just because something is part of our culture does not make is right or good.

Comment: Granted, compilers tend to be rude, but (as others have pointed out above) the problem with a lot of these comments is not their shortness, but their _longness_.  They include phrases that have nothing to do with the problem, but are only there to express exasperation.  If you think they're writing like a parser, then imagine your parser saying this:  `PHP Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax for the 5th time today.  I've repeatedly suggested checking the manual, but at this point it seems like a waste of time, so I'll save my breath.  Best of luck to you.`

Comment: @Marco13, I would agree that some people do have unrealistic expectations when it comes to interactions on here.  However, I would also say that at times, people could stand to be a little more courteous to others on here.  Basically, talking to people instead of at/down to them would be helpful.  I do see examples of that every once in a while.  I'm not saying it happens everywhere all the time, but it does happen, and when people see that, boom, there's your unwelcoming feeling.  That's what I feel like the heart of the matter is, IMO.

Comment: @Froopy I'm trying to be pragmatic here. If a comment is "rude or abusive", then flag it. Anything more to say about that? Yeah, let's discuss about politics, attitudes and feelings and other things that are totally unrelated to the goal of the site, and finally establish a CoC that is so elaborate that hardly *any* newbie will read it anyhow. At least it keeps the "Culture and Experience" staff busy. I honestly don't see the point of the whole discussion, despite reading and following the discussions for hours and hours. For me, the (reasonable!) "Be nice" policy has just grown out of hand.

Comment: @Marco13 "establish a CoC that is so elaborate that hardly any newbie will read it anyhow." That's the thing; a lot of the time I see people reacting to newbies posting lazy questions who've not read the FAQ, taken the tour, or spent the time seeing if their question fits in here or if they're just treating the site like all the other naff forums on the net. Perhaps if there was a "newbie needs to see how the site works, make this question go away until they perform some captcha-like proof they understand what we're about" button then a lot of this alleged unpleasantness could be avoided.

Comment: On a product I used to work on, we got a request from the field to change the name of one of our tools. I don't remember what it was exactly, but it went something like "Interactive Data Input Output Tool" which, when abbreviated in the logs said "IDIOT ERROR:" And the errors were only occurring when the customer had put in invalid input, as the output couldn't be generated. For some reason, they didn't enjoy seeing that when looking through the logs.

Comment: @Marco13 "What is the heart of the problem, though?" The very same thing that is the heart of the frequent "StackOverflow is not nice enough" discussion that is lead since many years: the answerers want the questioners to abide by the rules and show effort and the questioners want easy and quick help and be treated nicely. On top of that we are all only humans and some of us seem to have a bad day from time to time. So far, simple solutions haven't shown any effect.

Comment: @RyanLundy Yes, compilers certainly don't sound like [this](https://xkcd.com/371/).

Comment: @RyanLundy Well, I've gotten "too many errors; giving up" from a C++ compiler before.

Comment: @RyanLundy Some professional compilers really do have that degree of sass, check out these error messages from [Apple's MPW C compiler](https://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/91q3/cerrors.html). One of the gems? "Too many errors on one line (make fewer)"

Answer (score 79):

## Whoa SO, slow down a moment.

> [image: Comment Evaluator 5000]

Where was this? How was it advertised? *WAS* it advertised? This intro page sure looks like it was meant to pull in a large sample of people from Stack Overflow to get involved. I sure as heck have never seen this before.

> We had 57 participants

Oh, no apparently it was not advertised or even openly available. Heck, this doesn't even cover a *quarter* of SO's *own employees* (much less the 120,000 or so people who've gained at least 100 rep this year).

I have a feeling that more people (and more comments) should have been involved in this ratings process. Because of the fact that tone, in text, is a matter of interpretation you need to get a *wide spectrum of readers* to participate. I would even then break down the results by *age of the account* to see if there's an interpretation difference between new users and "old foagies."

On top of that, identifying the comments that 99% of folks thinks are fine, but That One Guy rated as frustrated or angry. Because the problem isn't that people make rude comments (those people can be dealt with), it's the new user who sees a comment, interprets the worst, and leaves telling his two friends "Stack Overflow sucks, they're all elitist jerks" because someone asked him to provide a MCVE. Fixing *that* is your stated goal, isn't it? Rather than punishing the commenter: teach the reader. Find a way to inform this person that "no, that comment isn't rude, our site has guidelines for asking good questions, and this person is trying to inform to that fact."

Then we get this chart:

> [image: Ratings chart]

This looks pretty typical, lots of abusive comments, some less than ideal comments, and some that are fiiiii--**wait a minute!** What was that vertical axis labeled again? "Number of raters." As in *the number of people who rated the comment.* Several of these have 1 or 2 ratings, most have less than ten!

**How is this graph even statistically significant?**

And now that I look at the name of the X axis, I'm not even sure what kind of data this chart is even supposed to be showing. "100% of comments with each rating" had 7 raters...huh? What does that even *mean?* How does a comment get a single rating that leaves it at "75%"? Even if we assume that the X axis is supposed to be "acceptability" or "average of all ratings" the choices are "outright hostile" "unsure" and "fine." A single entry of any one of those should not leave a comment at "75% fine."

Now you have me convinced that you're deliberately trying to deceive the community. For what purpose, I don't know, but I know that Stack Overflow knows how to analyze data and present good charts; you have been doing it for years with the developer survey. This on the other hand...this is really sloppy. I don't know what to say.

[image: I'm confused]

Comment: I believe this answer would be more suitable for Mark Amery's ["Feedback on the Comment Classifier blog post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370838/1630171) topic.

Comment: I've been staring at the graph for 10 minutes and here's what I think it is saying: 6 people marked 100% of the comments as "fine", 1 person marked 75% of the comments as "fine", 51 people marked 0% of the comments as "abusive", etc.

Comment: So one observation is that the raters couldn't decide on how many posts were unwelcoming - the orange distribution is w-i-d-e

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Oh good point, I'll go put this over there. That's what happens when I follow a promoted link in the side bar and run across this particular blog post for the first time. ;)

Comment: BTW, am I the only one who thought "EvaluaTron 5000™" when seeing that evaluator screenshot? Have people already forgotten how that game ended? For a moment I had actually thought this was a misplaced April Fools' joke.

Comment: Maybe they could only find 57 people who've never used SE before.

Comment: Or the results were secretly pre-filtered, removing (most of) those which don't fit the narrative.

Comment: @SargeBorsch That is a bit of a stretch. Even though I disagree with a lot about this "Welcome Wagon" initiative I'd be quite hesitant to make *that* kind of accusation (or even assumption) without at least *some* kind of evidence.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I only mentioned that this could be possible. Because it is obviously possible (in physical/mathematical sense). Because we were not observing the entire process to verify if all steps were done fairly and thus to eliminate that possibility. I don't see why is this necessarily a stretch. In real life all kinds of voting get cheated all the time unless there are enough concerning eyes to detect if someone does something suspicious.

Comment: A bit late, but agreeing with @bmm6o.  The chart seems to be comparing the number of people who rated comments to the number of times each person gave a given rating.  The key here is that each colour adds up to 57 raters, as indicated by the "abusive" green (which puts 52 at 0% and 5 at what appears to be 2%, out of the 57 stated participants), and to a lesser extent the "fine" blue (appears to be 7, 20, 12, 6, 8, and four 1s, starting from 100% and going left).  The chart is thus valid, but presented _very_ poorly, IMO.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the first screenshot makes the entire effort look like a parody of itself, to me. It's exactly what I'd expect to see if random Internet trolls collaborated to try to mock the Stack Exchange staff's attempts at being more "welcoming".

Answer (score 59):

In the suggested [SE Code of Conduct](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G1BpL_G_m6F5LIPMUZVcLejSPFTb3XbI_69X8fQSZAk/edit#heading=h.jv09j4ufyzvp) there is the statement:

> No discrimination of any kind. This includes ... **English fluency** ...

For someone whose native language is not English, the question

> “And this is tagged Javascript why?”

or comment

> “This error is self explanatory. You need to check…”

sounds perfectly fine (and it seems to be grammatically correct).
This is the language I'm using (and will keep using) in my comments with no bad intentions; it's just the level of my English.

Comment: They weren't cited due to not being good English. They were cited for being inappropriate. The phrasing of the Javascript one is needlessly aggressive; the neutral way to ask is "Where is the JavaScript code?" or something to that effect. The "this error is self explanatory" simply doesn't need to be there. It too is aggressive, suggesting that the OP can't understand something that explains itself.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's precisely the point. They were cited as being inappropriate, it's very clear that it's not because of the level of english, but for people less fluent in it, it may very well be how they phrase it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have some understanding of Japanese and several of my friends are English as a second language speakers. Though a few have been speaking English long enough to understand the problem with the 1st comment, others wondered why it was bad to say why at the end of the sentence (think or look up *desu ka* or just *ka*) - and thought this was a good way to ask it. Not saying this was the case in the original but PoGibas's point should not be disregarded (when thinking of comments in general). I worry SE might be too aggressive in attacking comments which are due to language as well.

Comment: I find it rather ironic that an answer that talks about English fluency is edited by a native speaker(?) to fix wrong usage of English.

Comment: @LutzHorn I like to think of it more as informing - I did leave a link to an explanation in the edit comment.

Comment: @NicolBolas _"Where is the JavaScript code?"_ seems every bit as accusatory as, _"Why is this tagged as JavaScript?"_ Personally, I don't see a problem with either one. I find them roughly equivalent. Even though they're explicitly pointing out a deficiency, I don't find either one particularly combative.

Answer (score 43):

I think that fundamentally, all of the examples have one common theme:

The commenter is frustrated. Frustrated with OP, frustrated with too many bad questions, frustrated at all the noise permeating what's supposed to be signal.

This is the principle problem that leads to snarky comments, not a general unwelcoming attitude. If you fix the quality problem or at least put forth more high quality submissions, the frustration and thus snark level is going to decrease. I don't think you can mandate people not be frustrated by fiat, no matter how well written your code of conduct is.

Comment: Whether their attitude is unwelcoming or not is irrelevant; what matters is that their *actions* create an environment that others don't want to participate in. Being frustrated cannot be helped; *expressing* frustration can be. So being frustrated is no excuse. The goal is not to mandate what people feel; it's to keep them from unproductive expressions of feelings.

Comment: @NicolBolas Why they do what they do is really _the only_ relevant factor because contingent on understanding that are any strategies to abate such behavior.

Comment: If someone steals from you, do you *really care* why?

Comment: ... Of course you do. If you only treat the symptom... you'll never really solve the problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course I do, because depending on why that is is my entire response to it. If that person is near death and stealing food no amount of threatening to report to police will solve anything there. This is a deliberately over the top example of course, but you can only abate what you understand.

Comment: @NicolBolas if "you" are designing a system - a justice system in your comment - then YES you care why people commit crimes.  It's utterly essential.  And likewise if discussing SO/SE policies and systems, it's so important WHY people might leave sub-optimal comments.  Some of the examples given by the thought police in the blog post sound so much like the person they are talking to was being a complete jerk.  And, if so, moaning at the volunteers answering questions to be nicer to the inconsiderate jerks will just drive away the volunteers

Comment: @Magisch: When dealing with *statistics*, you can care about why some people behave that way. When looking at the crime rate in a population vs. mean income or some other factor, that's important. When looking at a *specific* act, it is irrelevant. Misbehavior has happened and must be dealt with. Punishment can certainly factor in such considerations, but misbehavior must always be acknowledged as *misbehavior*.

Comment: @Magisch: Or to put it another way, reducing people's frustrations will reduce the number of people who lash out. But *any* lashing out still needs to be dealt with.

Comment: @NicolBolas Right, but punishment's purpose is as a deterrent or influencer of action. If you punish someone for something outside of pure restitution, you want a deterrent against future transgressions of the same type. That means your actual goal is influencing behavior. My hunch is that stack overflow mainly wants to improve the user experience for many people who are targeted by such lashing out. It would only behoove them then to first reflect on why people are doing so before going to the traditionally least effective and most time-expensive way of curbing behavior (pure punishment)

Comment: I think it's more of a cycle: new users arrive, frustrate people trying to help them, both parties feel wronged, nobody's happy, the site loses the chance of more positive interactions from those users. You can't mandate new users to write good questions by fiat either, so just putting all the blame on them is equivalent to giving up on the whole problem. We need to think of tools that help existing users deal with new users without getting so frustrated, *as well as* preventing that frustration leading to behaviour that drives new users away.

Comment: @NicolBolas No system of justice that requires perfection is going to work.  So "any lashing out still needs to be dealth with" means you are signing yourself up for failure.  Rules and consequences guide behavior, they don't determine it; so "why" are people doing X, and manipulating **that**, is more important than having rules about and punishment for doing X, in reducing the incidence of X.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: OK, how about this: any lashing out needs to be *seen as rule breaking*. Because that's the step we're on at this point. There are a fair number of people who see this lashing out and think "Meh, that's fine" or even "Bravo, give those freeloaders what for!" If we're going to guide behavior properly, we need to make everyone aware that these are against the rules and that there will be consequences for them.

Answer (score 40):

I'll take a stab at this. Most of them I agree can easily be rewritten or shortened to be nicer/more welcoming:

> No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.

This should be phrased:

> No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory.

That's all. No snark, no attitude, etc. Just stop right there.

> And this is tagged Javascript why?

Hard to tell without context, but it can be better asked:

> "Why is this tagged with JavaScript"

or even

> "Did you mean to tag this with Javascript?"

or even just remove the tag silently, if you are sure it does not belong (and have 2k+ reputation)

> Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design.

I don't think there is anything wrong with this, but again context is important. In this case, I'd like to see the question and any previous comments to tell. This could be made nicer though by saying:

> Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something's gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you're probably after LEAST(). But I would recommend fixing your design first.

It's a *little* bit nicer but again the change is largely superficial.

> For the last time, use the serial number code and replace kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey with kIOPlatformUUIDKey

Just remove the "for the last time" phrase. It sounds like you are exasperated and accusing the OP of not listening. May be true, but not necessary to point out, and we need more context to judge it effectively.

> Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I have already told how you can bind to the property. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.

Like most of the comments quoted in the blog post, this one is helpful and good, until the end, where the user piles on. Everything after the link should be removed/left out. The first sentence after is just repeating that exasperation tone, and then 2nd one is condescending and unnecessary because obviously if it doesn't work you've done something wrong.

---

The takeaway here I think is that most people aren't intentionally rude or unwelcoming in comments, they just get that way after trying to help someone who is not quite getting it or who needs more help than commenters expect to give. My advice:

If you find yourself about to repeat what you've said or resort to pithy truisms or retorts, stop commenting and move on.

Comment: Hmm. I've got mixed feelings about your take on the first and last comments. While I agree that the end of both of them is a bit snippy, you propose fixing it by outright removing instructions to the user on what to do next - in the first case, to "find out how the string is allocated", and in the last case, to provide an MCVE *specifically showing* how attempting to use the previously-suggested approach to "bind to the property" fails. I don't really understand what either of those instructions means without context, but I'm cautious about assuming out of hand that they can just be culled.

Comment: @MarkAmery In the first comment, it sounds as if the commenter has already said to find out how the string is allocated. Its essentially just a "if you wont do what I *already told you*, you won't progress". In the second case, the same situation, The MCVE link and instruction is the new info, and saying "I've already told you X" is... just repeating yourself. But I agree, context is important. Really we should be given links or screenshots of the whole context for each comment.

Comment: Wish I could upvote you twice. Each of these could be written to be less snarky or more kind, but to get the full picture we'd need to see the whole conversation.

Comment: Actually IMO a better approach to the "for the last time" comment and the "I have already told you how to bind" comment is not to reword it but just to move on without commenting.  Sometimes the OP is just not going to learn how to learn here - even though they've got a million examples in front of them on how to get generous help from strangers - and they're not worth trying to help.  I for one believe the original asker needs to put in some effort, just as we're expecting the many potential responders to put in an effort.

Comment: @davidbak Yes, if they've already said the important info, I agree moving on/refraining from commenting would be fine. Sometimes repetition is an effective teaching tool, though. It's probably a case of 'best left to the individual's judgment' on those; whether you feel someone might get the message by repeating it once, or whether they won't get it at all no matter how many people tell it to them, is a case-by-case and person-by-person thing. And yes, no one is suggesting askers should get everything they want handed to them without putting in effort of their own.

Comment: SO ist not a support system. We don't need to be nice and act like its ok if people act stubborn and ignore us.

Comment: @Mafii You do need to [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), that is what you agreed to when you accepted the terms of this site.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this should've been "excessively nice". Being nice but firm is what is okay imo, and some of these comments are (nice but firm), unlike the policy is suggesting.

Comment: @Mafii It sounds like you are using loaded language, and also trying to prescribe quite a narrow view of what the site is for. The site owners and operators are putting out a very clear message that directly contradicts your personal view. Please keep that in mind when commenting so as to avoid confusing new users by inadvertently telling them wrong information!

Comment: @TylerH I see your view. I'm not commenting that way, I just feel like being excessively nice is counter-productive to the sites healthiness over all.

Comment: @Mafii I tend to agree; it makes communication cumbersome, especially for programmers, who are notorious for not being adept at communication or social interaction to begin with. Luckily, they aren't saying we have to be "excessively nice". They are only saying we have to stop being rude and unwelcoming. Bridging the chasm of understanding is where we are right now between the people who recognize what that is, and the people who think there is no difference between reducing unwelcoming/snarky behavior and "being excessively nice".

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Ah. Now that we have the original examples we see that any remotely reasonable projection makes it the new users that the community doesn't really want the real problem.

Comment: @Joshua Your comment doesn't seem grammatically intelligible. Did you leave out a few words or something by mistake?

Comment: @TylerH: Nope. Maybe grouping brackets will help you: [Now [that we have the original examples]] we see [that [any remotely reasonable projection] makes it(1) [the new users [that the community doesn't really want]] the real problem]. (1): unwelcoming to new users

Comment: @Joshua Yep; the "it" being in the sentence in addition to the phrase that follows the "it" is what makes the sentence nonsensical.

Comment: as a non native English speaker I cannot see any difference between `And this is tagged Javascript why?` and `Why is this tagged with JavaScript`. You just changed the `why` position. many non native English speakers don't see these nuances.

Comment: It's quite pointless to comment on the comments like this, since they are taken out of their context. A fairly common situation on SO is this: Q: How do I implement a binary search tree? [Code] Comment: Your memory allocation is wrong, this will crash because [reason]. And then the OP responds to the comment: "Hi can you tell me how to implement a binary search tree?" (the original question). It is then perfectly reasonable to respond with: "This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the [x] is allocated you can’t make progress."

Comment: If you just remove the tag silently then the author will keep misusing it, which wastes the time of everyone watching that tag. It's better to get him/her to consider why it might have been wrong to do that.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga Native English speakers often change the order of words in a sentence to convey different meanings. Ending the sentence with "why" is a more pointed statement than beginning it with "why".

Comment: @PatrickParker That is a big assumption. Do you have any data?

Comment: @Lundin If you think it is pointless to comment on the comments then why bother commenting on the comment on the comments?

Comment: @TylerH data can be massaged to say whatever you want it to say. It's just common sense that people who didn't see a problem with what they were doing will continue under that illusion until someone points it out.

Comment: @PatrickParker If you are not willing to play ball then you don't get to go around saying that playing ball is easy. You are making *several* assumptions about what people will do and why they are doing it. Part of why I asked for data was to make you stop and think about those implicit biases you have as you ponder how to collect and then organize the data.

Answer (score 38):

#### I think what they are trying to get at is that there are nicer ways to say each of those things

> “No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.”

This could be said as: “No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. I'm trying to help you understand this, but I feel as if I am not being heard. Would you please find out how the string is allocated?"

> “And this is tagged Javascript why?”

"Your question seems to be about java(or whatever language it is really about). JavaScript is a completely different language from Java. Do you believe you could remove the JavaScript tag, or perhaos explain more why JavaScript applies to your question?"

> “Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design.”

"Your error looks like it's coming after LEAST(). However you would avoid this problem if you weren't using enumerated columns. I suggest that you reconsider the design of your program, as if you can avoid enumerated columns, then your design will be much much better."

> “For the last time, use the serial number code and replace kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey with kIOPlatformUUIDKey“

"Again, please use the serial number code and replace kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey with kIOPlatformUUIDKey"

> “Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I have already told how you can bind to the property. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”

"Please provide a full compilable sample so that we can help you: [mcve]. Binding to the property should work as I've already said, but if that's not working, show the code and show what you are doing wrong."

### However I don't agree that these are unwelcoming!

> “No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.”

This doesn't sound like an out-of-the-blue comment, it sounds like someone who was trying to help the user, and the user kept complaining or refusing to provide information. Then the commenter, who could have gotten offended and just left the question asker for being rude and wasting their time, decided instead to try once more to help the asker to understand. They specifically say that they are giving advice, and feel that they are not being listened to, yet still try once more to help the user know that "C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory." This isn't an unwelcoming comment, it's a person really trying to help even though the post owner doesn't listen to them.

> “And this is tagged Javascript why?”

I can practically guarantee that this comment was posted to a java question, but someone browsing their favorite tag "JavaScript" clicked on it and started reading only to find that the question had nothing to do with JavaScript. In all honesty, it's rude for people to add tags that don't belong because it wastes the time of people following the other tag only to find that the question has nothing to do with their subject of interest. Just like questions about c++ that aren't compatible with c yet are tagged c.  However, we can give the question asker the benefit of the doubt. Maybe they just don't know how tags work, or maybe they're just barely learning java and think JavaScript is the same thing. So instead of assuming that the person is wasting our time, let's just ask them: And this is tagged JavaScript, why?  I've provided a slightly more welcoming way of phrasing it for people who don't like to be to the point, but this phrase isn't rude or unwelcoming, it's just to the point.

(I actually have a friend from the Dominican Republic and in Spanish he always uses direct phrases like that. Short and to the point. It's just the culture there, it's how they talk and there's nothing rude about it. He never says something as drawn out as "Tu pregunta parece ser enfocado en el idioma Java. Javascript es otro idioma, completemente distinta a Java. ¿Crees que puedes quitar la etiqueta Javascript o explicar por que es necesario?" when he can just say "Y esta etiqueta de Javascript, ¿que?")

> “Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design.”

Wow. This person told the user exactly where to look (after LEAST() ) to correct the answer, however they took the time to point out an existing issue with the code that is provoking the problem in the first place. If calling out [xy](http://xyproblem.info) problems is rude now, I don't know what to tell you. This isn't unwelcoming, it's giving even more helpful material than the user asked for. It's like going into the -- oh wait I just remembered, I'm really bad at analogies, so I'm not going to try that. But it's good. The comment is good.

> “For the last time, use the serial number code and replace kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey with kIOPlatformUUIDKey“

I'm just going to go out on a limb here and say if there's a last time, then there was probably a first and a second time. If a person isn't listening to you, sure, you can just leave them to wallow in disagreeable ignorance. Or you can do as this commenter did, try one last time to help the user. Where on the internet are you going to find people so bent on helping you that even when you are rude to them and not trying what they suggest, they still stick around and with a civil tone try to make sure you do the right thing?

> “Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I have already told how you can bind to the property. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”

If we can't tell the user that their question is unanswerable until they provide more information, and if they aren't listening to the suggestions we are giving, then I think we can just do away with comments completely, there's no real point to them. They are for suggesting improvements and asking for clarification as this user has done. The phrase at the end ". If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”" *might* be considered rude in isolation, but it was preceded by the request of an MCVE so that the commenter could see what that "something wrong" is and help. Saying "something" isn't vague because the person is being unwelcoming, it's vague because there isn't enough information to guess at what the something could be.

In short, if this is the best sample of unwelcoming comments, then I think Stack Overflow is pretty darn welcoming.

Comment: There are *always* nicer ways to say something. However, I'm not willing to sugarcoat every word I'm saying while I'm trying to help solve somebody else's problem. There *is* a thing like "nice enough". And like you said, if this is the worst it comes to there shouldn't be any need for action at all.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I think the problem is your idea of "nice enough" is not nice enough.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You don't have to sugarcoat *anything*. In fact, all of the example comments can become welcoming by removing words (effort), barring the second one.

Comment: @DavyM - your last sentence is totally reinforced by the statistic (in the blog post) that only 7% of the (small) sample of comments were judged unwelcoming anyway.  That's small.

Comment: @davidbak: 7% is not small. Let's say that for every 8 hour period of your life, there's a 7% chance that someone will smack you. Would you consider 7% sufficiently small? The point was made in the blog post that, while it *seems* small, when you factor in the huge *number* of users who come to this site, what appears small can still have a large impact. We can do better.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Getting smacked by 7 out of 100 strangers I meet would be bad.  I don't consider getting smacked by a stranger equivalent to reading any or all of those comments directed at me.  Not equivalent in any way.  Seriously.

Comment: @davidbak: My point is not to make them equivalent. It's to show that how small 7% of depends entirely on how often you encounter the things that make you roll those dice. If someone doesn't meet strangers very often, 7 out of 100 probably isn't that big of a problem.

Comment: "In all honesty, it's rude for people to add tags that don't belong" And there we have the essence of what annoys so many about this "welcoming" project. Question askers are asking experts to answer their questions *for free*, but do not have the courtesy to provide a clear, complete and correct description of their problem. And the those experts are the only ones being expected to be the only courteous.

Comment: @Raedwald: I don't see anyone saying that askers of questions are not expected to be courteous. What's being said is that discourtesy should not be met *in kind*. If someone asks a bad question, or is a jerk towards you, you do not have to do it back to them. Improving the quality of questions is a project actively being worked on; improving the behavior of the community is likewise a project actively being worked on.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's why, after mentioning that what the asker was doing, I said to give them the benefit of the doubt, "so instead of assuming that the person is wasting our time, let's just ask them." This commenter didn't respond rudely, s/he didn't say "Do you not know how tags work?" or "Why are you putting *completely irrelevant tags* like JavaScript?" or "Do you even know what JavaScript is?" but rather s/he just asked why it was tagged JavaScript. No judgement, no nothing. If you're finding “And this is tagged Javascript why?” as unwelcoming, you're reading into things that aren't there.

Answer (score 36):

As the 14th Dalai Lama said:

> Be kind whenever possible.
>
> It is always possible.

The bastard. :-)

---

**Preface**: I'm not defending the study or certain other aspects of how SE is approaching this inclusivity/civility thing. I **do** think SO (the SE I'm active on) has a civility problem (though much less of one than the internet in general and just about any techncial mailing list I've ever read), and that not contributing to that incivility (which I've been guilty of doing) is worth-while.

---

> We cannot tell people they need to provide an MCVE anymore?

Yes, we can, and just generally we can and should (IMHO) hold questions to a reasonable standard, and point it out when they aren't up to standard. We can do so without being rude, sarcastic, and/or dismissive about it. We can be constructive and engaging. Or we can walk away, which is an option I don't think we exercise nearly often enough.

Let's look at those comments, and then I'll wrap-up with my take on "what we're supposed to be doing instead":

---

> No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.

This comment stream is clearly already in a downward spiral and the commenter is getting frustrated (quite probably with good reason). He/she might want to just walk away. But if they choose not to, trying to raise the tone rather than lower it is their better option. Something like:

> No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. Your best bet here is to find out how the string is allocated and take it from there.

---

> And this is tagged Javascript why?

OMG we've all been there. :-) My guess is that comment was on a Java question. Yes, it's really frustrating that people cannot get the distinction between Java and JavaScript, and/or apply tags willy-nilly without bothering to think about what they're doing. It really is. The urge is to slap down the sloppy tagger. And that's the problem: The slap. Instead, maybe:

> FYI, although their names are similar, JavaScript and Java are completely different languages. Please do be careful when tagging. (I've fixed it for you.) :-)

Amazing what a smile can do. A smile and removing the blatant sarcasm, that is.

Or if it it was genuinely unclear why it was tagged JavaScript:

> Why is this tagged JavaScript? Are you using JavaScript somewhere that's not obvious from the question?

---

> Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design.

Bluntness in written communication directed at a stranger usually comes across as rudeness. If the commenter wants to constructively help the OP, this is unlikely to be an effective means of doing so. If they don't, again, there's that *walk away* option.

Perhaps:

> It sounds like you're after [`LEAST()`](http://example.com). But I've found that having enumerated columns is generally not a great idea because [short, probably incomplete list of reasons]. So you'd probably be better off revisiting the design to see if there's a way to avoid them.

---

> For the last time, use the serial number code and replace `kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey` with `kIOPlatformUUIDKey`

Another comments thread that's already in a downward spiral. I've made comments like this in the past, and I shouldn't have, and I knew that long before the current Be Nice Mark II.

In this case, if that suggestion isn't in an answer, it probably should be. If there's a reason it can't be, then since the commenter has already told the OP what to do (at least once, from the sound of it), the best option is probably just to walk away.

---

> Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I have already told how you can bind to the property. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.

No one likes being told they're doing something wrong by a stranger on the internet, particularly when the person telling them that doesn't even know if that's actually true (because they haven't seen it). Perhaps:

> Please provide a full compilable sample, it will help us help you; more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If you've tried to bind to the property as I described above, it sounds like there's some error in the code doing that, so if you show us that code, we should be able to help you fix it.

---

Re the updated comments, you specifically called out the third one, saying you didn't see what was wrong with it:

> The code you posted cannot yield this result. Please post the real code if you hope to get any help.

It's not that bad, IMHO, but "if you hope to get any help" isn't all that useful. Perhaps:

> The code in the question cannot yield this result. Perhaps you accidentally removed the part of it causing the trouble to keep your example short, or missed out a compilaton step, or similar? Please update the question with a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and paste to see the problem ourselves, so we can help you fix the problem.

You wrote:

> If somebody is lying about their code they need to be told exactly that.

It's not likely that person is **lying**. It's much more likely that they're mistaken.

---

None of which answers your main question:

> Please tell me what we're supposed to be doing instead then. Walk away and don't provide any help at all rather than call a spade a spade?

FWIW, this is where I've come to after nearly nine years, for a question that isn't up to standard:

- In general, I think it's possible initially to say something constructive and engaging. I have several bookmarklets I use for the usual situations (MCVEs, how to ask, etc.) which I hope achieve that. These are usually accompanied by a close vote but not a downvote. (But sometimes both, because sometimes the post justifies both.)
- If they reply and there's something further constructive I can say, I'll do so (within limits; I have other things to do :-) ).
- If they don't do their part and improve the post, and I'm aware of it (because I stuck around, or they `@` pinged me, whatever), I'll usually downvote and walk away. There's no getting around the fact that this happens **a lot**. There are a lot of people who don't respect SO and the time of SO contributors. I've done my part: I've been friendly, but also (hopefully) clear. They haven't done their part. At this point, if they take that as unwelcoming, well, okay. I'm fine with that.

  - For particularly egregious posts, I even wait for it to be closed so I can vote to delete. (And I've recently realized I can sometimes accelerate that process by dropping a [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org).)
- If they do bring their question up to standard (and this happens a lot too, though sadly not as often as the other), I remove my comment, remove my close vote, remove my downvote if any, upvote if the updated question is useful, and either answer, or walk away because I don't know the answer, don't have time to answer, etc.
- If the OP is rude or similar, I flag the comment as Rude or Abusive. Then I walk away unless there's a very, very good reason that I should post a reply to the rudeness. For instance, if they rudely point out that I'm wrong about something, and they're right, I might reply acknowledging that (and removing the incorrect comment) but also asking them (politely) not to be rude. (And I probably shouldn't even do that, but...I do. Again: They haven't done their part, so if they find that unwelcoming, well...okay.)
- If the OP is unwilling to put in effort, or (bluntly) clueless, or both, I'll stick with it for a couple of rounds if it seems like we might get there, trying to help, but if I'm approaching that "Look, as I said above, do X. If you're not willing to do X, I can't help you." moment, that's a big walk-away trigger. I used to post those comments. I don't anymore. They didn't work anyway, didn't make me feel any less frustrated, and almost certainly ran afoul even the old Be Nice policy. :-)

So when I say that the **walking away** option isn't used often enough, I don't mean doing so from the outset (though some questions really are just not worth bothering). It's just I've learned that getting involved in long exchanges with someone who isn't being constructive at their end just ends up with me getting frustrated and, sometimes, posting something sarky or even rude that I later regret. So I'm learning to recognize those situations and walk away from them.

That's my take, FWIW. :-)

Comment: In fairness to the folks who confuse Java with JavaScript, Brendan Eich's original "LiveScript" language was renamed to "JavaScript" *specifically because* Sun Microsystems wanted people to confuse it with Java, for marketing reasons that I don't entirely understand. Ever since, we've been dealing with their continuing success.

Comment: @MarkAmery - Indeed. In fact, in my rewrite, I originally had *"...names are (intentionally) similar..."* but then figured I was distracting from the point. Perhaps I should have kept it. :-)

Comment: As for your proposed rewrites, in a few cases it's non-obvious to me whether the average reader would find them more or less polite than the originals. In particular, throwing in a smiley face risks being taken as patronising, and I can see the "good luck!"s rubbing some people the wrong way - there's a risk that by spelling out what needs doing but then also wishing someone luck doing it, you imply that it's trivial *for you* but a difficult task *for them* that you think they might fail at, which then comes across as a put-down. I think I *roughly* agree that these are improvements, though.

Comment: @MarkAmery - Well, not just throwing in a smiley face. Also removing the blatant sarcasm. People *can* read just about anything as patronizing and sarcastic. My goal these days is to not *write* patronizing or sarky comments (e.g., knowingly), which hopefully at least reduces the odds of their being *read* that way.

Comment: @MarkAmery - Good point about the "Good luck!" Re-reading it, there's just no saving that comment (without more context), I updated. Thanks.

Comment: I was exaggerating when I wrote "lying". Still, I believe it brought the point across regardless.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Fair enough. :-)

Comment: As for walking away: yes, that *is* always an option, and I do that most of the time when I get the impression that nothing I could say would improve the current situation. However, would walking away really improve the overall situation? Remember, the perceived problem is that people on the Internet accuse SO of being unwelcoming. Now consider that we stop responding to people who fail to provide the information required for actually solving their problem. Do you think they will not return to whence they came and complain how unwelcoming SO is?

Comment: A point about "lying" - it's not a big stretch to call it a lie, posting example code that does not exhibit a problem described in the question indeed amounts to making a false statement. But when you call something a "lie", most people think that you are presuming there was an intent to post a lie, and things go downhill from there. I agree that the examples in the blog post are not the best ones to get their point across. But if their point is to stay as neutral as possible when trying to convey the meaning - I agree with it completely.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Your comment above points out to me that I got lost in the detail of the example comments and *didn't actually address the main part of your question*. Sorry about that. I've done so now.

Comment: Do we really need to cap an ascii-smiley on the end of every comment which could possibly be construed as criticism? It seems like we're reflooring the internet in egg-shells via wanton carebearification. :|

Comment: @canon - When you're interacting with someone directly, the amount of non-verbal communication is **huge**. So the occasional smiley or similar helps bridge that gap and impart tone. (Now, personally, I think tacking a stream of emojis on the end of a message is OTT, but hey...)

Comment: I don't have a policy as detailed as that, but basically I'm doing the same. And it's also what I see other people doing (in the tags I'm active in). But from my understanding that is not what the "be welcoming" movement is about. Because if it were there would be no need to take action in the first place. It's exactly the *perceived* "unwelcomingness" (is that actually a word?) that seems to be in the focus, and I don't see how that could go well (b/c from all I can see all changes in that direction would require compromising our quality standards).

Comment: Everything goes better with *something* attached to the end of each sentence. Desu.

Comment: Henceforth, all of my comments will be clearly marked as _dead-pan_. :|

Comment: Was the current Dalai Lama born out of wedlock?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - I could be mistaken, but I think the current thing is because the comments posted at bullet point one have frequently been *not* constructive and engaging. "Do your own homework." "Have you at least glanced at the documentation?" "Have you even tried to do this yourself?" and lots of downvoting up-front, etc. And that does seem to be getting slightly better.

Comment: @TylerH - :-) It's a joke. I"m basically saying "Drat, he's right" and being a bit unhappy at being called on my sarky fun.

Comment: But does it help in that we're getting better questions, or at least less crappy ones? Guiding people so that they learn how to tackle a problem is fine with me, but I still do not believe that we even *want* to be welcoming to people who are just looking for a sucker to do their work for them.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - There are definitely some people I don't want to be welcoming to. The problem is I don't know in advance who they are. Example: The no-research, didn't-bother-to-check-docs question. When someone posts one of those, there are at least two possibilities: Person A who knows full well they're trying to get other people to do their work, or Person B who thinks that's what SO is for, people getting rep in return for doing their work. When you call directory enquiries to get someone's phone number (which used to be a free call), they don't reply with "Well, did you look *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* in the phone book?" They're there for the purpose of doing that for you. SO isn't, but not everyone knows that. So by keeping the tone high when we tell them that, we educate Person B without belittling them. There's nothing we can do about Person A other than eventually question-ban or even IP-ban them. And there will always those people regardless of how we comment; they're immune to sark. Maybe SE can cut down on their rubbish with a question template, maybe not, but we aren't going to with sarky comments that slide off Person A but hurt and discourage Person B.

Comment: I agree with all of that. What I'm trying to say is: we're already doing.what you describe. We're trying to educate person B. But it's person A who is complaining about how "unwelcoming" SO is, which is what lead to the "Welcome Wagon". The part I probably disagree most with in the infamous "SO isn't welcoming enough" blog post is the assertion "we know it's true, because they tell us". Just because somebody tells you they feel one way or the other doesn't mean they actually have a reason to feel that way. Or that they're even telling you the truth in the first place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Yeah, well, there were [a few issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/#comment582425_366924) with that blog post. :-) And that bit in particular was...poorly-judged. But I don't need them to tell us; I see it for myself in the unfriendly, sarky, unwelcoming comments on newbie questions that I still see every day. (And on answers and...) From the sound of it, you're not someone posting those comments. I used to be, and there are still plenty who are. I'm probably not on the same page as SE on a lot of this, but I do agree that that behavior needs to be changed.

Comment: Well, I don't see that amount of unfriendliness (quite on the contrary), but the tags I'm active in aren't that high-volume, and I also noticed that culture seems to differ quite a lot between tags.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Ah, yeah, it does. Hang around the [tag:javascript] tag for a while... :-)

Comment: That's something I actively avoid, and not because of the people ... ;)

Comment: "The best opinion is to walk away". Exactly. But I doubt SO will become a better place if all active answering people just "walk away". Nicer? Maybe. More useful? Guess.

Answer (score 22):

While many people might see this as a sudden change, I found that the blog post tended to reflect how comments have been flagged over the years that I've been a moderator. Almost all comments are fine. Truly abusive comments are relatively easy to identify, and you have a strong consensus as to what they are (the tight clustering in their study). And then there's the "unwelcoming" ones we're talking about here.

The broad distribution on the "unwelcoming" case is to be expected. Different people have different views as to what crosses the line, as can be seen in the arguments in the comments and answers here about the cases they highlight.

Comments like each of the ones above (as well as the new composite comments they edited into the post) have regularly been flagged by the community. In the past, many comments like this would have been flagged as "not constructive", but now we see them getting flagged as "no longer needed" or sometimes "rude and abusive". If we pulled a list of comments flagged in this manner over the years, I bet you'd see many that look similar to what they highlight in the post.

To me, it isn't shocking to see the results of a study like this, because that's how people have flagged things over the years. Stack Exchange themselves [employed Mechanical Turk to look at comments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/23/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/) during the Summer of Love project and found outside people rating comments in a similar manner.

Comments like this are going to continue to be flagged, I don't think this study will change that much. Kendra's answer provides excellent suggestions for how to reword them to alter tone while preserving information, which I think is a worthwhile goal, flags or not.

What is done in response to those flags is another topic, and not something I'll get into here, but I wanted to point out that in my years moderating the site I've seen a very similar distribution to what you see in that study.

Comment: *What is done in response to those flags is another topic* But that is the part that actually concerns me, particularly in the light of the new [code of conduct](https://github.com/tinkertim/StackCOC/blob/master/The%20Stack%20Exchange%20Network%20Code%20of%20Conduct%20(R7).pdf).

Comment: IOW, any comment that isn't a pat-on-the-back/positive-reinforcement is automatically unwelcoming.

Comment: @Mysticial I certainly hope we are not required to pat backs here. I just read the COC and my understanding is that as long as we do not add negativity, all is well. Perhaps it would be better if they clarify that neutral is good.

Comment: Clarifying; it might be nice [or not] for people to give  pat-on-the-back/positive-reinforcement , but I do not think it is necessary. External reinforcement can even be, but is not always, unhelpful. The best is to help questioners arrive at the place of their own internal satisfaction, pride, self-respect, and self-motivation that arises naturally from solving problems . Our part in this is to offer them respect.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile - That's odd, I thought our part in this was to offer them _answers_.  In fact, I kind of thought that in answering at all - something which takes time and effort - the respect was _implicit_: The asker wasn't ignored, but was taken seriously and was therefore worth taking the time and effort to answer.

Comment: Maybe you can help elevate this to a new question/etc @davidbak , but imho the goal is to offer respectful answers, as opposed to offering disrespectful answers. Maybe you think I think all the above items listed by OP are disrespectful. I do not.

Comment: You've got guts man. I've been expecting to find a heavily downvoted mod answer to this question.

Comment: *`Different people have different views as to what crosses the line`* That's...precisely...the problem I have with the proposed CoC...

Comment: @Draco18s: Different people have different views as to what is or isn't "nice". I'm sure many people see the comments here as perfectly "nice", while many others don't. So the Be Nice policy is no less subjective. After all, as Brad points out, comments like these have been flagged previously and removed previously. So they were often considered to violate Be Nice.

Comment: Solution is simple: implement some sort of penalty for raising pointless flags.

Answer (score 21):

> No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.

I'm fairly sure I wrote this comment.

For sure it is snarky. And it would be better without the snark.

Of course, the multiple previous comments that were posted without the snark, that were ignored by the asker, weren't offered up as context. As so many other answers and comments here point out, the snark is a response to frustration. It's not a good response, but it is a human response.

Was it unwelcoming? That's really a moot point. This comment was made way after the welcome stage. Then the asker was made perfectly welcome but for whatever reason was unable to heed the advice that they sought. Certainly my efforts were treated as being unwelcome!

It's a little ironic that so little seems to be done to make life easier for this site's most valued asset - its providers of content. Why is so much effort expended on those who flood the site with poor content and so little on those who try to curate? Perhaps I'm wrong on this one, but that's how it feels to me.

Suppose these welcome wagon efforts succeed and we train our experts to disengage as soon as we encounter askers that don't want to listen or heed advice to clarify and improve posts. What then? Will the asker feel any more happy about the transaction? Nope. They will feel frustrated that they didn't get their answer and that the question was ignored.

My honest belief is that the majority of askers who come away feeling unhappy with their experiences here cannot be pleased. Their expectations are unrealistic and can't be met.

I hope I am wrong, but I have little hope that this site will be able to satisfy its goal of curating high quality questions and answers, whilst at the same time ensuring that everybody who posts here feels happy with the interactions.

Comment: I've been a victim of your snark David but the points that you made in the snark that you have dealt me were valid and so I corrected my post accordingly to try to improve its quality. But I'd like to make it clear that the snark is not appreciated and indeed feels unwelcoming. Where you might have a point is some people are motivated by negative criticism. But I still think kindness can rule the day.Point out shortcomings in a kind way and leave it at that. If the poster really wants more they'll have to comply.

Comment: @Jonathan I agree and I think I acknowledged that in this answer.

Comment: This might be an interesting analysis to do on SO threads: "How many posts are improved after negative criticism" vs. "How many are improved after positive criticism". I hope that kindness rules the day but I don't actually know if it does. After all I'm admitting that I changed my post after you snarked at me not before ;)

Comment: @Jonathan In this case the post was not improved after positive criticism and the asker instead was rude, and I responded with snark. I think that's quite common. Obviously I should have walked away, but I think that there is value in understanding why posters here sometimes resort to snark. As far as posters feeling welcome goes, I think that can be taken too far. For sure we should be nice to good faith askers. But do we really need to make bad faith askers feel welcome?

Comment: Well if the asker was rude after positive criticism then I'm entirely with you, there is no redeeming them. You did your best and were met with rudeness. I completely understand a "human response" in that context.

Comment: @Jonathan It's a very understandable human response but it achieves nothing and weakens any arguments. So walking away is the right thing to do. I'm still struggling to learn how to do that consistently.

Comment: Well I wish you the best. Inspite of your snark I appreciate that high quality content providers like yourself are here on SO. And for my part I'll try not to take the snark so personally, looking past it to see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 13):

To me this blog post provided an interesting indication that problem with snarky comments can't be reliably handled without addressing the problem of low quality questions flooding the site.

Particular example that made me feel that way is "And this is tagged Javascript why?" (it is removed from current version of blog article but [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180710130804/https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/07/10/welcome-wagon-classifying-comments-on-stack-overflow/) shows that it was there from the very start).

I've seen this example discussed in at least five prior answers and all fairly reliably suggested that it can be perceived as snarky. For the sake of precision, some also reasonably point that in some cases this wording could be caused by mere lack of English fluency, but this only means that it would be discriminatory to punish commenter for unintended snark (note that snark would still be there and better be dealt with).

What stroke me is that I regularly observe similar comments in my close reviews and, which is maybe even more interesting, these tend to be posted on particularly poor questions,

> *My homework assignment is to write a calculator, pls help. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)*

I've seen an answer from moderator that comments like that could be flagged and deleted, which sounds like a good approach in general but I can't see how it can work in cases like described above. Because, if you think of it, even if moderator deletes one comment in such a question, it can (and most probably will) be reposted by some other user, especially if question uses highly active tag(s) like javascript.

Sad thing is, even phrasing comment in more friendly / neutral tone is unlikely to help, because in questions like that it would be practically doomed to trigger a snarky "follow-up" from someone else, *hey @commenter don't you see that lazy asker simply spam-tagged their homework dump to make sure that it annoys as many people as possible*.

Another suggestion I've seen for this example was to edit out the tag. It also sounds good on a surface. You can even ask yourself a question, why folks even bother commenting when edit seems to be obvious path of least resistance... or is it really?

I for one tend to abstain from edits like that because if you look closer, removal of the tag would fail to make it really better. I think that many (maybe most) active editors would also feel that way. And even users under 2K who may be tempted by a chance to get +2 rep are at risk of getting their suggestions rejected [as explained eg here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255767/839601).

So it's kind of a stalemate, the tag looks clearly superfluous but its removal looks superfluous as well. No wonder that it adds to frustration and tends to cause snarky comments.

---

Summing up above, it is hard to imagine how things can improve while such question is visible, especially if it is open (closed questions probably draw less attention).

Answer (score 8):

> Please tell me what we're supposed to be doing instead then. Walk away and don't provide any help at all rather than call a spade a spade?

Yes. Stop answering on SO.
That's it.

You know the answer but they want you to use some fancy words when you write it down? Just quit.
Jason and Julia will answer in your stead since they know how to answer properly.

Comment: This is not a helpful post in any way.

Comment: might not be helpful, but certainly needs to be said...

Comment: @Abyx thank you so much for demonstrating the absurdity.

Comment: Exactly. We don't need to bow down to jerks. It's the same logic around 10x engineers - if they're jerks, then nothing they contribute compensates for the vast # of people they drive away.

Comment: Upvoted. Stack Overflow seems to be focused on a short-time goal, to maximize the number of **people** using the platform. However, not every user is equal, and this policy aims to raise the number of users by increasing the influx of new, inexperienced users who contribute low-quality questions. In the medium term, that chases away the people who contribute the high-value answers, and in the long term that turns Stack Overflow into the new ExpertsExchange.

Comment: While people may or may not agree on the direction SO is being led, this post is plainly assuming bad faith. Please stop.

Comment: This answer is too *unwelcoming*

Comment: @PasserBy: Check the upvote/downvote counts on this question. It's currently +54/-54.

Comment: @Joshua I created the dis-balance now. :)

Comment: Perfectly balanced, as all things should be.

Comment: @MSalters careful with these "not every user is equal". Nowadays one can be burned for saying things like this…

Answer (score 0):

A rule to perhaps live by with comments as well as answers, in the vein of acting professionally and respectfully is: "would you say this to a coworker" or in particular "would you say this to your line manager"?

"I already told you" "You aren't going to listen" - etc. Of course we all know developers who do act like that in the workplace so it's a grey area still. But people who treat their coworkers in this way are often viewed as difficult and tolerated only because they are very skilled. They likely get passed over for promotion and are viewed as a trope.

Comment: Something I've always kept in the back of my head is: *"Would you step in front of a small auditorium and say this?"* Because that's essentially what posting anything on the internet is. And I wish a lot more question *askers* would keep that in mind too.

Comment: Hmm, I take your point but an auditorium of people are generally there to listen to you not answer you. Perhaps visiting your tutor who only has a few minutes to spare is a nicer analogy - prepare your question in advance so they have a chance to actually answer it.

Comment: The situation here is really more akin to presenting your problem to an auditorium of people and asking for their advise. Perhaps imagine [$YourCountry's Got Talent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Got_Talent) instead, that's pretty apt IMO.

Answer (score -2):

I see no issue with the original examples being unwelcoming:

- “No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. **You won’t listen to my advice.** If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.” *in bold, this is antagonistic and egotistical*
- “Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design.” - *I'd take this one on context personally. I don't mind such things in comments IF it is backed up with something helpful*
- “**For the last time**, use the serial number code and replace kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey with kIOPlatformUUIDKey“ - *how is this NOT rude?*
- “Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. **I have already told how you can bind to the property. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”** - *Asking and repeating the request for a MVCE is one thing. Criticism and irritation in comments isn't needed. Just leave it out. If they ignore you, leave the topic*

Software developers are often quite abrupt when communicating electronically, I would say that's an issue with an industry not "the way it is". If you can't provide polite answers without getting upset when someone doesn't listen, don't post answers. People ARE going to ignore you. Move on.

Answer (score -3):

I really don't think the new examples do the idea of "unwelcoming comments" their justice - here's one that I screenshotted before the commenter was pressured to delete:

[image: img1]

These are the kind of comments that need to be immediately flagged or removed, and have no place on SO.

Comment: The thing is, nobody is defending such comments. People are defending these comments here. The fact that there are worse comments does not make these *good*.

Comment: @NicolBolas a lof of people (myself included) don't see much of a difference.

Comment: @Pureferret Wait, you don't see a difference between, "Epic fail" and "The code you posted cannot yield this result. Please post the real code if you hope to get any help."?  That's, frankly, absurd.  One is nothing but a snide jab with no real value at all, neither describing a problem, nor how that problem can be addressed, and one is a professional and polite statement describing a problem with the question and how to fix it.

Comment: @Servy I originally posted this picture because I don't feel that "The code you posted cannot yield this result. Please post the real code if you hope to get any help." is an unwelcoming comment - my example is probably too extreme, but I don't think the examples that we're displaying above are properly capturing the truly snarky, rude unwelcoming comments that plague this site.

Comment: @NicolBolas Actually, the poster of the "Epic fail" comment was defending it :)

Comment: @servy no, that's an unfair example of what were discussing. From the op's post, this is closer to 'epic fail': "This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. " It's not the same tone, but the message is equally unwelcoming.

Comment: @Pureferret It's not an  unfair example.  You said that the image above is the same as the quotes from the question.

Comment: @Pureferret As to the other comment that you'd prefer to compare it to, that comment states that what they said was wrong, what the correct statement is, and what they need to be doing differently to resolve their problem.  That's all useful information.  Them stating that it's a waste of their time for their advice not to be followed is not being rude, it's not insulting for its own sake, like "epic fail" is, rather it's a statement that if the *helpful advice providing a solution to the problem* isn't going to be followed, help will no longer be given.  That's all *radically* different.

Comment: @servy it is stated factually and delivers facts. I'm not questioning that. I didn't even say it was rude. It is not welcoming though. Yes, to be welcoming you have to go out of your way, and yes it requires more effort. It's going above and beyond. Just stating facts is below the minimum desired to be welcoming.

Comment: @Pureferret If you want to have a place to socialize with people, and exchange pleasantries, and otherwise have a community with a low signal to noise ratio because it emphasizes pleasantries over useful programming information, then there are lots of social networks out there that attempt to deliver on that.  SO is not designed to do those things.  It's designed to be a place where you ask clear, low noise, questions, and get clear, low noise, responses.  Users are expected to be professionals that can handle formal communications like that.

Comment: @Servy There is no reason why Stack Overflow can't have a healthy balance of both of those.

Comment: @dwirony Yes, there is actually.   You can't have a low noise, formal, direct, and professional environment and also say that people who provide helpful, on topic, concise technical information aren't welcome because they need to go out of their way and spend considerable effort to obfuscate all of their communications with additional language there for the sole purpose of socializing.

Comment: @Servy And that's not what I'm saying - nobody has to go out of their way, if you want to maintain a low noise/professional mantra then that's fine by me, but if you're going to be critical of people that throw an occasional pleasantry in there then that's wrong and we're back to the problems of an unwelcoming environment on this site - and you keep mentioning the professional world like everything is done by the books, but it's not and a lot of interactions extend beyond a formal/direct demeanor - it's how people build relationships...

Comment: @dwirony "And that's not what I'm saying" That's what Pureferret said, and you said you supported it.  The site already does a *lot* to actively prevent socialization.  They're automatically removed from posts, and encouraged to be edited out if they are not filtered, for example.  It's a very *explicit* goal of the site that they're trying to *prevent* such behaviors.   They want people to find the information they're looking for, and not have to look through someone else's off topic casual conversation to find it.

Comment: @servy I did say that, but only in reference to merely stating the very base facts. It should be no effort to say "I don't think we're getting anywhere" instead of "Your wasting my time". Yes deliberately making the tone friendly is 'more', but the effort should be negligible.

Comment: @Pureferret But you were very explicit about the fact that you *aren't* expecting a negligible effort.  You said, "Yes, to be welcoming you have to go out of your way, and yes it requires more effort. It's going above and beyond. Just stating facts is below the minimum desired to be welcoming."  So according to  you people need to spend considerable effort, going above and beyond expectations (which is of course entirely contradictory, you can't say that the minimum expectations are well above the minimum expectations), in order to be welcoming.

Answer (score -4):

You propose to routinely edit comments to remove tone, etc. Don't do it man. Comments have no publicly visible edit history, and as far as I can tell no notice on being edited. Editing comments besides strikethrough should be reserved for great issues and rarely done.

You wanna hear people cry censorship, edit comments. So 1984 is being a pain and his post deserved massive downvotes. But the pain has a point buried within his rant. Stuffing words into people's mouths is not acceptible.

Comment: There are three alternatives: let the crap fester, remove the comment entirely, or remove the bad part of it. Letting it fester is not a good solution. And people have started to "cry censorship" to the point where the word is starting to lose its impact and meaning.

Comment: @NicolBolas: People are proposing things like "But don’t do that. Fix your design." -> "So you'd probably be better off revisiting the design to see if there's a way to avoid them." which is none of the choices you gave.

Answer (score -6):

Posts like this make me just want to hug a member of the SO team.

This will never get resolved. On one side, you have these very logical engineering oriented answerers whose primary goal is the facts, and on the other side you have customer-oriented  users whose primary goal is helping people.  Hand-holders vs Emotionless Robots (to borrow terms from each camp).  Neither is wrong, but both should probably attempt to be more like the other, or at the very least, see the other perspective.

Anyway... hugs.

Comment: Oh, you're expecting "customer-oriented" people? Where I can collect my pay for serving those "customers"?

Comment: "and on the other side you have customer-oriented users whose primary goal is helping people." Yes, the site is owned by people whose goals are irreconcilably at odds with the purpose of the site's existence. We know. The contradiction is becoming more unavoidable by the day. Might I take a moment to promote https://codidact.com ?

Answer (score -9):

Yes, I think those quotes can be interpretted as unwelcoming.  Perhaps you interpet tone differently than those who find it unwelcoming?

We can nitpick how to word things all day long.  Fix your feelings.  Meaning, if you're angry, upset, frustrated, annoyed, that will come out in your writing.  If you feel positively toward others, your tone will follow.  I suspect all of the comments had negative emotion when written.  That being said, here's a detailed (arugably nitpicky) explanation of the tone:

Calling the comments "allegedly" unwelcoming is telling. It can convey an attitude that you know it all. Of course you may not think that.  But since you didn't say something like "I'm having a hard time understanding why these are unwelcoming; can you help me understand?" which emphasizes that you're trying to learn, maybe you don't perceive tone the same way some others do.  And if you don't perceive tone the same way, no wonder you don't see how they're unwelcoming to some.

I will break down the unwelcoming I saw in the quotes:

> “No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.”

It's unwelcoming to call a social interaction a waste.  (It's also hypocritical - why continue if it's truly a waste.)

When you say "You won’t listen to my advice" you're making a statement about the other person.  Something you don't know.  That's aggressive.  Try talking about yourself, instead. Also, suggest *you* change.  "I feel misunderstood. How can I explain things better?"

People learn all sorts of ways.  People will make progress their way, most likely.  It may just be slower.  Something similar that's more welcoming: "I believe you will make progress faster if you do it this way.  Here's why." You've qualified it as a belief instead of absolute. You're acknowledging their process works (instead of inability to make progress); there's just a (probably) better way.

> “And this is tagged Javascript why?”

You said second example aside; skipping.

> “Also, any time you have enumerated columns, you can be sure that something’s gone very, very wrong with your design. That said, you’re probably after LEAST(). But don’t do that. Fix your design.”

Rather than pointing out weaknesses in the existing, point out strengths of the alternative.  That's positive. Also answer the question, first. It can be slightly condescending to answer a tangential question before answering OP's actual question.  The tone is demeaning with "you can be sure" and "very, very".  Here's a more welcoming alternative: "To solve your immediate problem, you should be able to use LEAST().  However when you enumerate columns, there's usually a way to improve the design, at least if the goal is to [insert purpose of design change here].  Here's how to do that."  Explicitly mentioning the design purpose along with the design is less dogmatic and shows the subjectivity in architecture.

> “For the last time, use the serial number code and replace kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey with kIOPlatformUUIDKey“

"For the last time" can be omitted; it's only unwelcoming.

> “Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I have already told how you can bind to the property. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”

Again, talking about others can be aggressive.  Consider "In order to help you we need a compilable sample."  "I have already told you" can be omitted; it only contributes to being unwelcome. Sometimes the fault isn't the user.  So "if you can't make it work" could be better worded as "if it doesn't work".  It's possible that they're doing everything right, but there's, say, a hardware error.  So "you are doing something wrong" could be better worded as "you are probably doing something wrong".  Both changes make the sentence more welcoming.  However, the idea may be omitted; I don't see much value.  A better idea may be, "if it doesn't work, let us know what you did so we can help further".

Comment: *`"For the last time" can be omitted; it's only unwelcoming.`* While I can agree with this in general, I have run across people who see the "Do the X with the fizzbar" comment--posted six times--and respond with "I did the Y to the foobizz, but it still doesn't work." Not here on SO, but I have run across these people. When you've told them six times what to do, they still haven't done it, and still think they're entitled to being helped. What would happen on SO is there would be six, identical comments, and they'd get flagged for removal under one reason or another (possibly even "rude").

Comment: @Draco18s That's a good point.  All of these quotes were taken out of context.  With context, welcoming or not may differ.

Comment: Heck, "welcoming" varies *by the reader.* The same sentence that to me looks kind and helpful can--to a plausible but hypothetical reader--could be [patronizing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/patronizing?s=t) or [pedantic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pedantic?s=t). Whereas a message, devoid of overly flowery language, is clear and to the point might be viewed as [brusk](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brusk). I encourage readers to view the definitions of each linked word to fully understand my point.

Comment: *When you say "You won’t listen to my advice" you're making a statement about the other person. Something you don't know. That's aggressive.* Wow we seem to have a very low threshold for aggression

Comment: @00 "we" - I think I see what you did there. I'm having trouble understanding why you don't find "you" aggressive - could you elaborate? Aggressive may be the wrong word.  What I'm describing is related to [I-statements vs you-statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-message).

Comment: @Draco18s I agree. It's tough to get tone right for everyone.  (I assume I did a poor job in my post, given my down-votes.)  To your point, I try to adapt to my audience. If someone appears terse I may take clear and to the point. etc.

Comment: If I could downvote your answer a 2nd time after your last edit, I would. Your point came across quite clear in the earlier versions of your answer. But the amateurish psychological  advice you give about "fixing" feelings is nothing I appreciate.

Comment: @LutzHorn What would adept psychological advice recommend?

Comment: None at all. If I want psychological advice I make an appointment with a professional. And this will not be anywhere on or near the SO/SE network.

Comment: @LutzHorn I think I follow your reasoning - discussing feelings is not appropriate on SE. I'm trying to understand how to answer better: why else did you give -1?

Comment: In the 2nd version I especially did not like this: 'the calling the comments "allegedly" unwelcoming is telling - that conveys an attitude that you know'. I don't think we should make diagnosis about others attitudes or character based on SO/SE posts.

Comment: @LutzHorn I wasn't trying to say OP had that atittude.  I said OP came across with (conveys) that attitude.  The whole point of being welcoming is how you come across; my answer was largely addressing that - how you come across, not how you actually are.  Does that make sense? Was that not clear?

Answer (score -14):

These type of comments just feel like you are patronizing the person or making he or she feels like she did something really bad. Some people are more sensitive and that's okay. We should be more inclusive, because if people feels welcomed, they are more likely to pursue programming and who knows, maybe they will answer your question one day?

Comment: Any person in the world can choose to take criticism of their work personally, that does not mean we should stop criticising people's work. It means they should stop taking it personally.

Comment: If you're feeling that bad about "patronizing", maybe you shouldn't ask other people to figure out and provide answers to your questions for you.

Answer (score -18):

I completely disagree with the OP. The vast majority of the examples that they used (and defended), while they may have provided some sort of answer to the question, were extremely sassy. If a commenter can't control their tone and respect the OP, they shouldn't comment at all. The point of this site is to help people, and even to provide constructive criticism. Not to outright scold them. You're not their parents, so don't act like it. If they choose not to accept your original advice, let it be; don't resort to insulting them.

Comment: "sassy", "scold", "insulting". No, nothing of this is in these comments, neither in the original nor the modified ones.

Comment: In response to @LutzHorn here is the first example that was used: “No. As it stands the C# marshaler is going to call CoTaskMemFree to deallocate the memory. This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.” Now you're telling me those last 3 sentences are necessary?

Comment: Necessary? Maybe not. But sassy, scold, insulting? No. The quoted commend obviously is out of context. There has been an attempt to help the person asking the question. The last three sentences express the frustration of the commenter about the unwillingness of the asker to be helped.

Comment: And as I stated, if you try to help someone and they don't accept your advice just walk away. You have no stake in the matter and don't benefit if the poster succeeds in solving their problem. There is no reason to get "frustrated" at someone for not accepting your suggestions.

Comment: @LutzHorn, Try saying `This is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice.` aloud to your colleague next time he asks you a question. If this is the way you communicate, even if it's tit for tat, it's not likely to go down well in most professional organisations. You can argue all day on the correct epithet to describe such language.

Comment: @jpp A colleague of a programmers in a *professional* organization would probably not ask a question or behave so ignorant that the asked person would think about commenting like this. Part of being a professional is knowing what and how to ask.

Comment: @LutzHorn, As I said, "tit for tat" isn't condoned in most professional organisations. You seem to think it is.

Comment: @jpp No. I think that in a professional environment question quality will be much higher that what we encouter daily on SO. You will usually not be asked to solve some lazy pupils homework assignment in the workplace. Also, colleagues will not refuse help as it is common on SO.

Comment: @LutzHorn Actually, as much as I may have agreed with that statement in the past, I have seen recently that just because someone is in a professional organization doesn't make them knowledgeable. People ask dumb questions, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Yes, we're not their parents.  So we should be holding them accountable to our quality standards.  We are not obligated to help them in any sense, so if users want help, it would be beneficial to themselves to actually follow our rules and work with the community, not against it.

Comment: "The point of this site is to help people, and even to provide constructive criticism. Not to outright scold them." - The hypocrisy here is palpable. By your own reasoning, you should have provided examples of alternative phrasing to get the point across without "scolding" or "sass". But you didn't - maybe because you intuitively understand the forces at play? ...Unless, of course, you don't actually agree that people should be told how to fix their questions, or maybe even that questions should have to meet standards. That would seem to align with the "accept your advice" phrasing.

Answer (score -44):

"No. As it stands this is now rather a waste of time. You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work out how to relate to other human beings, you can't make progress.

And this time you're answering questions on Stack Overflow, you're doing so voluntarily. If you get frustrated, walk away. Nobody is forcing your labor out of you. But don’t do that. Fix your attitude.

For the last time, this is a website for voluntarily answering questions, and it's silly to expect everybody else to be as smart as you, even more so to get so up in arms about politeness guidelines from a post on the website's own blog that you write home about it.

Please provide a full compilable sample if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/07/10/welcome-wagon-classifying-comments-on-stack-overflow. I have already told how you can be a kinder person by not needlessly injecting meritocratic brogrammer attitude into everything. If you can’t make it work, you are doing something wrong.”

Do you not see how this is a toxic way of talking to people?

> Are you kidding me?

No.

> Really?

Yes.

The idea that people can be so busy that they can't take the time to communicate kindly is funny, because these same people are voluntarily answering questions on Stack Overflow, and some are then writing lengthy arguments about how they should be allowed to be rude as they do so, and posting them in Meta.

It costs you nothing to be kind, and common courtesy is not some sort of limited resource.

It's not about giving people a warm fuzzy feeling, it's about letting nontraditional learners, women, people of color, and non-native speakers of English into the industry, which'll never happen if people maintain an elitist, technocratic, meritocratic attitude toward question askers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: *common courtesy is not some sort of limited resource* - Time and the number of characters that are available for comments *are* limited, though. The issue of "women and people of color" was basically dismantled (or never even properly justified, to begin with). When "user3246324" writes a crappy question, it will not be welcome (in fact, I'm pretty sure that a user called "BlueEyedSweetie21" might even have some bonus here, but I won't *claim* that without evidence). I think this whole topic is not technical enough to be discussed here, but we cannot help being exposed to it. That's annoying.

Comment: "The idea that people can be so busy that they can't take the time to communicate kindly is funny, because these same people are voluntarily answering questions on stack overflow, and some are then writing lengthy arguments about how they should be allowed to be rude as they do so, and posting them in Meta." Here's the thing, though: these people pride themselves on how altruistic they are to be putting so much time into making things better for anyone else who wants to provide good answers and moderate the site well. You can critique this, but insulting it is unwise.

Comment: Unwise? I don't care. Also, pride yourself in how altruistic you are? Did I just read that sentence?

Comment: If you actively don't care about making an effective argument, there is no good reason for anyone to listen to the arguments you do make.

Comment: I find this answer condescending and **unwelcoming**

Comment: @NathanTuggy: What you've said here is essentially entitlement. That some people feel that, as "altruistic" curators, they are entitled to be as sassy, snarky, or jerky as they want. It's like saying that being snarky towards poor people at a soup kitchen is OK if you're the one handing them soup; such people shouldn't expect better treatment from volunteers. Such a position *deserves* insults, not reasoned critique.

Comment: Would you say that getting snarky still isn't okay if the people getting free soup started demanding golden spoons?

Comment: I don't think people generally get snarky until it's obvious the asker either doesn't feel like researching the issue themselves ("please write this code for me") or they don't want to take the advice given to them by other users. You say the community should show some common courtesy to new users - how about new users show the community some common courtesy in return?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I deliberately phrased my original description in a way that would make it clear that it was mistaken and even somewhat self-deceptive. But treating this position, or any wrong position that is the result of extremely common human psychology, as deserving nothing but insults is, again, unwise. If you can't explain what's wrong with someone believing they are being unselfish while actually being selfish, you should allow the many writers of the past who *have* managed this (I am thinking of C.S. Lewis' *Screwtape Letters* here) to do the job instead.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Consider it from another angle. Suppose I have spotted some arrogant, entitled, rude user posting loudly on Meta about how badly a certain group of users acts (and by extension, how good they are that they don't do that). Does it help anything if I then skewer that user with insults, recognizing their pride and hypocrisy, and wanting to be sure everyone knows that they are Not Cool, or Unwelcoming, or otherwise disapproved by All Right-Thinking People? No. I have simply taken their same error a step further.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: "*If you can't explain what's wrong with someone believing they are being unselfish while actually being selfish*" If you have to explain basic courtesy to someone, they're probably not going to understand it. I've tried to explain why some comment or other was insulting or inappropriate, but they *just don't get it*. So I don't bother. Also, there's a difference between "deserving of insults" and actually choosing to deliver those insults. The latter is not acceptable, but the former?

Comment: To speak of "brogrammers" and imply that "toxic" modes of discourse are *selectively* filtering out people based on race, gender, English fluency etc. (what on Earth is a "nontraditional learner"?) even when the discourse doesn't actually mention those attributes, is itself **appallingly** bigoted and non-conducive to discussion. "and some are then writing lengthy arguments about how they should be allowed to be rude as they do so, and posting them in Meta." - this is a blatant mischaracterization that demonstrates no intention of actually engaging with the point being made in the question.

Answer (score -46):

These aren't really that bad; they're pretty sassy, like an angsty adolescent talking back to their parents. I must say, it's hard to take you seriously when you leave a comment like

> "...You won’t listen to my advice. If you won’t work find out how the string is allocated you can’t make progress.”

Sorry about your day, pal!

If you absolutely *need* to be snarky to get your point across, consider the following options:

- leave the question for a more level-headed person to answer
- take 10 deep breaths; in through the nose, out through the mouth, then re-write your comment

You **never** need to be snarky to get your point across! Try looking at it from a more realistic (less emotional) angle and re-calibrate yourself.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvotes- They're right, at least about snark and how best to handle it from oneself. We don't _need_ snark, especially on a Q&A site that's supposed to be used by professionals. =/

Comment: I dowvoted because this "take 10 deep breaths; in through the nose, out through the mouth" is not welcoming. It is patronizing.

Comment: @LutzHorn Actually... It's sound advice. Can you explain what feels patronizing about it? Deep breathing is a commonly advised way to calm yourself down, and doing so before posting a comment is never really a bad idea. If spoiledgoods knows what's wrong with it, they can reword it.

Comment: @LutzHorn good, it was intentional. You feel patronized by my comment, like the human on the receiving-end of these unwelcoming comments.

Comment: @Kendra Sound it may be. But the language is not nice. It tells me what to do and how to behave. I don't want to be treated like that.

Comment: @spoiledgoods I like how being welcoming is only important when you're talking to someone asking a low quality question.  Whenever you're talking to anyone else being intentionally rude is just fine.

Comment: "like an angsty adolescent talking back to their parents." I've felt like making this comments both when working in a tech support call center (to both the customers and my fellow techs!) and when dealing with my own children. So I don't think it's specific to angsty teens.

Comment: @Kendra I have a panic disorder and practice deep breathing just to avoid hyperventilating (sometimes), but I admit I put it here as a "calm down buddy" thing.

Comment: I'm willing to bet many people who post these kinds of comments are calm enough, at least on an emotional level. Taking some deep breaths probably isn't going to remove the frustration about not seeing the question move along to the blissful state of being an interesting question with at least one good answer, because, to some extent, it's a *professional* frustration. If just taking a deep breath was enough to make these comments disappear, I think there wouldn't be as much heat surrounding these discussions as there currently is.

Comment: The quoted comment is completely factual and actually good advice. On the other hand, this answer is patronising as ####.

Comment: Sometimes I do need to be snarky for my own emotional balance. I'm warped that way...

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers And telling me how to keep by emotional balance level is patronizing. But that's what SO will tell us and enforce using Machine Learning Magic™.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nope, it's whiny and unnecessary. Where's the advice?

Comment: @spoiledgoods: The advice is: start listening to advice (or why show up at all) and follow the instructions given in order to make progress.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no need to argue! I'm not sure what your point is either. That snark is an effective teaching technique?

Comment: @spoiledgoods: No, my point is that the comment _doesn't have any snark_.

Comment: "You never need to be snarky to get your point across". Wise words. It's just that you yourself could follow them. So maybe give everybody some breathing room and don't have a language police around the corner. I think we're all happy we can *have* this discussion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I respect your opinion! I've seen far worse comments on here, most of these are straddling the fence of unwelcoming.

Comment: This is a great example of new users (who have basically not helped anyone on the site) being held to a lower standard than established users (who have helped hundreds of thousands or millions of people). @spoiledgoods openly said in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370792/is-this-really-what-we-should-consider-unwelcoming?cb=1#comment607706_370803), that their answer was designed to offend and insult other users. They are explicitly trying to be unwelcoming...

Comment: ...I'm doubtful that @spoiledgoods's flagrant disregard for the rules will cause SO (the company) to post a blog about how established users are being abused by newbies and how that needs to stop.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 Well if this isn't elitism I don't know what is. Sorry you don't get special privileges for being a more senior user.

Comment: @spoiledgoods Matter of fact, you do. It's in the software.

Comment: @spoiledgoods, it's not elitism to hold you to the same standard as everyone else. Of course, it's common sense to treat established users better that newbies (heck, that's exactly what the reputation system does) because established users help 10x-1000x more people than you and me.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 Yet, we do try not to let it go to our heads and still hold everyone to the same standards, be they Jon Skeet or user24960626 who joined 5 minutes earlier.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 I'm just curious why you put a personal attack in your comment towards me? The only reason you could possibly be offended by my answer, is the fact that you make snarky comments regularly and do not wish to have this privilege taken away; not to mention your senior S.O. status!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Edit: You deleted your comment again, but this was a response to you saying the original quoted comments are perfectly fine.... Yes of course my answer was patronizing, and yes it did cause the toxicity, as I said twice above. <---- see that end part? It's snarky and unnecessary; VERY similar to the quoted comments. Do you find it snarky now that it's directed at you?

Comment: @spoiledgoods, statements of fact are not personal attacks. I won't respond to your other accusations since they are all malicious speculation without any proof.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 You said I've helped nobody. Where's the fact? Show me the fact.

Comment: @spoiledgoods, I said you "...have basically not helped anyone on the site." Assuming that "people reached" means "people helped" (which was the original wording), you've helped 126 people compared to Ansgar's 11.3 million people. The amount of people you've helped is basically 0% in that comparison. Heck, I've only helped 1-2% of the people he's helped.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 Ok, point? Are you maintaining your point that Ansgar or Steve or Sally or anyone with 11.3 million people can and should be snarky?

Comment: @spoiledgoods, I'm saying that it wasn't a personal attack to say you haven't helped anyone. I'm saying that SO should care more about keeping its elite users happy than placating new users or even established users (because the elites are much more important to the site). And I'm saying that *at the very least* new users like yourself should be held to the same standard as elite users, old users, and established users.

Comment: @spoiledgoods I think it's kind of hypocritical for you to say that seniors want to be held at a different standard, when you yourself post something unwelcoming and snarky purposefully and think it's fine. If you don't want double standards, then maybe act like you expect everybody else to act? :/...

Comment: "good, it was intentional. You feel patronized by my comment, like the human on the receiving-end of these unwelcoming comments. "

So it's fine for you to engage in that because you share the position of the moderators? This policy is unworkable.

Comment: completely blown away by what people get offended by these days...