# A better way to make Stack Overflow more welcoming?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, welcoming

As I've read through recent discussions like [Is this really what we should consider "unwelcoming"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370792/) and [Feedback on the Comment Classifier blog post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370838/), I've started to notice a theme. There are two things that are being said pretty widely:

- New users are far more put off by having their questions downvoted without explanation, and would prefer to know what they're doing wrong ([example 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252235/), [example 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370911/), [example 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370857/), [example 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370819/) in a comment). (BTW, since I can't figure out how to link directly to comments, I'm copying the comment from example 4 here so it can be read):

  > Posting a question on SO as a new user and having it downvoted and closed without comments would feel much worse to me than receiving some comments that aren't overtly nice. I would greatly prefer to be told like it is than to simply be swept aside because the people making that decision decided they had nothing nice to say to me about it.

  Oh, and example five: [What can we do to encourage (or discourage) a second question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311504/) This one is particularly interesting because it includes a large-scale data analysis of newbie behavior, and found (based on the analysis) that the most effective way to encourage a newbie to engage with the site was to leave a comment.
- Experienced users are hesitant to leave comments when they downvote, because they have learned that it often leads to retaliatory downvotes. Most the examples I could find were from comments, and I don't know how to link directly to comments, so here's the text of those examples:

  - > I'm not a fan of silent downvotes myself, b/c if someone thinks there's anything wrong with my answers I'd like to know what that is, so I can either fix it or explain their misunderstanding. However, I also see the other side of this. I tend to comment when downvoting, explaining what I consider wrong with a post, and I have received my share of revenge downvotes for doing so. I can see why people prefer silent downvotes. And I don't think making a downvote reason mandatory would help in the least. IMO that'd only lead to less downvotes, and in turn to decreased content quality.

    Source: deep in the comments on the [Is this really what we should consider "unwelcoming"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370792/) thread.
  - > I personally do not recommend downvoting after trying to be helpful. It just gives them a target... speaking from personal experience.

    Source: the fifth comment on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370819
  - > **Leaving a comment accompanying a downvote can lead to negative consequences, like revenge downvoting and even off-site harassment.** Many experienced users will tell you that they used to leave helpful comments along with their downvotes, but have stopped doing so because of the unpleasant blowback they received from unreasonable users.

    Source: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/ (emphasis in original). This one was not a comment, but I quoted it anyway to excerpt the most relevant part of the answer.
  - > Moderation is almost always viewed negatively - There's nothing like having your question closed to bring out the snark, colorful language and even revenge downvoting.

    Source: [Curation and cynicism: Or why Stack Overflow sometimes doesn't seem welcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367016/) (again, not a comment but I excerpted the most relevant part for this discussion)
  - > I've had it with being beaten up over comments. I'm just not going to post any, at all, on questions from low-rep users. No requests for clarification, no hints, no quick answer 'cos I don't want the rep or can't be bothered dupe-linking. Just no comments at all. They'll still have the guns and will still want to shoot me, but Imma taking all the ammo.

    Source: the ninth comment (or the seventh comment before clicking the "show N more comments" link) on [Curation and cynicism: Or why Stack Overflow sometimes doesn't seem welcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367016/)

I could go on (and on and on), but I think the examples I've posted so far are probably enough to give a feel for the two horns of the dilemma. New users feel that it's unwelcoming when their questions are downvoted without feedback, while experienced users trying to curate the site hesitate to give feedback, because they don't yet know which of two categories *this* new user will fall into:

- The kind who will be grateful for that feedback, and improve, or:
- The kind who will take it (wrongly)* as a personal attack, and engage in revenge downvoting or make snarky, hostile comments in return.

* I'm not, here, talking about the times when the feedback is actually hostile. I'm talking about when the feedback is something like "What is the specific error message you got?" or "You need to post an MCVE or we won't be able to help you".

#### So how do we solve this?

I suspect that the best action the Stack Exchange team could take, the action that would provide the biggest "bang for the buck" in terms of long-term effect, would be to find ways to reduce people's reluctance to explain their downvotes. In particular, I think [Raise flag for obvious revenge downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280040/raise-flag-for-obvious-revenge-downvotes) (posted four years ago on Meta.SO), or [Check for revenge voting directed against question closers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96787/check-for-revenge-voting-directed-against-question-closers) (posted seven(!) years ago on Meta.SE) would be good features to implement. (And note the end of [Raise flag for obvious revenge downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280040/raise-flag-for-obvious-revenge-downvotes): "Yes, I'm aware there is already a reversal script - **it doesn't catch it.**" - Emphasis mine).

I believe that leaving these feature requests unimplemented for so long was a mistake on Stack Exchange's part, as it has led to the vicious cycle described above where people get burned out on leaving feedback, and then new users feel unwelcomed when their questions are **silently** downvoted or closed. But the flipside of this mistake is an opportunity: if Stack Exchange would implement these features, that would go a long way towards undoing the damage. If people felt safe leaving feedback on bad questions, knowing that the automatic tools can catch revenge downvoting and that the moderators can take care of personal-attack comments, I believe we might see an increase in feedback left on new users' questions, and then the kind of users that we *want* to attract to the site would actually stick around and continue to contribute.

But this post is tagged `discussion`, not `feature-request`, for a reason. My goal is not (solely) to mention these feature requests that I believe have been unfortunately neglected. I also want to start a discussion. For that purpose, I have two questions for those with some experience in the "trenches" of downvoting, revenge downvoting, and the like.

#### Questions

1. Do you personally feel that if revenge downvotes were far more difficult, or caught and corrected better by the script, you would be more likely to leave comments explaining why a question is bad?
2. Are there any **other** ways that you can think of to mitigate the problem of downvotes with no feedback?

Comment: 1) no, not really. Revenge votes are just one factor of unwelcome results of exposing that you're a downvoter. I just don't comment anything unless I know the person on the receiving end is in the right frame of mind - a listening one, not a "I need someone to blame" one. Often hard to see, so I err on the side of shut up and move on. 2) I don't call it a problem at all, so no. Downvotes ARE feedback.

Comment: Even if it's not  feature request is *sounds* like a duplicate of "require voters to explain"....and that's been shot down dozens of times. I have no issue with revenge DV...I'm confident the script will pick them up...and I DV and comment *a lot*.

Comment: The issue isn't necessarily the revenge downvotes. I'll use a personal example, but I pointed a user once to "hey, you made a mistake and posted this on meta. meta is used for [blablabla], while the main site is used for programming". I got met with "STACK OVERFLOW IS FOR PROGRAMMING, THIS IS PROGRAMMING. Would you prefer I talk about ice, snow, or hockey? As a Canadian you'd love that I'm sure". **this** kind of behavior is why I don't comment as much as I used to, not at all because of revenge votes.

Comment: I don't care about rep or revenge downvotes. I don't comment because of the unwelcoming responses I am likely to receive from the OP. I have an aversion to being verbally abused, I could care less about a mosquito bite.

Comment: Welcoming™ merely requires that DV and comments are not condescending or rude. That's all...and that's not hard! A DV by itself is not rude. It's a signpost that indicates to the OP that "something is wrong" and they should fix it.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I specifically do NOT want to *require* anyone to explain. I want to *encourage* that behavior by removing its negatives, but in no way do I want to FORCE anyone to explain. Plenty of people are busy and don't have time for that.

Comment: @Paulie_D - As for your second comment (that being welcoming merely requires that downvotes and comments not be condescending or rude): have you looked at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311504/ in any depth? Jon Ericson concluded from his data that "the effect of getting a comment drowns out any effect of how the comment was worded", i.e. even a rude comment felt more welcoming (as evidenced by the users' further engagement with the site) than silence. I submit that the evidence is against your theory. If you have counter evidence, I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: So by that argument, *not* leaving a comment is *more* welcoming? Wait...I'm confused.

Comment: No, it's the opposite. Getting a comment had a net positive effect, no matter whether the comment was negative or positive. And although you'd expect that getting a negative comment would be off-putting, it didn't measurably discourage users in Jon Ericson's data. But getting NO comments did discourage people. So *not* leaving a comment is *less* welcoming, in this argument, than leaving a negative comment.

Comment: But again, what of the user leaving the comment, and the backlash he exposes himself to? I don't mind leaving comments and make sure they are welcoming and nice. But if I am met daily with insults, push backs, ad hominem..... that I care :(.  Of course it's not all new users. But from experience, it's a decent proportion :/

Comment: So, if I just go around sprinkling "Hello! I like turtles!" comments on questions from new users, they'll all magically feel welcome?

Comment: That one doesn't have a good automated solution; you can flag the insults and ad hominems, and it's a good idea to do so, but yeah, that would get discouraging rather fast. The one thing that *does* have a good solution has unfortunately languished for multiple years without any attention, and I wish the Stack Exchange people would actually do something about the kind of revenge downvoting that the serial-voting script misses.

Comment: *"I wish the Stack Exchange people would actually do something about the kind of revenge downvoting that the serial-voting script misses."* Is this **really** such a huge issue...I'm doubtful and even if it was, there are mechanisms in place to address it.

Comment: @TinyGiant - Heh. I haven't looked at Jon Ericson's data in depth, only looked at his conclusions. But somehow I doubt that the comments he found encouraged people were completely *off-topic* comments. I suspect, as I imagine you do too, that off-topic comments wouldn't help. What **does** help, as the many, MANY newbie comments I researched bear out, is having your question be *meaningfully engaged* by other users on SO.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I didn't think there was a big issue, since I've almost never personally encountered it. But then I found comment after comment after *comment* from long-time SO users who were burned out on the negativity they experienced (I selected SIX of them up above), and all of them mentioned one of two things: revenge downvoting, or insulting comments, as the reason why they no longer gave feedback. So after looking at the evidence, I decided that maybe there IS a big issue after all. (And those two feature requests, and their many upvotes, suggest that the mechanisms aren't addressing it.)

Comment: So, it seems to me, that this has nothing to to with Welcoming™ at all (at the core), really, just a bump to implementing a better script to pick up revenge voting.

Comment: It has everything to do with welcoming, as evidenced by the MANY comments by newbies about how lack of feedback makes them feel unwelcome (and the statistical data by Jon Ericson to the same effect). The script for revenge voting is my best guess at something that will be the biggest help. Now, I'll grant that it has little to do with Welcoming™ as defined by that infamous blog post, because the data shows that the kind of Welcoming™ that blog post wants us to do **won't actually be welcoming**, and in reality will make things worse in the long run.

Comment: I am not worried about revenge downvotes (I am not sure new users can downvote at all). I don't like the sometimes [hostile reactions to comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366692/how-do-you-know-stack-overflow-feels-unwelcoming/366733#366733) of new users, but they are easily removed by flagging as rude. The only reason why I became reluctant to explain downvotes is because of the "welcoming" blog posts.

Comment: FYI, it is a common pattern on the internet that the date/time on a post is also a link to that post. For example, the post time on a tweet is a link to that tweet itself. And the post time on comments here are links to that comment.

Comment: @Will - Thanks! I'd seen that on GitHub but for some reason hadn't thought to try it here. I don't have much time right now, but in a few hours I may have time to fix up my post with proper links to the comments I quoted.

Comment: There is a severe problem with your analysis here, as well as the downvote discussion in general. Question downvotes are different than answer downvotes. A question downvote is rarely because of technical inaccuracy, and as a result the explanation of that downvote rarely includes technical details; it is probable users are less interested in material which is not related to technical issues. An answer downvote is almost always because of technical inaccuracy, and as a result the explanation is generally desired because it would include technical detail that users want to know when inaccurate.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> New users are far more put off by having their questions downvoted without explanation, and would prefer to know what they're doing wrong

This is simply a fallacy.  First off, people *love* to complain about not getting feedback on how to improve their questions *when they have already gotten lots of feedback on how to improve their question*.  Probably close to half of the meta posts I see for, "my question was downvoted, but I didn't get any feedback on how to make it better" have at least one comment explaining what's problematic about it, often multiple.  So many people seem to think that someone commenting with things like, "The code you've provided doesn't reproduce the problem you've described," is not actually feedback on the quality of their question, and not a problem that they need to fix.

Next, as much as people complain about not getting feedback on why their posts were downvoted/closed/etc., they get *way, way* more upset when people actually *do* tell them what's wrong with their post and how to fix it.  People get a little mad when they get a downvote with no comment.  They absolutely *fume* when someone tells them that their question isn't clear or that the answer to their question is covered in the documentation of the method they're asking about.  And not only does actually getting the feedback on what they did wrong tend to make people more upset, but *they have someone to direct that anger towards* and often do so.

And that brings us nicely to "revenge downvoting".  Honestly, this is an issue that is grossly overstated.  It's worth noting at this point that I'm a user that:

1. Downvotes a lot of posts.  Like, a lot.  Not the most of any user, but pretty high up there most months.
2. Frequently comments on how posts are problematic and how they can be improved.  Less and less over time, but still quite a lot.  Often these are posts that I've downvoted, often they aren't (only 40 downvotes a day after all)
3. Votes to close a good deal of questions.

And yet I'm very often surprised at how *infrequently* I get downvotes that I suspect are not based on the voter's opinion of the post itself.  As in, I would personally expect at least an order of magnitude more than I actually get.  And what's more, my personal opinions (worth noting that they don't have much evidence here) are that much of the revenge downvotes I get are based on my meta participation, rather than downvotes/comments/close votes on main (based purely on how downvotes I get are more often on the same day as heated meta discussions, rather than heated comment chains on main).

So based on my actions, I'm probably one of the users most inclined to attract revenge downvotes, and I just don't care in the slightest, both because of how infrequently they happen (I'd guess somewhere in the neighborhood of ~3 times a *year*), and also how low impact they are when they happen (especially if the end up being reversed).

So the whole proposal about trying to reverse revenge downvotes is just not really a useful place to spend time.  It happens fairly rarely, and tends to not be a major dissuading factor in experienced users giving feedback.  Doing so would also be *very, very* hard.  There just aren't good ways to manually, let alone automatically, determine if a downvote is based on the authors view of the post quality or based on their opinion of the user who posted it.  The evidence needed to it to be convincing enough for SO to roll it back means it's easy to not provide enough evidence as a user, and having SO reverse a lot of valuable votes that were honestly cast based on the voters opinion of the post quality is really bad, we don't want to see that happening often, as it would likely have to in order to accomplish your proposal.

So now that we've covered what *isn't* the reason why people don't comment, we have to cover what *is* the reason.  The most significant reasons why experienced users are very hesitant to post feedback in comments is:

1. It so infrequently works.

   So many users just aren't interested in improving, even when told what to improve, or are simply *incapable* of fixing the post (either because the post is that bad, or their skills are so lacking).

   This makes many users at a minimum start looking closely for signs as to whether or not a post is likely to actually get improved, and not post unless they see strong signs that the user is likely able and willing to fix their post.  It makes others just stop trying entirely because of how often it results in wasted effort.
2. People hate you for it.

   It doesn't matter how polite you are, how useful your advice, people will be super pissed at you for simply telling them what the problems are with their post and how to fix it, rather than giving them code that they can copy paste without reading to fix their problem.  They will insult you, be mad, complain, and just all around make the interaction an unpleasant experience for everyone involved.  It's just *exhausting*, so people who try to help others improve their posts tend to get exhausted and burn out.

   And not only will the post author hate you for trying to help them improve their post, but SO will hate you for making a user mad.  You will be insulted by moderators for upsetting people and making them feel unwelcome, instead of just downvoting and moving on, or just leaving the site entirely because you care about having quality questions with quality answers instead of low quality questions and answers that can't actually answer the question.

Neither of these problems are solved by trying to make the vote reversal script more aggressive.

Comment: This...end of discussion!

Comment: "This is simply a fallacy". Then do you have an alternative explanation for the strong correlation that Jon Ericson found? I'm not basing this solely on anecdotal evidence, but on some pretty good (AFAICT) statistical analysis. Data that solid cannot be simply dismissed as a fallacy; if it were a fallacy, the correlation should not have shown up.

Comment: @rmunn That doesn't control for any number of different factors.  It's just comparing posts with comments to posts without comments.  You need to recognize that many of the comments won't be explaining why a post is bad, many of the posts without comments were because the question was quickly deleted, and none of this is indicating causation.  Jon's post isn't indicating that the act of commenting means a user can come back, it can just as easily indicate that people comment more on the types of posts made by users posting good content, who tend to come back.

Comment: @rmunn Also, that post is merely measuring how likely someone is to come back, not anything else.  Someone may be more likely to come back even if they were more upset by an interaction.  After all, I'm more likely to not bother posting on a Q/A forum that is just *empty* than in one where people said my question was bad.  The former has no chance of being useful, the latter just a lower chance, etc.

Comment: @Servy - Fair enough; those are good alternative explanations for the data. It's just that I've seen so many people making the same claim (that silence feels unwelcoming), PLUS data that seems to back it up, that I tend to believe it in the face of strong evidence to the contrary. Your experience (over a great length of time) that "it so infrequently works", on the other hand, is pretty good evidence against the theory. I'll wait until later to accept answers in case some more good ones come in, but so far yours has been the most useful to me.

Comment: The silence is not unwelcoming to me.  It's actually great!  No abuse, no blog & totter, no nothing:)

Comment: @rmunn I'm not saying that people don't feel unwelcome when they get downvoted or closed questions with no feedback.  I believe full well that it makes them feel bad.  I'm just saying that when they actually get feedback it's *even worse*.  The fallacy is not "people feel bad when they get no feedback", because that's most certainly true.  The fallacy is "people will feel better if we just give them feedback on what they did wrong".  It just makes them feel worse, and act worse towards others.

Comment: I agree with your point 1 here, that resonates with me. I don't feel inclined to comment because of point 1; users just are not attentive to making changes to the questions, or worse there is also the case where literally no edit will fix the question. While partaking in the mentoring program, we had users that wanted to improve their questions end up in a chat room. Even those users, who were inclined to improve their questions, we simply often unable to make progress because they just didn't grasp the immediacy with which the site moves.

Comment: Could it be that the "close to half of the meta posts" you see for "my question was downvoted" have at least one comment explaining what's problematic about it _because_ it was posted on meta so therefore someone went from meta and left a comment?

Comment: @Qwertie No. It's easy to tell from timestamps that it was posted earlier.  Being an active meta user I'm often one of the first people to see such questions, and the first thing I'll do is check the question, so it's often easy to tell the original comments apart from any comments from users who saw the meta question.  When people have feedback to give from seeing a meta question about it they also *tend* to give that feedback on the meta question, rather than the post itself.  It's not unheard of for people to post on the question itself, but it's rare.

Answer (score 15):

For me personally:

### Do I care about revenge downvoting?

Not really.

I may have been serially downvoted here and there (not that I can tell you why), but overall it doesn't affect which comments I leave.

### Do I comment to explain downvotes?

Not really.

But "What is the specific error message you get?" is asking for more information, not explaining a downvote.

But this is a nitpick, not a useful section.

### Do I ask for more information?

Sometimes.

### What stops me?

The overwhelming reason I wouldn't ask for more information is probably **most users don't respond**. They just don't. Sometimes they respond to *everyone not asking for improvements*, but mostly they just don't respond at all. Given this, I often just stick to voting to close.

Or they **argue**. Don't respond or argue - very, very few actually seem to listen.

Next is **their question can't be fixed** - there's something fundamentally wrong with their question. I can ask for more information to help them *improve* their question, but I still don't see it ending up in a state where I'd want to do anything other than close it.

Last, but maybe not least, is **redundancy** - why should I repeat what the close message should already tell them? Now here is where I actually have a problem, since users often don't actually *see* the message until way too late (or possibly never). We really should be showing them the close reasons before their question is closed (with at least the visibility of a comment). Although doing this "properly" probably wouldn't be that easy.

Comment: The problem with your last paragraph is that it would still require consensus, otherwise one person incorrectly voting to close the question would cause an irrelevant message to be shown to the user, further confusing matters. The logical progression would be to have a minimum of, let's say, 3 close votes to show the message. The next logical progression would be to just lower the required number of votes to close a question to 3.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, doing it properly wouldn't be easy. I'd prefer showing the reason even if there's *one* vote, but **somehow** make it clear that it was posted by a regular user - even with comments I already too often see people listening to some random ignorant users telling them to do wrong things.

Comment: Maybe following the dupe-vote pattern where when the first close vote is cast for a given reason, the close message is posted as a comment by the user under the question. Subsequent close votes for that reason would upvote the comment, and the comment would be removed when the question is closed if closed for that reason. Just some brainstorming.

Comment: @TinyGiant I always thought a rather fundamental problem with duplicate comments getting removed is that the question can get reopened, at which point it's mostly lost (it's still a linked post, but that's given very little visibility). It's probably *less* of a problem with other close comments, but I'd still say it's a problem.

Comment: Well... there is that.

Comment: Yup. All of this.

Comment: 'the close message is posted as a comment by the user under the question'.. I could agree with that if 'by the user' was struck out and replaced with "by an anonymised, generic user name, eg. 'closer1247".

Comment: @MartinJames But that isn't what happens when you vote to close as a duplicate, and there's nothing stopping you from deleting the comment immediately after it is posted, other than network latency of course... and the point is to show the user that this _is_ just one person saying this thing to them, until there is consensus. My point is that showing the close message under the question is Official, and without consensus that is quite a lot of trust to put in a single user with nothing more than 3k rep as a qualification.

Comment: @TinyGiant ... and when you vote to close with a custom close reason.

Answer (score 7):

> Do you personally feel that if revenge downvotes were far more difficult, or caught and corrected better by the script, you would be more likely to leave comments explaining why a question is bad?
>
> Are there any other ways that you can think of to mitigate the problem of downvotes with no feedback?

Downvotes are not for the question asker; they're for people who might want to read the question. Voting indicates a question's quality; that is its primary purpose. Whether a downvote gets explained or not is therefore irrelevant to their primary purpose: indicating the quality of a post.

If downvotes are seen as harmful to new users, then don't show them to that person. But the ability to vote without comment is a vital tool for maintaining quality on SO.

Screw with that at your peril.

Comment: You are now the second person who has, apparently, thought that I'm asking for the old "require comments with downvotes" feature. I'm not. I want to remove any *obstacles* that might be in people's path to leaving useful feedback, but I'm not, repeat NOT, asking for comments to be *required* when downvoting. I recognize that that's a useful feature. My focus is on the people who used to leave comments, and would like to continue to do so, but have grown discouraged from doing it.

Comment: @rmunn the problem is the imprecise wording. No one should be commenting _about their downvotes_. **Do** vote on cotent. **Do** comment on content. **Don't** comment on votes. It would be best to remove the focus on downvotes from your question as it is irrelevant to your point. I mean, the real point is to encourage users to leave comments advising on how to improve the post regardless of whether that user downvoted, upvoted, close voted, or abstained from voting altogether, right?

Answer (score 2):

*Check for revenge voting directed against question closers*- There doesn't need to be a special thing for close voters; the script just detects whether there's been a string a votes on a user's questions. It doesn't check whether the targeted user has interacted with the user who's voting.

*Raise flag for obvious revenge downvotes* - I want to know how a moderator is supposed to tell whether a vote was legitimate or revenge:

- By time? By number of posts? Then why wouldn't we automate it?
- Existing post score? Are we saying a user has to agree with the community when voting?
- By the moderator's opinion of the post? Again, are we saying you're only allowed to down vote if someone else agrees the post isn't useful?

I'd also want to see how much voting would end up flagged based on the criteria.

I don't think you're going to get a lot of people who care about revenge down voting among regular meta users because they tend to have rep above 3K and likely get enough up votes that they don't have to worry about loss of privileges or bans.

Personally, the only time I've felt fairly sure I got a revenge down vote was after I rejected an edit so this isn't something I (think) I've been affected by either. (This was ages ago and not the reason I haven't been active in review queues.)

Comment: Not a moderator: a script. The script can safely be given access to data that the moderator should not have access to: *who downvoted*. If user A downvoted user B's and left a comment about why, and user B then within a short span of time downvoted an unrelated question of user A's, I would like a script to flag that as a likely revenge vote (and reverse it immediately). Two or more such revenge votes within a month, and user B gets an automatic reprimand of some kind informing them that revenge voting is not tolerated.

Comment: Oh, the linked question was talking about raising a flag for moderator attention so I thought that's what you were suggesting happen here.

Answer (score -5):

Downvotes in and by themselves cause an unwelcoming impression for people posting. They are the first thing you see when returning and scanning the page (top to bottom, left to right), and they don't encourage polite constructive explaining. It can be perceived as the digital equivalent of a little punch, and hurts long-term prospects of a welcoming atmosphere.

There are alternative systems. (We once removed downvoting in a social universe we created, as it caused too much fighting, and replaced it with only upvotes, and many other mechanisms, including flag reporting.) But I'm not saying it would be easy to overhaul StackOverflow (or Reddit et al) to move towards such, just that it's possible, and I would guess the pragmatic chances of the powers that be to see this point, let alone attempt the change, are near zero.

I fully expect this answer to be downvoted :)

Comment: Downvotes on Meta don't cost you any reputation points, so there's no downside to them. For example, this question currently has 19 downvotes, but that just means that most people think my suggestion isn't needed; it's nothing personal. And whenever I've used discussion tools *without* downvotes, such as Disqus, I've missed them, because it provides a useful feedback tool to say "most people here disagree with this comment". (Note: Disqus pretends to have downvotes: it gives you a downvote button, but that button *doesn't reduce that comment's score*. It's a fake downvote button.)