# What exactly about the comments in "Is this really what we should consider “unwelcoming”?" is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, comments, scope, moderation

[Is this really what we should consider "unwelcoming"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370792/is-this-really-what-we-should-consider-unwelcoming) has been locked

> due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated

Could the mods please explain what exactly about the comments on this quesion is off-topic?

Comment: There's probably a threshold of pain; if the number of flags a mod is receiving about a specific post exceeds that, locking it to clean things up and get both sides to chill out is in everyone's best interests.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I temporarily locked the post - for 9 minutes. To be fair it showed a notice to be locked for one hour.

This is taken from the post timeline history:

> 20 mins ago   history locked  Yvette Colomb♦
>    11 mins
>   ago   history unlocked    Yvette Colomb♦

At that point we were getting an increasing number of flags on the chat thread and it looked like it was going to explode into a brawl. From the flags we received, it's clear not everyone saw all the comments that have been deleted. It was literally a stop gap measure for the mods to discuss it and decide what course to take.

I applied the lock and then went to the mod chat room to ask what to do. There's a couple of mod/CMs able to monitor the thread, so the advice was to unlock the post. Then to move the comments to chat and place a comment, as I did.

On another point, I'm still learning about moderating meta and seeking guidance on what is the best course of action to take, so appreciate the community's patience when it comes to moving comments to chat, as too many comments raise auto flags.

Comment: My advice would be: don't respond/take action to the auto flags on Meta posts, at least not by moving the thread to chat. Once real humans start to raise flags it is early enough to consider an appropriate action. But I can't see what you see so it is a bit of a guess if this can work for the mod team.

Comment: @rene I'm currently taking the advice of a well seasoned mod and Shog - well Shog mainly on the comment threads. I agree, ignoring the auto comment flag sounds good (within reason). 50 comments under a question is a bit much wouldn't you say?

Comment: No, that is not too much. It depends, as always.

Comment: I must say, I've never seen a post lock due to comments, before. Usually, the comments just get nuked / moved to chat, followed by a small message from a moderator. Users that ignore the message face the consequences...

Comment: Unconstructive comments take care of themselves.  They'll quickly disappear from view in an active discussion, crowded out by upvoted comments.  Moving the posts to chat only makes sense if those comments get a lot of votes.  Never do that, that's censorship.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have many times on meta and the main site. It's a standard lock reason.

Comment: @HansPassant  No need to throw down the "censorship" card. This website is not a government bound to free and open speech.  Everything about SO is already actively monitored and *censored* --questions, comments, and answers are continuously deleted for various reasons.  Not everyone agrees with those reasons each time, but it is still perfectly within reason and the purpose of SO.  Censorship would be a concern only if it ever got personal or was for reasons outside the standard of conduct (i.e. be nice).  This was apparently done in good faith to avoid off-topic and flaming comments.

Comment: In my not-so-humble Meta experience, 50 comments under a question is not a surprising amount when the topic is a hot button one like the above topic. In those cases you can expect hundreds of comments. Though that is not to say that I necessarily disagree with moving the comments to chat. @HansPassant Calling the move-to-chat option censorship is absurd; it links directly to the more chat-friendly medium that the comments were moved to. It doesn't prevent commenting or punish people for commenting or continuing on.

Comment: @CPerkins yeh I get tired of the censorship accusation. I don't delete comments on meta unless they're flagged and the flag is valid.

Comment: @TylerH totally agree - how can moving them to chat be censorship

Comment: Presumably, he takes issue with content being moved to a second class medium, like chat, instead of residing within its original context where it's still relevant. Moving it to chat might be interpreted as, _"I moved something that doesn't belong here. You can safely skip this aspect of the discussion or navigate to a separate area to see it."_ Some might call that censorship, in the sense that you're picking and choosing what gets to remain within the first class discussion. Extended discussion doesn't belong on the main site but maybe it should on meta.

Comment: StackOverflow cannot post controversial stuff like they've been doing lately and expect to not get a ton of angry posts and comments. They seem to forget that StackOverflow is a community of **volunteers** who are not obligated to help anyone. If they want to keep letting their politics interfere with their running of the site, I think they'll quickly see that, unlike in the workplace, no one has to deal with their rubbish.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam [agree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370993/with-a-userbase-as-diverse-as-stack-overflows-how-will-we-arrive-at-an-actiona/371015#371015)

Comment: @canon yes, I'm very conservative with comments on meta now, as a result. My intentions are to help the community function well, not make it harder.

Comment: Its depressing that so many people see "let's cut back on the snarky tone frequently found in comments" as "controversial rubbish politics".

Comment: @Beofett I think it's more complex than that. People are feeling unsupported. That's what I've realised.

Comment: @Beofett It is absolutely politics, especially their conflating of criticism of newcomers with minorities. They're losing in the world of real politics, so they feel the need to enforce their politics in the only place they have control over.

Comment: It certainly is more complex than that, but a portion of those people (and a significant one, at that) feel unsupported because they believe any attempt to get people to be more polite is pushing some sort of partisan political agenda.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam I have seen no conflation of criticism of newcomers with minorities.  They have identified these as separate, but related, issues. Newcomers, who typically have difficulty understanding the nuances of our community, are made to be felt unwelcome when they violate our expectations. Members of minorities have also expressed being made to feel unwelcome, but for completely different reasons.

Comment: This nonsense of "**they're** losing... feel the need to enforce their politics in the only place they have control over" is exactly what I'm talking about.  People are so tied to seeing things through their own partisan perspectives that they attack anything they perceive as possibly being "the other side".

Comment: @Beofett yeh I don't see the "they're losing" thing either. I think they want to improve the site, the public profile, but there's a lot of focus on the "new users" and we need to put into place support for the long time users. Did you read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370993/with-a-userbase-as-diverse-as-stack-overflows-how-will-we-arrive-at-an-actiona/371015#371015?

Comment: Yep, I agree.  The issue largely revolves around low quality content from new users.  However, they're trying to address that across multiple channels, which I think makes a lot of sense.  My issue is that too many people are taking the discussion of reducing snark (which, imho, is a better way of phrasing what they've been referring to as "being more welcoming") in a vacuum.  The debate this creates takes focus away from the other avenues, like question wizards, that I think will be more productive overall.

Comment: @Beofett I used to think that. But (as mod and user) I've noticed a massive change in some users. So despite the complaints, people are stepping up. There will always be people who cannot be taught and there's nothing we can do about that. So I say, let people have their grumble, as the site is improving and if it takes allowing people to vent on meta, let them, that's ok. I agree coming at it from a multiple perspective is vital. I think it's time to "nurture" our long timers lol such a touchy feely word

Comment: My perspective is largely from the "other" SE sites; my participation on SO has been limited (largely due to learning how to effectively search before asking!).  I see the "grumbling" having a pretty toxic effect on a number of other SE sites, to the point where I've drastically cut back my participation across all SE sites.  That's part of the problem: we all tend to have perspectives focused on only parts of the bigger system.

Comment: @Beofett I see, valid point.