# Why was this post locked?

Tags: discussion

The reason that is displayed is:

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated

Yet, every comment I've seen is on-topic, there was only one abusive comment which I'm assuming was the reason for the locking of this post but it was deleted?

Shouldn't the single user be punished rather than everyone discussing?

Why would the post then be locked?

[Is this really what we should consider "unwelcoming"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370792/is-this-really-what-we-should-consider-unwelcoming#370796)

Comment: @Patrice will close as such, never noticed it (seconds difference, I believe).

Comment: "there only one abusive comment" I've seen more than one comment go away in that thread.  I don't know how much is mods and how much is self-deletion, but the moderators are clearly following the post rather closely, so there are probably more deleted comments than you realize that were deleted before you saw them.

Comment: Erm, no one is being punished. Don't forget mods have night vision and can see all teh terrible thingz  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370811/3956566

Comment: @YvetteColomb my apologies, it was taken as that, from what I've experienced a comment is left then cleanups take place.