# Automatic ban for very aggressive users

Tags: feature-request, account-suspension, abuse

Sometimes very aggressive users keep posting offending comments for quite a long time before they are suspended or banned.

IMO if the system receives a series of abuse flags - it should automatically suspend the user and then the moderator should review it. It will simply stop the ongoing abuse.

Example from today. Only my flags. From the comment, I know that another user was flagging them as well.

[image]

Comment: The problem is: you know how the system auto-deletes "thank you" comments that are flagged? Well, if you use a "rude or abusive" flag on those, the flag would be marked as "helpful" just the same.

Comment: @AnnZen I do not think that is a big problem to see if  the comment contains some set of words (f-words, w-words, c-words etc) and new that is something different than "thank you".

Comment: Chat has a feature to suspend users automatically when they get their chat messages flagged. Maybe that same logic can be brought over to the main site.

Comment: half-hour or hour commenting block to cool down would be interesting to try. Would better be once-per-user feature, because repeat abuse likely needs to be left for moderator to deal with

Comment: I was under the impression that all comment flags go into a single bin - and that moderators can't distinguish between a comment flagged as no longer neeeded, and a comment flagged as unfriendly or unkind.

Comment: @WaiHaLee It's a bit of a mash-up. For some things (e.g. auto-deletion), all of the comment flags are treated similarly. For other things, they are treated differently. Moderators do see lists of posts with comment flags which are separated by the type of comment flag, but when a post is displayed within any of those lists all existing comment flags on that post's comments are displayed, regardless of if it's the type of flag which matches the comment flag type list which the moderator selected. If there are multiple flag types on a single comment, handling them *can't* be separated by type.

Comment: "IMO if the system receives a series of abuse flags - it should automatically suspend the user"  - hold it. We need to be extremely precise here, because as worded this is automated cancel culture. No no, if the system receives a series of abuse flags *which are validated*. Otherwise flagging becomes a powerful tool to get someone suspended, just wrongfully flag a bunch of their things and the software does the rest. That long list of "helpful" in the screenshot is the key.

Answer (score 16):

This is a problem. We do get some unreasonable users going berserk every once in a while, and to this day, the  only way to put a plug on such a rampage is for a moderator to apply a suspension. [This isn't the first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396581), and it won't be the last. At best, a mechanism to throttle the posting of comments once enough of that user's comments are deleted in a short time span would at least prevent further harm on the spot without being too invasive. After all, comments are second class citizens.

---

Hey, here's something that could work even better! **Bring more moderators!**

Ensuring that at least one moderator is online at any time of the day may seem utopic, but at least they don't depend on dubious algorithms, and they'd get to these problems in much less than an hour.

---

But hey, here's something that could work *even better*! **Set people's expectations right!**

The way that the company is advertising Stack Overflow continues to attract folks with some sense of entitlement over their own questions and answers. Sometimes even, anything less than giving them what they want is perceived as an insult. Should the platform be much more upfront that they aren't here just to get free help and that their posts will be subjected to scrutiny for long term value, we could prevent cases of persistent offensiveness from ever happening.

Comment: You're painting new users in a very negative light here, the site's etiquette is something that's learned by participating hands-on (a few *unfriendly or unkind* flags are sometimes part of the process)... The example in the question with *harassment, bigotry, abuse* is something more serious that a welcoming guide is unlikely to solve (we also don't know if it's a reaction of the user having taken abuse that went unnoticed in a previous thread and reacting badly in the next thread thinking that's how things go around here).

Comment: @bad_coder That the site is attracting entitled folks does not mean that it attracts only of such a kind, that would be too large a brush to paint this. Still, nowhere did I mention new users, and this issue is unfortunately not only constrained to new users. Even after some time on the platform, some of them may eventually feel the hand of curation a long time after, for many possible reasons. Regarding that last hypothesis, the existence of previous events of abuse would call for more moderation, so that those can be acted upon quickly.

Answer (score -1):

> Sometimes very aggressive users keep posting offending comments for quite a long time before they are suspended or banned.

Well, it's just words. Report them and move on.

Sure, it would be nice if we had a system that could be 100% perfect, but we don't.

So I would rather have a few swear words standing until a moderator sees them, compared to people being locked out of their accounts without a reason other than they got voted off by people flagging their comments. There is a reason we have rules and moderators and not just "mob rule". Mob rule isn't cool. And a few f-bombs is something I'm willing to take to keep us from being ruled by a group of happy trigger fingers instead of rules and elected and *accountable* moderators.

Comment: I think checking if the reported message contains f.. or similar words is not a bit issue. I do not think that someone using them can be *`locked out of their accounts without a reason`* . Using them is the **reason** to have a long break here.

Comment: @0___________ Well, what words would you like to nominate to be universally worth of blocking users over? Introduction to the topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375352/to-what-extent-does-language-need-to-be-moderated/375391