# Do we have data which demonstrates a change in high-rep users' commenting patterns as of late?

Tags: discussion

The blog post [Welcome Wagon: Classifying Comments on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/07/10/welcome-wagon-classifying-comments-on-stack-overflow/) has brought out both sides of the "too welcoming"/"not welcoming enough" debate. I've noticed every time this is brought up, there's some group of existing users who decide (or as least posture) that they'll simply walk away from difficult users to avoid being unwelcoming.

The most recent example I've seen is from [Is this really what we should consider "unwelcoming"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370792/is-this-really-what-we-should-consider-unwelcoming?cb=1):

> Please tell me what we're supposed to be doing instead then. Walk away and don't provide any help at all rather than call a spade a spade?

This was from a >100k user; not a user I'd want to opt out of comments. Personally, I would find this far more harmful to the site than being unwelcoming. However, this all depends of whether or not there is data which suggests high-rep users have been commenting less frequently on new posts in the recent few months as Stack Exchange has fleshing out a better idea on how welcoming to be.

If there's been no observable change, my point is moot.

If there has, however, then it may be worth a discussion on where a balance lies between being welcoming while still encouraging our most helpful users to contribute. I'll table that discussion for now.

As it stands, I was wondering if we have been able to observe detrimental changes in the commenting behavior of high rep users (or any helpful user, I'm just not sure a better metric to use. Users who comment most often, maybe?)

**NOTE:** *Please* don't rehash this debate in the comments. I'm only after objective data here.

Comment: "I've noticed every time this is brought up, there's some group of existing users who decide (or as least posture) that they'll simply walk away from difficult users to avoid being unwelcoming."  That's SO's whole goal here.  They're trying to get people to comment less with the problems a post has and how they can be improved because new users don't like being told what they've done wrong.  The experienced users are complaining because they want to be able to provide that useful feedback that SO is trying to prevent them from posting.

Comment: @Servy Yep. I was wondering if we had some way of measuring the actual change in behavior for these users. In other words, now that both sides of this debate have been better fleshed out, have we seen an observable, empirical response?

Comment: @Servy - In answers, I think pointing out error is required. In questions though, is it useful? From my experience it isn't. Pointing out all the wrong ways that someone asked a question most people probably understood but pedantically will not acknowledge leads that user to simply leave. If they leave, it helped no one, left an artifact on the site, and drove away someone who, while they may have had an issue asking their question, still potentially was a very experienced professional. Again, answers different story; questions, not useful.

Comment: Comments are pretty hard to measure.  But there has been an observable change, the number of downvotes instantly fell by 24%.  Arguably the most institutionalized kind of unwelcoming.  I expected it to recover, it slowly increased again.  But it didn't, stuck at around 16% down today.  Whether it is because users opt to no longer downvote or because a lot of users with vote privileges quit is not obvious to me.  The previous time this happened (2012) a lot of users did quit.  SO never recovered from that.

Comment: @TravisJ It's a pretty fundamental principle of the site that quality questions are important.  Questions that are unclear, are missing information, or that have other problems *are problematic*.  It results in answers that are just guesses (which will sometimes be wrong), questions that can't be answered at all, makes it harder for others coming across the question later to see if it is applicable to their problem (or even to find it).  There are lots of sites that don't have much in the way of question standards and where most questions are allowed. SO is one of the few that isn't like that.

Comment: @Servy - Comments about missing information and clarifications are perfectly acceptable. It is when users start defining "other problems" as whatever their pet peeve might be and then enforcing those requirements on questions that issues arise. I agree with you, question quality is very important. Standards for closure are important and should remain. However, kibitzing on tangential material in questions instead of addressing the core situation is the main problem being addressed here. Is SO being successful with their approach to solve that? Perhaps, but that is the main issue.

Comment: @TravisJ Wait, so your problem is with people posting comments with information that's likely to cause problems for a question author but that isn't what they explicitly asked about?  First off, that's not what SO appears to be primarily targeting (at least to my understanding), but second, why in the world do you not want people posting such information?  Providing information that's tangential, but still useful, is entirely appropriate.  In some cases, far more important than the actual answer (and, naturally, sometimes much less important).

Comment: @Servy - No, that isn't it. I think everyone likes useful information which is related to their question. That was not my point.

Comment: @TravisJ Then what is your point?

Comment: @Servy - As stated. Perhaps the phrase kibitzing leaves too much room for interpretation. Essentially, in the context of unwelcome advice (the definition of kibitzing), this was intended to mean when someone will negatively insinuate that there is something personally wrong with the asker, or their ability in general, based on the content of their question. That this type of implication is sometimes paired with useful content makes it a grey area that is difficult to address.

Comment: @TravisJ "there is something personally wrong with the asker" I've yet seen anyone that complains about the asker. The only cases someone complains that I've seen on main is about what the asker or the answerer is doing./

Comment: @TravisJ The examples of things that SO is saying they're trying to get rid of aren't people commenting on the author of the question, merely pointing out problems with the question that need to be fixed.  That people so often consider advice on how their question can be improved to be unwelcome is, of course, highly problematic.  Yes, lots of people take criticism of their post personally, and treat comments stating problems with a question as an attack on them.  The solution isn't to stop people from posting comments explaining problems with a post.

Comment: @Servy - I don't think that is always the case though. There are many comments -- certainly fewer now so in my opinion there is progress -- where the statements are aimed at the asker instead of the content. For example, "you didn't even attempt to show us what was supposed to happen" is essentially not content based, although you can certainly understand the meaning. On the other hand, "this question cannot be answered without an expected outcome" is content based. The goal here isn't to stop people from explaining how a post can be improved, it is raising the bar of expectation on comments.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't consider it inappropriate at all to ask the author, specifically, to fix a problem with the question.  It makes it clear that it's their responsibility to take a specific action to fix the problem, and that they can't just wait for someone else to fix it for them.  It's still not a commentary on them as a person, merely the actions that they have (or have not) taken, and what they should (or shouldn't) do in the future.  Acknowledging that a person is involved in authoring the question isn't inherently problematic.

Comment: "if we have been able to observe detrimental changes in the commenting behavior or high rep users" I'm afraid I can only attest to positive (*I hope*) changes in my own commenting patterns, for what that's worth.

Comment: @Servy - From the current data set (albeit I too wish they had a larger sample size), 92% of time you are correct. 7% of the time, as SO notes, that just isn't good enough for them and a line is crossed. The direction they took is attempting to move the line, which sits somewhere between requesting clarification and driving off askers.

Comment: @TravisJ 92% *according to a few dozen SO employees*.  An opinion not shared by many of the other thousands of members of the community.

Comment: @BoltClock I have to admit, after reading the blog post I went back and rewrote a recent sarcastic/snarky comment to be nicer, so it's hopefully improved the quality of the average comment. I hope it's not done so at the expense of valuable users' contribution, but that's what I'm here to find out (and going off of Erik's query, it doesn't look like it has).

Comment: @Servy Don't be absurd. That is not SO's goal. Their goal is for people to stop being rude. Yes, they are stumbling like a spider wearing roller skates in their attempt to do it. But their goal is not seppuku.

Comment: @HansPassant Downvotes being down 16% actually really worries me. Is that a consistent trend since the blogpost (I assume obtained using SEDE?)? Do you have similar trends going for close votes and delte votes?

Comment: @HansPassant that’s strange. As far as I remember, the stated goal was reduce “unwelcoming comments” and it has been suggested to downvote without a comment instead. Now, you’re saying that downvotes are “the most institutionalized kind of unwelcoming”. Just to be clear, I’m with you on that point. I always tried to give constructive comments before downvoting, to give the OP a chance to improve the post without going through downvotes. And I know, a lot of people never come back to check whether the post has been improved, to retract the downvote. But you’re contradicting previous messages.

Comment: I have no real idea what you are objecting against.  I merely noted that DVs are a welcoming problem, a lot of users take them as a personal attack and complain about it loudly.  Not the only kind of institutionalized unwelcoming, questions bans are the harshest kind and nobody is ever happy about close and dup votes.  Those have all been weakened quite a bit, but DVs are pretty hard to squelch.  I assumed, but apparently a blog post was enough to put a dent in them.

Comment: @TylerH Their goal is for more people to use the site.  They think that they aren't getting as many users as they want because there is rudeness on the side, and they think that the problem is a result people posting rude comments.  I don't believe that either of those are major factors that affect the userbase of the site, nor do I think that their attempts to make the site more friendly are likely to be successful (on a significant scale).  But just because they're not actively trying to kill themselves doesn't mean that's not precisely the direction they're moving towards.

Comment: @HansPassant "nobody is ever happy about close and dup votes" Not true. I occasionally get new OPs thanking me for providing an answer to their question when I dupe-hammer. However, since the "Be more welcoming" drive started I do tend to add a personal comment asking the OP to let me know if the dupe target doesn't answer their question adequately. Also, if the target isn't a perfect match, or if it's obvious the OP is a newbie to the language, I try to add some extra info in my comment to help them along.

Comment: @Servy Even if that's the effective outcome, it is not their *goal* to get people to stop commenting less or to stop helping. Their goal is to stop people from being rude. Talk about whether that's a good idea, or talk about whether their methods are effective, but don't say their goal is something it's not; that's dishonest.

Comment: @TylerH I've seen lots of SO staff *specifically* saying that they're trying to get people to comment less.  It's not always easy to distinguish company policy from the policies that individual employees are advocating, but I'm also not sure if it matters, as the later will be treated by most as the former even if that's not the intent.  Many people have made it clear that they want people downvoting and moving on way more often, and commenting way less.

Comment: @Servy If the user is unable to comment without being rude or snarky, then yes, don't comment. In the context of this broader discussion, that's more "less rudeness" than "less commenting", to be frank. And yes, it can be frustrating when The Company says one thing and individual employees say or do another, but we should not argue from a position of what the individual employees say when it countermands what The Company says. That's the wrong direction.

Comment: @TylerH "The Company" doesn't say anything.  Individuals say things.  Some of them intend to say things that represent the company's view, some intent to say things that represent their views and not the views of the company as a whole.  Sometimes they're explicit as to which they mean, often they aren't.  But employees aren't contradicting "The Company", they are, at most, contradicting *other employees*.

Comment: That said, I'm not seeing contradiction.  There are lots of people saying, "rude comments are a problem", and not many people advocating actual changes to address the issue (just that ideas will be forthcoming).  Some employees *have* said though that they'd encourage people to comment less in general, trying to get people to "move on" rather than interacting with problematic posts.  That is not a contradiction.  I haven't seen people representing the company saying that they still want people commenting just as much as before, but just being "nicer".

Comment: @Servy - My experience is that users who have a problem with a post frequently don't bother explaining what the problem is in any reasonable fashion. If I downvote a post below 0, I try to always leave an explanation. And if I vote to close I always leave an explanation. And I try to leave it in as neutral a tone as possible. After all, it was my choice to spend time on the post.

Comment: @Omnifarious And it's precisely your behavior that SO thinks new users tend to perceive as an attack and as being unwelcoming, and that SO is therefore trying to discourage.  That said, I find it rather uncommon to see a post be downvoted much or closed without comments indicating its problems or how it could be improved.  The community, generally speaking, spends a *lot* of time trying to help people improve their questions, despite the fact that very few of them actually do so in response to such feedback.

Comment: @Servy - I was going to say "Most of the time." instead of 'frequently' in my comment, but I didn't because I realized you were right. The times downvotes or close votes without comments happen stick out in my mind a lot. Especially when it happens to me. :-) I think SO is foolish to discourage this. The only thing I noticed that seemed like it would drive people away was a distinct tendency to close things that didn't clearly need to be closed. People who can't handle sincere constructive, non-hostile feedback won't be helped by SO anyway.

Comment: *`That is not SO's goal. Their goal is for people to stop being rude.`* That's not their goal either. Their stated goal is for no one to feel as if something rude was said to them. IE. an unachievable goal, because there will always be someone who's looking to get offended (I have seen people get offended at *downvotes*). But as *this* question isn't about *that* debate, I'll [redirect you over somewhere else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312080/313685).

Comment: The basic problem is that people with high reputation tend to be people who set themselves very high standards and demand similarly high standards of others, and while some people respond well to leaders who demand high standards, others perceive them as unwelcoming and elitist. If I point out to a questioner for example that one specimen input and output does not constitute a specification, some people will take that as personal criticism, but I will continue to make the point that any answer is only a guess if the requirements are imprecise.

Comment: @Draco18s I get offended at downvotes, if there is no way of ascertaining the reason for the downvote. I think it's definitely rude to say you don't like what someone has written without saying why.

Comment: @MichaelKay: That seems to be a misunderstanding of the purpose of downvotes. Downvotes are not about telling a person you don't like what they have written. Downvotes are how you tell *other people* that what was written is not a good use of their time. Downvotes are not meant to spark corrective action from the OP; they're meant to help others avoid poor quality content. It's a signpost; signs don't need an explanation.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have the feeling that that is the point: new users don't understand that, get a downvote, get upset, and leave.

Comment: @NicolBolas Telling other people not to bother reading stuff that I have spent time writing, without saying why you are giving other people that advice, is insulting to me. I have no idea whether the person downvoting is an expert or an idiot, and I have no opportunity to explain why I think they are wrong.

Comment: @MichaelKay: The basis of this site is the expectation that voting will eventually yield the right answer. That is, it *doesn't matter* if there's *someone* out there who thinks that what you said is bad. If what you said is good, then the evident quality of your post will attract enough upvotes to make a spurious downvote meaningless. And if what you said isn't as good as you think, then maybe it deserves that downvote. What we *don't want* is a discussion; SO's entire system exists to *prevent* discussions, not to create them.

Comment: I can speak from my personal perspective (as a 100K+ user). I've cut my commenting by probably 90%, opting instead to simply downvote and closevote rather than commenting. When you can't ask for a MCVE or suggest an edit or clarification without saying *Pretty please, may I please (with no offense intended) ask you (again, not meaning to make you feel unwelcome), beg of you to provide some code (but it's OK if you don't, because asking for it might make you feel bad) that helps explain the problem (not that you don't write extremely eloquently, but because I'm not smart enough to understand)?*

Comment: (continued) or risk suspension or banning, it becomes not worth the risk, especially when the level of risk is based on flags from low-rep users who think anything you say that isn't praise is unwelcoming and rude. When a moderator tells me (in a private message warning me of flags on a canned comment I've used here for at least 2 years) "Your comment is being flagged. If it's any consolation, I've had to stop using idownvotedbecau.se myself because of this situation*, I'd prefer to just downvote, VTC and move on to another question. The only downside? I run out of votes almost every day.

Comment: @canon: That's not my concern. I'm not in any way violating any *be nice* rule by using the site exactly as it was designed to function, and by not commenting to explain or try to help I'm not violating any new *coddle the newcomers who can't be bothered to learn how the site works* policy by using an unfriendly or unwelcoming phrase like "Please include the code that isn't working so we can try to help you" and getting myself suspended.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're talking about the *amount* of comments, I've constructed [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/872491/comment-count-for-high-rep-users-by-day?HighRepBorder=10000#graph) to measure that.

[image: Graph of comments by >10k users]

Eyeballing it, I see that the amount of comments by >10k users has been on a steady decline since 2014. You can enter your own cutoff for high-rep and see the numbers yourself.

If you're talking about the *quality* of comments, SE is just developing tools to measure that. I hope they make the data they gather publicly available, so we can draw our own conclusion. But there's no real data available.

Note that there are many sources of bias for drawing conclusions based on this query. The main ones are: the reputation cutoff is *current* reputation, not reputation when the comment was made (this less new comments), deleted users and comments aren't counted (this leads to more new comments), reputation may be harder to achieve nowadays (this leads to less new comments). So take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Note that this isn't able to account for deleted comments, or comments from now deleted users, which skews the data.

Comment: @Servy Indeed, and it doesn't correct for the fact that there are more high-rep users with passing time either. But I'd expect all those effects to skew it towards more recent and less older comments. Honestly, this wasn't at all the result I was expecting.

Comment: Trying to normalize for number of users with X reputation would be hard as, over time, users will stop being active.  You'd really want to normalize it based on "active" users, but now you need to define the term somehow, which isn't easy.

Comment: @Servy Yes, activity might be a large bias here. I wouldn't know how to reliably correct for that, besides calculating rep at the time the comment was posted, which will be _way_ too complex to not cause a timeout.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth This is just the kind of stuff I'm looking for, thanks! Would there be a way to add a filter to run this query only for comments added with 24 hours (or some other amount) of a question/answer being posted? I'm giving it a shot to try joining it on Posts where the creation date of the post is within a day of the creation date of the comment, but I'm not very good with the SEDE. If you don't want to actually write it, you can just tell me it's possible and I'll work it out; I just don't know if there's a queriable association between posts and comments.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I have the time, so [here you go](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/872506/comments-within-24-hours-by-high-rep-users?HighRepBorder=10000#graph). The numbers are remarkably similar to the previous query: a very large fraction of all comments is posted within 24 hours, especially those by high-rep users. Tip: read the [SEDE faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/369403). There's a relationship between nearly all tables in SEDE.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thank you! For the query, but mostly for that faq link; that's a gold mine. I guess that makes sense the data is so similar; I suppose high-rep users aren't prone to going back to a week-old question

Comment: 2014 sounds right, that's about the time IIRC that my activity on SO started to taper off. Nowadays the only things I really do here are I ask a question when I need to, upvote good answers that I get to from Google, and peruse meta.

Comment: The decline exists period.  You can see it with the HighRepBorder at a mere 90 - not 900 or 9000, 90.  It's just more pronounced at >2k, as around the 2k rep mark and below, there's an odd spike in 2015 before it starts dropping again.

Comment: It's worth comparing this to the overall number of comments for all users. There does seem to be an overall decrease in comments, but the trend is more pronounced for high rep users. ([Query for 1 rep or higher](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/872491/comment-count-for-high-rep-users-by-day?HighRepBorder=1#graph))

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Keep in mind that 10K users have more than 1 rep too, so you might still see the effect of the high-rep users commenting less, just diluted by more comments. If you only query for users with <1000 rep, [it looks very different](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/872853#graph). Do note that comment by Servy can explain a lot of this: the query takes _current rep_ into account, so 1-rep users in 2014 may have more than 1K rep by now.

Comment: This also doesn't account for past initiatives like the summer of love, better tooling for removing comments, pushes to delete older comments by the staff/moderators, etc.

Comment: This needs to be adjusted for 'rate of people achieving 10k'. There is going to be a lifetime for most people's engagement with any site. Over time, people will leave. Also, new people might not achieve the required cutoff level as easily as time goes on for a wide variety of reasons. If you adjust for the rate at which users achieve the cutoff, I think the measure will be more accurately reflect what you're trying to measure, which is high-rep users engagement with the site.

Comment: @Omnifarious I've added a note at the bottom about some of the sources of bias. Unfortunately, with the data available and the timeouts and performance of SEDE being what it is, I couldn't do better (rep history is not available and would need to be calculated for things like _rate of people reaching 10K_ or _reputation at time of placing comments_. If you feel like you can write a less biased query, I encourage you to do so. And you can add notes to that message if you feel I've missed something.

Comment: Could the decline in comments be because as StackOverflow has evolved, the overall quality of questions and answers has also improved, thus necessitating less comments?

Comment: @ZevSpitz No. The more you answer question, the more you get really annoyed due to people that ask questions without doing a simple Googling. Too many poor questions causes high rep users to reduce commenting, ignore the question, flag to close it or down-vote it. The quality of questions has not improved.

Comment: I'm a SEDE noob but I believe [this edit](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/874952/comment-count-for-high-rep-users-by-month?HighRepBorder=10000#graph) of the query shows comments by month instead of by day in case somebody wants that. No guarantees on correctness though...