# Should we ban comments asking for vote justification?

Tags: discussion, comments

I mean different variants of

> Why the downvote?

Justification:

- Even in the most neutral form (like the one above) they are at least passive-aggressive, and often go straight to the rude and abusive side.
- If voter made a conscious decision to avoid explanation an attempt to force the comment doesn't feel right. Additionally it is likely that the voter will never go back to the post.
- I don't have hard data to support that, but I often get an impression that comments like this make other users uncomfortable, and result in all kinds of "it is not my vote" responses.
- Discussions about votes can easily get out of control - it is not easy to explain why post is not useful, and be truly "welcoming" at the same time.

Overall justification requests are ([disputably](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252826/8371915)) not constructive and likely to escalate. This is particularly important in the light of new CoC and overall "welcoming" discussion which seems to strongly promote "if you're in doubt, don't". Voters should not be pressured to respond, especially when there is a high probability of misunderstanding.

**Edit**:

Responding to [the comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371405/should-we-ban-comments-asking-for-vote-justification#comment612749_371405) by [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)

> Why not simply flag the comment as "no longer needed" since it in fact not needed

This is certainly an option, but doesn't fully address the problems mentioned above. It might however if there was fast track removal path, similar to the one for "thank you" comments.

**Another edit**

The question I want to raise here is not if why-the-downvote comments are constructive, but if they should be accepted in the context of the emerging [CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review) and overall "welcoming" discussion.

There are two points which are particularly important in my opinion:

- Why-the-downvote comments are usually (that's subjective, so I look forward to community feedback) not welcoming, especially when we tend focus on "Unwelcoming language" and not intent ([Feedback on the Comment Classifier blog post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370838/8371915)).

  Subjectively (once again community feedback is welcomed) they affect both voters and passersby.
- Why-the-downvote comments are an attempt to coerce voters into behavior which goes strictly against their own best interest. Considering only on-site mechanics voter is always better-off by not commenting on a vote:

  - *Voter comments*, user accepts the explanation and fixes or deletes the post if it cannot be fixed (0 on site, overall satisfaction).
  - *Voter comments*, user doesn't respond (0 on site, 0 outside site).
  - *Voter comments*, user starts rude or offensive comments (0, -1 outside site if voter cares about being called names by a stranger).
  - *Voter comments*, user starts revenge voting (-1 on site, -1 outside side if voter cares about internet points).
  - *Voter comments*, comment is marked as not welcoming enough (-1 on site, -1 outside side). It's been pointed out in [With a userbase as diverse as Stack Overflow's, how will we arrive at an actionable definition of "unwelcoming"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370993/8371915) that finding "actionable definition" of welcoming is hard in such diverse community, and to be honest I am not eager to check if my limited English skills and unfamiliarity with US culture can survive the welcomes  test.
  - *Voter doesn't comment* (0 on site, ? outside site).

  To summarize, if I comment I can only get worse and never better, than when I don't comment.

**Yet another edit**

Seeing a heated discussion in the comments I think it important to point out that assumption that comments-on-votes are useful and should encouraged doesn't imply that why-the-downvote comments are as well.

I strongly suspect (this could an interesting survey question) that comments requesting vote explanations have actually an opposite effect. Based on my personal experience is it actually a good warning sign of troubles waiting ahead, I tend to avoid taking a part in the discussion, regardless of my actual status (being original voter or not).

So unless there is a strong empirical evidence suggesting that explanation requests actually prompt the explanations (or otherwise), we shouldn't use it as an argument pro or against why-the-downvote comments.

Comment: Eh. The other side is that  these comments *can* draw out useful explanations from downvoters who'd otherwise have moved on silently; I've left them occasionally myself with success. I wouldn't block them from being posted outright, although by their nature they're obsolete the next day and should be deleted or flagged. (Naturally, the usefulness depends heavily on its tone; the same notional question may be read as "I don't understand; please provide me with an explanation?" or as "who dared downvote my answer? I will smash them!" depending upon word choice, and the latter isn't useful.)

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366421/1233251

Comment: Why not simply flag the comment as "no longer needed" since it in fact *not* needed

Comment: I just ignore them, no special reply/action/ban required.  Such comments are a invitation to a free mugging, and I'd rather stay out of hospital.

Comment: @user2285236 I am not sure if I can agree with the duplicate target. It is certainly related, but doesn't reflect current situation.

Comment: @MartinJames I share the feeling, but it I'd like to save the others learning this the hard way.

Comment: I think the issue is the opposite. A downvote is so vague if a seemingly good post is downvoted, how with the poster know how they could correct it? Justification should be the norm, not the abnorm; especially if the goal is to now be a welcoming community and discourage downvoting unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @vol7ron well, that would be nice, woudn't it?  Sadly, given the very poor record of users improving bad questions after constructive comments, and the even poorer record of responding with abuse, there is next-to-no incentive for curators to attempt to explain downvotes.  If OP's wish, they can read the rules/policy/advice that is freely available and work out for themselves why they were downvoted.  It would be good if they could show some diligence and read that advice before asking questions instead of asking for street-fights afterwards:(

Comment: Non-voter, why did you not vote??? Whats wrong with my question?? If I find you I'm going to go thru every single one of your questions and not vote on them!

Comment: @JK could you please stop with the serial non-voting? Or at least explain yourself on each of my posts you see? Having to flag your (lack of) actions daily is getting tiresome!

Comment: @MartinJames agreed. I still don’t think it explains the good posts that are just randomly downvoted. When they’re seemingly good, the rules aren’t going to help unless someone was downvoted for some obscure interpretation of the rules. More than likely it’s an emotional downvote, which should be discouraged — the rules don’t justify that.

Comment: Downvote should have a clear reason. So you should not ban those who ask for downvote.

Comment: 'I still don’t think it explains the good posts that are just randomly downvoted' - examples/evidence, please!  You see, the thing is, that the 'random downvote' claim is made very frequently and, just as often, the claimants are asked for evidence to back up that slur against SO curators.  So far the number of examples linked, over years, is zero.

Comment: @vol7ron 'emotional downvote'... how likely do you think that is from a group of software enthusiasts and professional engineeers who only appear/vote on this site because they have much skill and experience dealing with soulless, dispassionate data processing machinery?  They send their working lives keeping emotion out of machine-managing because they know it is a useless tool: it will not kill bugs, for example.

Comment: @GeneCode I agree.  Just ignore the request.  It does not need a flag and/or ban.

Comment: @vol7ron if you want to see some evidence of unacceptable behaviour, you should take note of the huge numbers of accounts that get removed for sock-puppeting, ring-voting etc.   There is a LOT more evidence for that than 'emotional downvotes'.

Comment: @vol7ron Would you mind defining _emotional downvote_? Vote arrows give are self describing - "Not useful" for votes "does not show any research effort; is unclear or not useful" . There are highly subjective, but so are the opposite options. Posts which are useful and clear for you are not always useful or clear for others. There are cases which call for an explanation (especially when the answer is has subtle problems which can cause problems for other users), but most of the time we just express opinions. And discussing opinions is a short way to trouble.

Comment: @MartinJames If you’re asking how likely it is that programmers get emotional, I would say very. Go ask any about emacs vs vim or spaces vs tabs or even further.. how many spaces. Not every engineer is like Wozniak some are like Jobs. And this site attracts a wide variety of ages.  I’m sure some of these accounts are kids in high school or earlier.

Comment: @MartinJames as for evidence — what do you need? There have been cases of serial downvoting in the past. That is, someone gets mad over a comment, looks at that person’s profile and downvotes all of their answers. SO put in safeguards to ban those accounts. Then came sock-puppeting as you say. But not everyone is some master engineer or willing to do this, some people still lash out and downvote because an answer is too similar to theirs. You want evidence of those cases? So do I.

Comment: @MartinJames Which is why asking for a comment with a downvote would help. If people are worried about retaliation, then you have just proven that people get emotional. I would suggest those downvote comments to be anonymous until a certain level is reached.

Comment: I'm working on a query to have the deleted with a one user flag and to auto delete them from the site's history, with the help of Shog super powers. That way the OP can ask, but it will be removed in a timely fashion.

Comment: @vol7ron The site already prompts (new?) users to comment if they think the post can be improved - so what else can angry why-the-downvote comment achieve? If didn't comment, and I get an impression that OP is already angry, why on Earth would I comment now? And the problem is not really if we should explain (it has been discussed many times), but about respecting user decision to not, especially when good intentions are just not enough.

Comment: Thank you @YvetteColomb.

Comment: @user8371915 FWIW I've been campaigning publicly and working behind the scenes to help with the sites comments, as they seem to be a big source of friction and flagging. So I'm trying to oil the wheels. This is the latest public effort https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371410/can-we-have-some-site-approved-canned-comments-to-match-the-new-coc-and-welcomin

Comment: @user8371915 that’s like asking if the OP knows the rules, why didn’t they write the post correctly to begin with? Again, sometimes the rules are obscure. But I point out again, you all are speculating why people downvoted. Your trust is that the downvoter is right and the OP is wrong. — The point of the downvote comment is not to cause harm, but to show how the answer may be improved — To avoid any retaliation is why I think it should be anonymous. There are too many cases of downvotes without questions and people wondering how they could improve their answer. That’s an ineffective system.

Comment: My mobile device replaces my words too frequently.  ... there are too many cases of downvotes on questions w/o any comments. A downvote without any comment at all leaves people wondering how they could improve their answer.

Comment: @vol7ron Correct me if I am wrong but primary tool for enforcing site rules are flags and close-votes - both come with specific justification which reflects community consensus and terms of service. Post votes are just opinions - we can try to do out best, but we have no way to guarantee that our downvotes are any more objective or correct than our upvotes. It is just the wisdom of the crowd, nothing more and nothing less. And since both mechanics and emotions are skewed towards positive feedback it is more likely that someone gets unjustified upvote than downvote.

Comment: That sounds correct. The issue is that a negative vote is not as welcoming as not voting at all. I thought the community is trying to be more welcoming. If a downvote is just a “I don’t like that answer” that’s not good for the community. If it’s a “that’s a bad answer because it’s <insecure/inefficient//incorrect/poorly worded>” that at least gives the answerer something to go on. — I would think the ideal (perhaps unreachable) goal is to have all good answers and only upvotes awarded to the exceptional answers.

Comment: @vol7ron How is refusing to provide accurate feedback on the quality of a post welcoming to all of the people who will come across the page and be interested in knowing how useful each of the answers are?  It's rather unwelcoming to refuse to help *all* of those people when you do in fact know that an answer isn't useful, but are refusing to provide that information, resulting in them being mislead into using an answer, thinking that it's useful, when *you could have helped them avoid it*.

Comment: @Servy you may want to go back an re-read. You’re solidifying my point. Improving answers is the goal. Downvoting is only a short-term remedy. Voting itself isn’t reliable, especially for newer solutions to older questions.

Comment: @vol7ron How is voting a short term solution?  Do votes expire?  If so, that's news to me.  Yes, improving an answer from a bad answer to a good one is great.  Sadly, it pretty rarely happens for answers with significant problems.  Often because it's not possible, sometimes because it's just too hard for the author to do.  Sure, sometimes voting isn't reliable because people like you refuse to actually cast your vote based on the quality of the post.  That's not a reason to encourage people to vote *worse*, it just makes voting accurately all the more important.

Comment: I expect a ban on these words would go as well as the ban on "-1" or "What have you tried?" in comments; the way it was expressed would just change... "Wherefore the reason this question hath been voted downwardly?"

Comment: @Servy it doesn’t correct the behavior of bad posts. It’s shortsighted to expect a downvote without an explanation being corrective at all. The only thing it does, as you noted is suggest to the community that it may be a bad answer, but the longer the question the more disparity in voting of good answers — time is a factor. Also, I’ve come across good answers that were downvoted because they offered alternative solutions to the question asked and not because they were bad answers themselves. Finally, don’t you dare speculate how I vote. You have no idea.

Comment: Asking about downvotes isn't always passive-agressive or a trap. For example: _"I noticed I've been getting downvotes on this post. Reading over it again, I'm not sure what I've missed. What can I do to improve this post?"_ Sure, this _could_ just be an innocent sounding trap, but that's assuming bad faith. It could _also_ legitimately be the OP wanting to know how to improve their post... (Just to point this out, I _have_ seen this style comment a few times.)

Comment: @vol7ron Sure it does.  Lots of people correct problematic posts as a results of downvotes that they get.  That said, that's a secondary goal of the votes, not their primary goal.  The primary goal is to ensure that readers are given information on the quality of the posts.  That's valuable.  That you're refusing to provide that *very useful* information is a problem.  I'm not speculating on your voting, *you're telling us* how you vote, and I'm telling you the major problems with *the behavior you're advocating should be used*.

Comment: @Servy I’ve asked why my answer had been downvoted and thanked someone and made a correction when they’ve answered. One time, it was a bad reason (if that really was the downvoter) to which I was penalized for no legitimate reason.  Sure, people correct their issue if they know what’s wrong, but often they don’t... resulting in meta comments “why was I downvoted?” or others saying “I didn’t downvote you, ...” — — I did not say how I vote or don’t vote. I’ve only addressed an issue with lack of comments when people downvote and the lack of clarity for the answerer. Please stop speculating.

Comment: @vol7ron And I've seen lots of cases of people complaining about getting downvotes and starting fights and wasting tons of people's time and resulting in no improvements to the answer.  A single anecdote that it works doesn't make the practice useful.  You advocated that people not downvote bad posts.  If that's not how you vote, then my points still stand.  You're advocating that harmful behavior.  If you don't do it yourself that doesn't make the advice any less harmful.

Comment: That is not what I said. I said that would be ideal. That is a fantasy where all answers are good and some are more helpful than others. That isn’t realistic. Stop projecting what you think I’m saying and putting words in my mouth.  It’s agitating and unappreciated. Also, it’s not just one experience. Others have mentioned the same things in Meetup groups, at conferences, and in blog posts. Maybe you are dismissing something because your own feelings are getting in the way(?) I don’t know. I won’t speculate, but it is bad user research to be so dismissive.

Comment: @Servy “I’ve seen seen lots of cases...resulting in no improvements” That sounds like an implementation issue. We have canned reasons for closing votes. Why can’t there also be a simple solution for downvoting? I’ve already listed a way to discourage confrontation via anonymity. It sounds like you have a pessimistic, defeatist attitude to improving the voting system, whereas I would like for it to be improved.

Comment: @vol7ron If you want to propose that comments be mandatory with downvotes, feel free to do so.  Note that it's been a rejected suggestion *many thousands* of times because there is just so much compelling evidence that it would be harmful.  You're free to do the research yourself if you want to learn more about why it's a bad idea.  It's not pessimistic to consider very compelling and overwhelming evidence that a given course of action is harmful.  Ignoring all of that evidence and advocating it anyway, because it works 1% of the time, doesn't lead to improvements.

Comment: Because it wasn’t implemented correctly. It’s equivalent to putting a petrol engine in an amphib-vehicle and complaining when the vehicle’s engine is submerged underwater. That won’t work. A diesels engine, on the other hand, works great. — Solutions to problems are the same way and you’re saying it doesn’t work. I’ve been on this site as a reader and contributor for nearly a decade and I haven’t seen any implementation when downvoting. Your explanation that it doesn’t work escapes me. I would further challenge you that the implemented solution was not satisfactory.

Comment: @vol7ron If you think you have an entirely new idea for how to force people to comment when voting that hasn't already been discussed and that addressed the criticisms of all of the other proposals, then feel free to make such a proposal.  Given how many have failed, I don't like your chances.  Just make sure you do your research, because there have been a *lot* of different proposals, and there are lots of different problems for you address if you want to make another.

Comment: @vol7ron I tend to believe that the value of the explanation and validity of give-me-explanation comments are two separate problems. Without strong evidence that one (request) implies other (explanation) this would be a pure speculation. It also doesn't address the problem that such requests are (subjectively) not welcoming but itself. Two wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: It is possible that the downvoter misunderstood an answer and prompting them to think further about their downvote would lead them to reverse the downvote, leading to a more accurate representation of an answer's worth.

Comment: @user8371915 yes, they’re separate issues. Both are triggered by the same action and I believe that a solution can accompany that action. There isn’t going to be a perfect solution, but I believe there is a better solution that would satisfy more users.

Comment: @vol7ron That's something we can agree on. I'd even say that the overall focus on unwelcoming language is rather unfortunate and misguided. As long as there is large group with different linguistic and cultural background misunderstandings are bound to happen. We should focus on leading by example and resolving conflicts than hard policing based on arbitrary and culture specific rules. That being said, these rules are the reality now, and prompt for reevaluation of certain patterns. This in my option includes votes requests.

Comment: @D.W. Indeed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Most people value constructive criticism and dislike unconstructive criticism. An unexplained downvote is unconstructive criticism and it's entirely reasonable for the person so criticised to seek more detailed feedback on what you didn't like. You can ignore the request but that's even less helpful than the original downvote.

Comment: @pnuts It think it is important to distinguish here between site related motivation and incentives and personal one. Many actions which are personally rewarding, might not be (for good or bad)  incentivized by the platform (gamification model, terms of service, CoC).

Comment: @jpmc26 I somehow fail to see how the linked question addresses the problems mention here. I strongly believe that both focus and circumstances are different.

Comment: @user8371915 A moderator in the linked question explains that these comments are not constructive and they are deleted when flagged. Other than that, what kind of *ban* are you suggesting?

Comment: @user2285236 Initially I thought about similar limitations as for "what have you tried" and similar comments, but [improving removal process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371405/should-we-ban-comments-asking-for-vote-justification?noredirect=1#comment612893_371405) could be a better approach.

Comment: I think it depends a lot on the person, but I see a lot of value in asking "why the down-vote". I have a tendency to pick a couple of questions and check them several times until I feel either the OP is not paying attention or he knows what he needs. So I can see how someone would down-vote without writing a reason, because for them is obvious, and when the OP asks, the reviewer  can take the time to clarify the down-vote. That way you use your time to comment the vote ONLY if the OP actually cares to know.

Comment: @Brad It seems like you completely missed the point of the question, and decided to put things in my mouth. I never stated (if I did, please be so kind and point out that votes shouldn't be explained). However I strongly oppose attempts to force people to comment, if they otherwise decided (for whatever reason) not to. It is strange to see that you cannot recognize a difference between these two.

Comment: Wut ? Nah. Instead, on Stack Overflow at least, let's ban down-vote that don't provide justification.

Comment: @scharette in your case, that would involve you in more three times more work as you try to explain your upvotes too.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure I quite understand what you just said .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, definitely not.

You have some valid points, but I get the impression that they are pretty speculative (which you also admit to some extent) and I have not seen the same picture as you at all. I do not claim my view to be 100% true and good, but I really do not see the same problems you see. I can at most admit that there are *potential* problems, but not *actual* problems.

> Even in the most neutral form (like the one above) they are at least passive-aggressive, and often go straight to the rude and abusive side.

Well, I admit some truth to this, but I cannot see how that justifies a ban. It's important that it is allowed to ask. After all, you're not forced to answer anyway.

> If voter made a conscious decision to avoid explanation an attempt to force the comment doesn't feel right. Additionally it is likely that the voter will never go back to the post.

I have asked this several times, both on my post and others, and I have often received useful answers. Sometimes from the downvoter and sometimes from others. It has often helped me improve my posts.

> I don't have hard data to support that, but I often get an impression that comments like this make other users uncomfortable, and result in all kinds of "it is not my vote" responses.

I have no idea how uncomfortable it makes other users. I can only answer for myself here, and I have no problem whatsoever to answer *"I did not downvote, but I think it is because of < reason >"*.

> Discussions about votes can easily get out of control - it is not easy to explain why post is not useful, and be truly "welcoming" at the same time.

Occasionally I've seen these discussions become somewhat hectic, but that's ok. It is very rarely I would describe it as "out of control".

Comment: Why did you downvote? :D

Answer (score 9):

No, don't do this. There are two reasons:

1. **They often help questioners / answerers to improve content.** The focus shouldn't be on internet points(*), it should be on improving content. Some people instinctively delete their negative-scoring posts. Others, like me, religiously don't unless they can see, or are made to see, something materially wrong with their answer. I have often improved, and sometimes deleted, posts based on specific feedback from voters.
2. **They clarify usefulness of poor-scoring accepted answers.** Accepted answers get pinned at the top. On several occasions, my negatively scoring post has been accepted(**). This only serves to confuse the community and the wider audience (visitors from Google)... What? The answer is pinned at the top and has got a green tick. But it's got a negative score. What does that mean? Commenting on such answers helps the wider community and improves SO as a Q&A resource.

(*) Some increased possibility of retaliation votes.

(**) Some examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204552/loop-through-each-row-and-write-id-if-it-exists-in-list-pandas/50205433#50205433), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130592/how-can-i-fill-the-data-frame-na-value-using-data-in-another-dataframe-python/50130803#50130803), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695751/make-a-year-week-column-in-python/49695875#49695875), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696344/numpy-where-and-division-by-zero/48696529#48696529).

Comment: I feel like you are addressing a different question here. I don't doubt that comments on votes can be useful in general. I just don't think that the comments should be extorted this way, and the language which is usually used, has further implications.

Comment: @user8371915, I take your point. But, as many would say, if you don't ask you don't get. I *often* ask for feedback on negative voting on my answers, and perhaps 50% of the time get a productive response. Don't have official stats, and it's only one person, but it's my experience.

Answer (score 6):

`they are at least passive-aggressive`

Sometimes, but not always. Here are two examples:

**Questionable or malicious votes:** I have questioned downvoting that was later deemed suspicious enough to be removed. The possibly-bot downvotes happened almost immediately after I asked the question and took attention from a fresh and valid question, and visitors could at least see a short discussion including someone else commenting that it was a reasonable question, giving them a reason to still consider using it or answering.

**The user really doesn't know why their question is downvoted, and we want to help them become a better community member:** We as a community have been talking about making SO welcoming to new users and not turning them off. Even if a user tries to follow guides, standards, and conventions, they may need help *in the context of their specific question to fully understand*. A discussion will allow them to overcome frustrations and edit the question without giving up. Helping people is half the reason we are here, therefore I think it is worth our time to encourage the community personally. The discussion can be as simple as paraphrasing or linking to guides, much like how a duplicate question flag automatically shows the potential duplicate to allow for contextual discussion.

**Since there are valid reasons for discussing votes**, we should mitigate their noise after each matter is settled by using the existing comment flagging tool for anything that is no longer helpful.

[image]

Comment: I have these 2 things exactly happening to me. I posted a question and about 30 secs later someone down-voted (the question was longer than your post, so no way they actually read it complete) and you have no clue what just happened. Another time I created a very complete question (in my opinion) and someone felt I was missing something or it was not clear and down-voted without comments, and only after I asked for clarification someone helped me realize what was wrong.

Comment: @Dzyann The "in my opinion" part is incredibly important to desonctruct. It does not matter what one's opinion of their post is. It's the *content* that is evaluated here, and if said content is poorly researched, a downvote is the signal that needs to be applied to it. Unrelatingly, do not underestime the quickness at which an experimented user of a technology can scan a post to see id it contains key elements. I can recognize a lack of research in many questions which tags I'm proficient in in mere seconds, with very high accuracy.

Comment: ... not to mention that generally, longer questions are mostly noise.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I agree with you, I have seen many of such questions. I would like to point out though that my comment is not a rant. I just have seen this happen for whatever reason and that is why I find value on being able to ask why did I get a down-vote. I research thoroughly, asking friends and colleagues and searching on internet, books, and whatever resource I can find, however I am not perfect and I am bound to ask something someone won't like or that someone else has asked before.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Also, being not native English speaker, sometimes I can be searching for a long time for something and I ask a friend from the US to search for the same and they find it in a second. They way I phrase things is obviously different, and for this and many other reasons of the like, and even for the very one you are pointing out, "opinion", the one down-voting in those 30 secs may very well be wrong on their down-vote, or they may be seeing something I don't so I find extremely helpful to be able in some way to ask "why?"