# About people suggesting alternate methods or services for helping out

Tags: support, comments, users, code-of-conduct

Premise: I've limited experience about SO and SE in general, so I don't know if this is a common issue; also, this is a matter I find difficult to find out about in here, as its description might be very vague.

There's an user that, usually in comments, suggests people to contact him (or her) using other methods than SO community (as far as I've understood, there's a Discord channel). While it usually happens *after* a question has been somehow answered (as an actual answer or in a comment), I think that this is not really a good behavior in here, as it is completely against the overall concept of Stack Exchange.

I know that I could just write a comment to mark that, but unfortunately I've had some *[history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388558/is-this-rudeness-with-polite-disclaimer)* with that user; while there has been some kind of "reach" (interestingly enough, suggesting to join a Discord channel again), I really am not interested in that, and any other kind of previous interaction always ended up into unclaimed comment/fighting threads. I want to avoid further unnecessary *noise*: I know from experience that it's difficult that any "closure" would happen from such conversations in an online community.

From a personal point of view, I could just ignore all of that. But I really feel that the "contact me on [*whatever*] if you need [further] help" isn't very compatible with SO at all.

I've already flagged a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747884/no-taskbar-details-after-splash-screen#comment103800885_58747884) as "Something else" explaining my point of view, but I'm afraid that it won't be enough.

Am I overreacting, or is there something that should be actually done about this matter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct: requesting a user to contact you off-site is not allowed here, in large part precisely because it is against the entire concept of Stack Exchange. (In addition, it's a potential abuse/harassment vector that we cannot moderate.) It's not a Code of Conduct violation, *per se*, but it's not something that we encourage.

The best thing for you to do would be to flag these comments. Pick either "no longer needed", or use the custom option to type a message to moderators. (If the issue is blatantly obvious, skip the custom option and just go with "no longer needed".)

Moderators review flagged comments and routinely delete them. This is easier for everyone, avoids arguments, and solves the root of the problem. There's almost never a reason for you to get into a debate or discussion with someone about it.

I deleted both of the comments on [that question where you raised a flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747884/no-taskbar-details-after-splash-screen). You just hadn't waited long enough for a moderator to clear the flag queue. We get a lot of flags, and we're running a bit low on moderators at the moment.

Also…the user who left that comment is well-known to moderators as exhibiting a pattern of this behavior. So we've handled that case specially. If you see patterns like this, it's OK to flag one of the user's posts and explain your concerns in the textbox. Flags are confidential, so you cannot be targeted by that user for sharing your concerns with moderators.

Comment: Thanks. I flagged the comment while thinking about this post, as I wasn't sure about the correct conduct to follow, so I chose to take both actions. I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: As they point out, the user's behavior has already become routine, even becoming uncomfortable because he always places the same information. I foolishly wanted to explain to him not to introduce noise in the comments but he seems not to understand, it has already become routine for me to raise flags for his comments.