# Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, edits, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

So far I was working under the assumption that any edit will push a closed question to the review queue.

After all, we advise question-banned users to improve their old questions, and that would not work if the questions are closed and nobody else is likely to notice the edit.

But the documentation for this appears to be contradictory:

According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

> Closed questions that receive edits **within the first 5** days of closure
>   are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for
>   reopening.

But according to this [Faq entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work/161391#161391)

> questions with active reopen votes, as well as questions which have
>   been **edited after closing**, appear in the reopen queue.

And this [help center entry](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) says:

> There is functionally **no difference** between an [on hold] question and
>   a [closed] one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, but
>   they both allow comments, votes and edits.

Does an edit *always* cause a closed question to go to review?

Or is this only the case for "locked" questions that have been closed less than 5 days ago?

Is it any edits or just edits from the original asker?

Is there a rate limit or maximum on how often edits can cause a question to go into the queue?

Comment: The first snippet from the Help Center is correct.  I'm pretty sure the second is also correct, if you qualify "edited after closing" with "within the first 5 days."  The third is also correct, if you don't consider the review queue behavior (which it's not talking about anyway).

Comment: I would add to this: People is getting edits on their belt by editing closed questions without improving them in any aspect but formatting (which in no way saves the question). Getting some of those each time I go into Reopen review queue

Comment: For anyone who *doesn't* want to reopen a question, you can still edit it (it has a [little box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URZfu.png) at the bottom asking if you want to try to reopen).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[From a time when I probably knew something about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078):

> 1. ...Edited (body edits only) within 70 days of closure by the author. Or,
> 2. ...Edited (body edits only) within 70 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to close it. Or,
> 3. ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month.
>
> Note: for #2 (3rd-party edits), any flag raised by the editor *other than* "moderator intervention" disqualifies the edit from consideration, even when the flag comes after the edit, is declined, or is retracted by the flagger. Flag types *include* close and reopen votes, which are represented as flags internally. [There are some unintended consequences to how this is handled](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/why-was-this-reopen-review-item-invalidated/3351#3351).

A question will only be enqueued once per closure via editing. It will be enqueued once per reopen vote *as long as* there are no outstanding reopen votes that've already triggered a review.

Comment: Too bad you don't have access to the source code. :)

Comment: Too bad I'm so lazy

Comment: So if someone else edits my question to fix a spelling, then I exit it to remove the reason it was closed.   My edit will not put it in the reopen queue.

Comment: If someone makes a trivial edit, the question is reviewed, and then someone makes a more extensive edit, the latter edit will not trigger a review @Ian.

Comment: @Shog9 If I understand this correctly, than if a closed question is enqueued because the [OP vandalizes it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25916257/revisions), my reverting to the previous revision will not enqueue it again?

Comment: sounds right to me, @thegrinner

Comment: Are you sure also posts closed by moderators should follow that last rule, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/14886872)? This does explain why we sometimes hit some meta drama, those posts get noticed in the re-open queue.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure about that, @rene; mods can make mistakes too. And... Keep in mind, these can also show up in the reopen queue *years later* if the question isn't deleted for whatever reason. If you get something popular that gets closed but not deleted and folks *keep finding it*, we're not really minimizing the grief by keeping it out of review, we're just pushing that grief on arbitrary searchers.

Comment: So I suppose that the conditions changed now after introducing the checkbox for significant edits. ("This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening.") This was recently announced on [meta.se]: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013)