# How to reopen a question if I don't have (used) reopen vote?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

Long time ago, I've used the reopen vote for [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814501/misplaced-datagrid-error-indicator) without success.

I understand my initial question is not clear enough, so I edited it now to make it a more specific question, but as I had used my vote before, how can I get it reopened/reconsidered?

Or, please can anyone explain why the question should be closed, should I instead of editing/improving it, rather just delete it and post a new question?

Comment: The edit should cause it to go into the "reopen votes" review queue. I frequently come across "this question was edited after it was closed, should it be reopened?" cases when I work through that queue.

Comment: Thanks @ivarni, hope that is the case, and it can get reopened :) As I can't see it in the reopen queue, can anyone justify it please?

Comment: Bolu & @ivarni: This edit didn't push the question into the re-open queue. [Only certain edits do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/444991).

Comment: Is the **"Note"** section of your question at all relevant? Seems like you're just explaining your experience with the dataGrid, and since the problem statement is so vague, it leaves users reading through the note section hoping for more information on the problem, and they instead find... a bunch of irrelevant information.

Comment: @KevinB, they are kind of steps that getting me there. But I agree with you I could possibly improve that section.

Comment: right... but how do they relate to the problem? #1 mentions a problem, and then a solution. so why mention it at all if it isn't a problem you are facing. Repeat the same question for points 2 and 3.

Comment: @KevinB, if I didn't apply the work around in step 3, I won't get this problem, but again, I agree that I will do more work on that. It was like fixing one problem leading me to another, and this is the point I can't fix it any more.