# How do I vote to re-open this question?

Tags: support, status-completed, vote-to-reopen

I would like to bring the attention of this question to Meta:

- [*If, elseif, else in jekyll statement?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12423658/617937)

It was closed as *"too localized"*, however, judging by the massive amount of upvotes and views on the question, contrary to the reason it was closed, **many** people have benefited from it.

Moreover, there is a comment by [**dbaupp**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256624/dbaupp) with 7 upvotes (which means 7 people agreed with him, and likely would have resulted in 7 votes to re-open):

> I'm voting to reopen because this will help future visitors. Even [the official documentation for liquid](http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid#If_.2F_Else_.2F_Unless) doesn't mention `elsif`.

I agree with **dbaupp** that the question should be un-closed, but I can't seem to flag the answer for re-opening, the only options that are appearing are for *spam*, *offensive*, and *other (moderator attention)*. Is there a time-limit, preventing users from voting on old questions?

Comment: Do you require another answer to the question?

Comment: I guess it's a bit ambiguous whether I'm asking _"Please re-open this question"_ or _"Why are several of the flagging options missing?"_ I'm hoping to achieve solutions to both, I suppose.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's more the perfectionist within me who sees a question closed which I feel shouldn't be. I don't plan on adding another answer, no (the one that's there got to the root of the problem very well). But, what if someone else down the line decides they want to add an answer?

Answer (score 4):

The question has now been **reopened**.

I don't think it is possible to flag a question for reopening. You can however edit it, this will have a similar effect:

When you have 3000 repuation, you can vote to close or vote to reopen questions.

With less reputation, you can flag questions for closing; this will cause them to be added to the *close-review queue*, for other users to review.

You can also edit a closed questions; this will cause it to be added to the *reopen-review queue*, again for other users to review.

[However not all edits will cause a question to be added to the reopen queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/145999); Normally only the first edit within 5 days after closure will add it to the reopen queue, but there are some exception for "popular" questions. I am not quite sure what counts as popular.

Failing that, your best option is to bring the issue up in chat, or here on meta, like you have done (and rightly so, IMHO).

Comment: I find a lot of questions are closed as inappropriate when they have great answers with lots of up votes. One I'm looking at today was closed only because of *part* of the question is inappropriate. I see this so much that I'm beginning to wonder if moderators have problems being objective, perhaps related to some cultural aspect to the moderator community that is not constructive (ego related, perhaps, or some competitive element that makes moderator operations rewarding, like commissions for parking inspectors). Please consider editing questions instead of closing them.

Comment: Also see this information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions . Without knowing the numbers or context 50 close votes per day per person seems huge. If you worked for 10 hours a day that is a vote to close 1 question every 12 minutes. If anyone is actually doing that I would argue that's quite likely to be destructive. Otherwise 50 votes per day is the same as infinite votes per day. Why not change it to 5, or even less, like 1. Why is there a goal to close as many questions as possible?