# Should I flag a question which has been incorrectly marked duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, duplicate-questions

Suppose I have made an edit explaining why my question is different, should I flag it for moderator attention?

And if it is indeed not duplicate and is re-opened, is my flag refunded or is it gone?

Comment: You haven't actually explained why the other questions don't answer yours at all. You've engaged in a mini-rant and slightly changed the title. The change you've made to the body of the post directly contradicts the title, and doesn't add _anything_ to the question. If you think it's not a duplicate then please actually explain why.

Comment: Now the banner says "This question already has an answer here:", where there are two links. This is only the duplicate of the first one, not the second one.

Comment: [second link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue) answers "Suppose I have made an edit explaining why my question is different, should I flag it for moderator attention?" -- if you edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure, you should _not_ flag, as this is expected to be handled automatically by the system (which will bring edited question to review of users eligible to reopen)