# Questions should be deleted or not when get closed by moderators?

Tags: support

If any question gets closed due to be duplicate or off-topic or unclear etc. should it not be deleted? Sometimes users do not delete those questions. Some questions may be useful and some are not. What should be done with them?

Comment: [Duplicates are useful](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) because they may help more people find the canonical answers by widening the search terms that lead to them. Other questions are put on-hold, not closed, because **we hope that the OP will improve them** so that they can be reopened and answered. If this doesn't happen, they're usually [autodeleted after a while](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/248731).

Comment: Closed questions are deleted after a week anyway, if they have -1 score or lower. (I believe.) I don't think a mod would delete something, since it might not be a dupe after all, and it might get reopened.

Comment: @JonasCz per the link I just provided *"closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no upvoted or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days"* are automatically deleted.

Comment: What about the answers which gets lot of downvotes but not deleted by user?

Comment: @sgtBOSE what about them? They appear greyed out at the bottom of the list, but they aren't automatically removed as far as I'm aware.

Comment: related: [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/839601) See also: [reopen review triggers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256071/165773) "There are three ways a question can end up in Reopen Review..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicates often should not be deleted, since they serve as a trail of breadcrumbs that people can follow to find the original question. Unless a question is nearly identical to the original (meaning it doesn't offer anything new for search engines to find), then it should be preserved.

Other questions can be deleted after a time if they aren't improved. There is an automated process that deletes old questions that are negatively upvoted and have no answers, since these weren't helpful to anyone. Users with sufficient privileges can cast votes to delete closed questions as well.