# Ping close voters on closed question body edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, closed-questions

When a question is closed for a reason that can be fixed (like `Unclear what you're asking`) [wouldn't it be nice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lD4sxxoJGkA) if the close voters be notified in case of edit of the body of the question?

I mean, I know it'll be [pushed to the reopen queue if it fit a few conditions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue) but maybe the closers are the best to know if the edit fix the answer or not and it would take less time for them to vote for re-open if needed.

Comment: The other question is about downvoted content, which is a larger set than closed questions but the problems are essentially the same.

Comment: Please tag clear-cut feature-requests that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Please **don't**.

There are so many insubstantial edits to crap questions that any valid edit that improves a question to the point of being reopen-worthy would quickly get lost in the noise. Especially now that SE guidelines on suggested edits have been weakened to the point where almost any edit that's not actively harmful will get approved (e.g. capitalization edits to an off-topic piece of crap that should be deleted, gets approved faster than I can cast my single reject vote). Without a sophisticated system classifying edits and filtering out the noise, I'd guess it would be pretty much useless.

There are further problems as well, like your assesment that close voters will be able to tell if a question should be reopened (e.g. it's easy to see if a debugging question is missing example code in any language / system, but harder to tell if example code is sufficient to reproduce the problem).