# One-time notification about questioned close votes

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close, notifications

Lately, I have made an habit out of reacting to clearly inappropriate close votes that I happen to run into around Stack Overflow with a comment to the question that clearly states my disagreement, in the spirit of Shog9's answer to [Directly vote to not close a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298520/2751851). While that seems to be a reasonably effective strategy to prevent further bad close votes, it might be even more effective -- and perhaps even instructive -- if the close voters had the opportunity to read my objections and, should they agree, retract their votes. That being so, I propose **there should be a special-purpose mechanism for notifying close voters that their votes are being questioned**. In what follows, I will specify some constraints that would make such a feature work in a way that is reasonable for everyone involved.

In principle, casting a close vote is at least as engaged a form of participation in a question as leaving a comment, and so if the latter makes one a potential target of notifications it should be no different for the former. However, if anyone was free to send notifications to close voters under any circumstances, there would be legitimate concerns about the volume of notifications thus submitted, specially towards those doing shifts at the review queues (concerns of the sort raised against [Ping close voters on closed question body edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294070/2751851)). I believe such concerns would be adequately dealt with by adding four restrictions to my proposed notification pathway:

- **Notifying close voters should be necessarily accompanied by a comment** (this should discourage drive-by notifications and mindless gut-feeling misuse of the feature).
- **Notifying close voters should only be an option for questions that are still open** (after all, we already have the reopen queue for closed questions).
- **It should only be possible to notify close voters once during the lifetime of the question** (this should largely prevent anyone's inbox from being flooded).
- **The author of the question should not be able to notify close voters** (the system is not meant as a means to defend your question, but as another form of peer review of close votes -- in other words, as an out-of-band complement to the review queues.)

Lastly, I have no strong opinions about the UI of this feature. The obvious solutions appear to be either an extra option in the close vote dialog or some sort of variation on the "@" comment notification syntax, but if these are problematic any more sensible suggestions would be good enough.

Comment: Since we've been able to retract close votes, there are only two reasons for close voters to not check back on the question after a (short) while -- either they think it's not salvageable, which means your suggestion would not work, or they don't care in the slightest, which means your suggestion would not work either.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That seems to assume close voters always monitor all questions they cast a vote on, which does not seem too likely.

Comment: You would be surprised. Anyway, it does revolve into the two cases I mentioned -- if I don't look back, then either someone posted irredeemable crap or I just don't care. I personally belong to the first category, as do quite a few others, but I don't have hard numbers about the not-caring guys. They still do the right thing in the vast majority of cases, though.

Comment: Also keep in mind there has been *an entire chat room* dedicated to close-voting for a while now, and although I'm not a member (I hate chat and I work better as an "independent agent"), I would be very surprised if their *modus operandi* lacked the monitoring required to compensate when they screw up (which happens, them being humans and all).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you're right in your assumption. The questions that are posted in said room are monitored  for changes by a bot. Once a change is detected it leaves a message in the room with links to the original cv-pls and how much has changed and pings the poster. And we have the occasional debate when members disagree about close reason or even close worthiness. So the peer reviewing / challenging of  moderator actions is in place and maintained actively.

Comment: @rene (and Frédéric) This has very little to do with said room (that is, [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)). The mechanism I propose should be available to all questions -- not just those which happen show up in SOCVR -- and all potential challengers -- not just those who happen to patronise SOCVR.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm not suggesting that most voters don't do the right thing. Even well-intentioned people will occasionally commit mistakes (e.g. considering something "irredeemable crap" because they misunderstood a closing reason or read a question too quickly) or forget about a question they voted on. I know I do make mistakes every now and then, and I enjoy being made aware of them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'd say the number of people that go back to check on the questions they voted to close is vanishingly small. Nor would it be expected they would necessarily run into it again in the reopen queue. It's very much a "slam, bam, close you ma'am" affair.

Answer (score -7):

I love your idea, and think it's trying to solve an important problem, and think it should be implemented.

The only caveat is that in all too many cases you are being overly generous in characterizing incorrect close votes as being "occasional mistakes". More often, they are blatant abuses of the close vote system and the close vote reasons, amounting to nothing more than an additional downvote. Unfortunately, you could notify these people of objections to their close votes until the cows come home to no effect.

The worst abuse is with the "opinion-based" reason, and to a lesser extent the "too broad" reason. People incorrectly use "opinion-based" to just mean there are different approaches, which a good answer could delineate and give criteria for adopting.

At the same time, people inexplicably fail to use the "non-reproducible/typo" close vote, instead piling on with answer after answer saying "Works for me", or pointing out some inane typo like a misspelled variable name.

However, I disagree with your constraint of "Notifying close voters should only be an option for questions that are still open". It's precisely after questions are closed that it's most important for people to review their close votes and possibly vote to re-open. Yes, we have the re-open queue, and yes, it has its fair share of traffic, but it's a blunt knife against the hordes of close-voters.

Comment: In my experience, many questionable close votes appear to stem from a too literalistic reading of close reasons, with insufficient regard for context. Typical cases: questions with adequate problem statements attracting "recommendation" close votes merely because they were phrased as "What can I use..." rather than "How should I do..."; "Should I..." questions attracting "opinion-based" votes even if constraints of the relevant technical environment (that the voters are likely unaware of) mean there is an objective answer.

Comment: So essentially, close voters are just a bunch of ignorant people, completely abusing the system all day long and for which absolutely nothing can be done to stop them from going berserk? That's _a little_ far fetched....

Comment: @Tunaki A small minority are.

Comment: This isn't what the answer is saying though. *in all too many cases you are being overly generous in characterizing incorrect close votes as being "occasional mistakes". More often, they are blatant abuses of the close vote system* followed by *it's a blunt knife against the hordes of close-voters*. If that is more often to happen, this isn't talking about a small minority.

Comment: @Tunaki Apologies for my choice of words. Instead of "hordes", I should have said "those few close-voters who abuse the system" or something equivalent.