# Did I miss the reopen interval with my rework?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

Today, I realized (by chance) that an old question of mine was [closed] *`as unclear what you're asking`*. Some time before, I noticed it to be [on hold] but had not the time for working on it. Today I was able to [rework](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28812476/revisions) it, then I clicked on `vote-to-reopen`. Now - after searching for informations on the process that might be triggered by this - I learned on *meta* that [an edit has to be done within the first 5 days after the close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/2932052), I see this *could* be the case (depending on the time zone displayed for closing).

Is the question clear after my rework?

---

BTW: Why didn't I get noticed *when* one of my questions is closed, *if* time is running against me?

Comment: *"I learned on meta that an edit has to be done within the first 5 days after the close"* - do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a link in the question.

Comment: That's about *automatic* reopen queueing, as far as I'm aware there are no limits on the length of time for *manual* voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question does have an reopen vote on it:

[image]

And it is in the review queue so it might get reopened.

[image]

Comment: ...which means that it's functional the same as an edit in time?