# What should be done with an answered closed (seemingly misplaced) question like this?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

I'm talking about [Efficiently normalize strings that represent (combinatorical) necklaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28812476/2932052). This question was not well received at its start, but got three answers, two of them upvoted and helpful (at least for me). The question was (so far)

1. on hold
2. closed
3. reworded
4. voted to reopen
5. [asked about here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297038/2932052)
6. down-voted some times more (since then?)

...but never considered off-topic until now.

Maybe I'm *too blind* to see the actual message in the comments and downvotes. Some of if it seem to suggest a migration, but that seemed not possible to me because it's too late (I read something of a 60-day period), and there are already answers... now I found that I and the up-voted answerers have an account on code review as well. Maybe it's possible to migrate?

What can (should) be done with this question?

Comment: The first version of the question was poor, not that easy to recover from that.   Are the answers you got not sufficient?   Then you'll have to wait until it gets enough re-open votes, you can then put a bounty on it to increase exposure.

Comment: No, the answers helped, maybe I should accept one if them now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, I believe, is the very open ended nature of the question that is at the end of your post

> I'm relatively new to Python, and I've the feeling that there could be
>   a more efficient (and more pythonic) way to do what I want. How would
>   an experienced Python programmer solve this problem?

SO questions are typically about solving a particular problem.  You haven't demonstrated that there is a concrete problem to solve.  The only indication is that you "feel" there is a better way.  Is there a need of a better way? If not, then SO probably isn't the best place for the question.  Codereview or Programmers might be a better fit (not entirely sure, you would have to check yourself).

If there is a need, what is it?  Is it not fast enough?  Does it fail on huge input?  Without a concrete problem with criteria that shows what you need, how will we know when it is solved?  Will we just "feel" like it is done?  And how will we know which answers are better than others with no criteria to measure them by?  Cleanest code?  Fastest?  Most compact?  Looks most like an ASCII unicorn in notepad?  This feels like an opinion based question as every answer could be equally valid and there wouldn't be any objective standard to determine whether something was "better" than what you had.

In your case, it could be "I have this working code, but it isn't performant enough.  I've tried X, Y and Z, and the performance has increased as shown in these benchmark tests, but that's not enough.  What can I do?" (just a very rough example).

Also, not being a Python programmer myself, the term "more pythonic" sounds like a completely subjective standard to measure by and that might also be contributing.  Maybe that means more to Python programmers, but I would be willing to bet that even amongst veteran Python programmers there would be some disagreement on what the "most pythonic" code would be.

Comment: Interesting perspective I never took before.

Comment: After that: do you have a suggestions what I can do to this question?

Comment: @Wolf If you really want a more "soft" answer (ie. cleaner code, more pythonic,stuff like that) see if such a question would fit better on Codereview SE and post there if that is OK.  If the question is more about if there is a better algorithm to use, check out Programmers SE.  If you are set on salvaging the question that is here, maybe reword it to show that you need a faster solution.  Provide benchmarks (and the tools with versions, etc, required to reproduce them).  If by doing benchmarks you realize your solution is good enough, consider deleting the question.  Otherwise post them

Comment: @Wolf and hope for some better answers.  If all of that doesn't seem like it would work and you don't want to delete it, you could see if there is some kind of lock that could be put on the question.  (I'm not sure there are any or how you would go about getting one applied to the question, might be worth looking into tho).

Comment: Thanks again for your kind assistance: your analysis made the problem clear to me. I [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28812476/revisions) aiming not to do harm to the existing answers. If you have the time: would you please have a look whether you would say that the [current version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28812476/2932052) would fit better into the SO format? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @Wolf Using phrases like "good enough for production" still makes it a good target for CodeReview (look at the [topics to ask about for Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).  If I were trying to edit it to be on topic, I would drop the last paragraph entirely and replace it with something like "This works, but it is slow and I need something faster.  What can I do to speed this up?"  That should make it on-topic.  (You may need to provide information on typical inputs of your program and some timing tests to show slowness and still have it be a good question.)

Comment: Thanks so far :-) I'll have a look on this soon.

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned, the question cannot be migrated to CR as it's been more than 60 days (without even considering anything else).

I don't see anything *to* do.  The question doesn't seem appropriate for SO.  You've spent time improving it, but even with all of that I don't see it as a question that should be opened.

There's no reason to delete it, as it has answers that some may consider valuable.

If the answers you got didn't resolve your problem, you can ask the question in an appropriate venue, possibly linking back to this question as a reference.

Comment: But if it seems to attract downvotes, isn't it pointless (at least bad for me) to keep it?

Comment: @Wolf Well, you couldn't delete it even if you wanted to, because it has answers with a positive score.

Comment: Sure, but at least vote-to-delete seems possible. Anyway, let's see what happens...