# Disagreement on duplication action

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

By the powers of Mjölnir, I marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110259/execute-a-bash-command-on-a-list-of-files-on-stdin-and-redirect-the-stdout-to-re) as a duplicate of [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028643/read-list-of-files-on-unix-and-run-command).

The author of the accepted answer on the first one is [apparently taking exception with my decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110259/execute-a-bash-command-on-a-list-of-files-on-stdin-and-redirect-the-stdout-to-re?noredirect=1#comment50273474_10110389).  I can see how one could disagree on a number of things, but in the end, do not see a need to reverse my action (but am also unsure of how to proceed if that wasn't the case).

The questions differ in some details (the first one asks how to create new files with the same base name, so is arguably somewhat more specific) but on the whole, the answers are quite similar; and also, this is a frequent enough question that I would be wholly unsurprised to find a better canonical question to mark them both as duplicates of.

I am turning to the meta community for guidance, in general as well as in this particular case.  Was I too trigger happy?  How should I proceed in the event that a duplicate marking is unwarranted?  I'm still getting used to the powers of Mjölnir ... (The fact that it works for me in [one tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) but not in other related tags certainly adds to my bewilderment.)

Comment: related: [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217406/165773)

Comment: You can also reopen the question in one go, as you've been marking the duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Personally, I would have voted to close the question as "too broad". It lacks a good code example, asks for help with multiple aspects of the problem, and fails to provide enough context to know for sure what the best approach for the OP would be.

As far as the question of duplication goes, I would say that the referenced "duplicate" only addresses part of the OP's question. This is both a reason to hesitate to use it as an actual duplicate, as well as a reason to close the question as "too broad". The proposed duplicate question doesn't address everything in the OP's question, but at the same time that's because the OP's question is asking for a lot.

As far as the disagreement between you and the answerer goes, at least as far as I can at the moment (maybe comments were edited or deleted?), the answerer is simply suggesting an earlier question would have been a more appropriate target as the duplicate. He doesn't seem to be contesting the "duplicate-ness" of the question per se (though IMHO he might have a valid basis for that). I would agree with your general sentiment that one should pick the *best* duplicate, not the *earliest*.

At the end of the day, the thing that matters most with respect to the question of whether the question is actually a duplicate or not is what the OP actually thinks, and how the community judges the question. The OP is free to edit their question, to elaborate and especially to explain in more detail why they believe their question is not answered by the proposed/marked duplicate. They can also lobby for the question to be reopened, and the community can vote to do so.

This is the check that balances your gold-badge ability to close the question in a single swell foop.

Yes, maybe you could have been more conservative here. But if the OP is satisfied with the disposition of the question, I would not spend any more time worrying about it. Use the experience to guide future close votes, but don't do too much second-guessing on this one. You've got a whole community of Stack Overflow users to do your second-guessing for you as the need might arise. :)

Comment: worth noting that in many cases, there is no even need to lobby after edits, because system does it automatically, see [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/839601)

Comment: You are all too trigger happy with your 'too broad' and 'duplicate'. Unless it's exactly the same question, you shouldn't touch it. It's better for the community to have many questions that resembles each other than to close all of them. It's frustrating to the users and often slightly different questions produces better & different answers.

Comment: @Lazik contrary to power users being too trigger-happy, other users are too question-happy and lack researching and question-asking skills. The "Too Broad" and "Duplicate" close reasons are there for a reason. It sure can be frustrating to not be able to find an answer to your question, but that may be caused by asking (yourself, the search engines and the community) the wrong question. Duplicate votes help link differently-worded questions to the same set of answers instead of spreading out the knowledge over many (incomplete) answers.

Comment: @Lazik Your opinion is contrary to the general approach here, particularly with duplicate.  If the answer in another question answers the fundamental question in this question, it should be closed as duplicate - that's the main value of close-as-duplicate.