# Reopening questions that have been marked as duplicates

Tags: support

If my question was marked as a duplicate and I changed it to make it unique, how can I let whoever marked it as a duplicate know so they can check to see if it's viable and reopen it?

Thanks

Comment: Just edit and make your particular points as clear as possible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe:  No, this doesn't seem like a duplicate.  This seems like a misunderstanding of how the system works, to which the dupe doesn't fully satisfy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to inform those who closed your question that your post has been edited, but don't despair;  [your question will make its way through the review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/1079354), and someone that reviews your post can cast reopen votes in that fashion.