# Request to re-open a question with a good answer

Tags: support, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

My question [Shell_NotifyIcon without sound in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434653/shell-notifyicon-without-sound-in-windows-10) was closed (*closed as unclear what you're asking*), but I've got a very good answer.
I edited and updated my question the content. I think it is much clearer now.

It is possible to re-open the question now, because IMO this question and the good answer is helpful for other developer with the same problem?

Comment: I found a lot of reopen request on meta.stackoverflow.com, that's why I thought I have to ask for a reopen it here. Sorry.

Comment: see also: [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if your question should be reopened or not (I'm not expert on those tags), but since you've edited it, your question was automatically added to the [reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).

You don't need to post a question on meta asking us to reopen. Just be patient, if experienced users think it should be reopened, it'll eventually be.

Answer (score 2):

First, just because there is (good) answer to the question that does not mean that question should get reopened. Answer to the question is upvoted, so question will not be automatically removed from site just because it is closed.

Second, in your particular case, while your edit made your question a tad clearer it is still bad question.

1. It shows lack of research - answer is basically copied from documentation
2. It lacks MCVE, it is hard to say what is your problem without knowing what is your code. I would have closed it as

> Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**)
>   must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and
>   *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not
>   useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and
>   Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

3. Because there is no code, it could also be interpreted as too broad, how to - give me the code question.

When you are asking questions, keep in mind that not only people that have stumbled upon your exact issue can answer your question. You can also get good answers from skilled developers that can quickly locate issues in your code even though they have never encountered your exact issue themselves. But in order to do that they need to see your code.