# False duplicate question, hard to see on first glance (title, tags)

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38562945/2932052) about char arrays is a question that seems hard to distinguish from a former one about int arrays. Nevertheless it's not a duplicate. I think the duplicate mark was set prematurely.

I voted for reopening it. Now I changed the tags and title to be more consistent with the contents of the question. Rephrasing the question will not help to distinguish it from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2741784/2932052) as it already shows the difference (if you read both).

Is there anything else I can do to get the force the removal of the duplicate mark?

Comment: you realize that the OP of the question is the one who actually closed it, so it seems that it did solve his problem

Comment: I cannot see that the OP closed the question. Where may I see this?

Comment: The only time "Community" closes as a dup is when the OP acknowledged the dup addresses the problem

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes only now I saw it, but I think Sayeed didn't realize that this step doesn't automatically stop downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP of the question cast the final close vote (you can see this because Community ♦ is mentioned as the close voter), so apparently he doesn't need the question anymore. Anyway, your edit will not put the question in the Reopen votes review queue ([because the OP closed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/4751173)), so there are basically two ways to get the question reopened:

- Invoke the Meta effect (as you just did)
- Post a message in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) - they do reopenings as well, if you provide sufficient arguments

Neither method guarantees success!

Comment: Thanks so far. I did not realise what `Community` means in this context, the hint shows it, but I didn't expect this connection, so I spared hovering. I think it's a misunderstanding by the OP, maybe a panic reaction with the purpose to prevent him from further downvotes... (I think this is a usability issue)

Comment: Yes, we do reopen-pls requests. They should be accompanied with a (good) reason. Post something like `[tag:reopen-pls] wrong dup http://stackoverflow.com/q/38562945` in the room and we will take it from there. Visit our room FAQ for extra guidance: http://socvr.org/