# Question closed for no obvious reason

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This question: [External application remote control from Red language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259483/external-application-remote-control-from-red-language) was closed as "too broad", which looks like an inaccurate characterization. The author asks for a way to automate the GUI of third-party applications from the Red language, giving a clear and detailed description of a simple case on Windows platformn, using the Calculator app.

As the author of the Red language, I have a very valid answer to that question that would be fully satisfying, as I commented on that question. I edited the question title and tags to improve it a bit. My comment was ignored and the question was promptly closed.

I am asking the moderators here to allow reopening of a valid question about how to accomplish a precise action using a programming language (*that's what SO is mostly about, right?*), and allow me (and others) to provide useful and informative answers both to the author and rest of the SO community.

Comment: I still took 5 people to close the question, you can't blame it all on one person you don't like for valid or invalid reasons. The question is basically asking for "sample code"for "learning purposes", if it wasn't closed as too broad the question would go down a different path probably, none ending up well for the author.

Comment: As a sidenote regarding: *"(...) one of the closer (probably initiator) (...)"*: The names of the close voters are shown in the same order as their votes came in.

Comment: I don't know any Red, but it does sound a bit broad. If it involves COM automation, almost anything is too broad, (though it's possible that calc does not have such an interface).

Comment: If it is not too broad it is asking for an off-site resource and/or lacks an attempt. If anything, I don't feel there is much *abuse* here, just plenty of reasons to have it closed.

Comment: *"provide me with some starter/sample/example code"* is **not** an acceptable SO question, whether or not you want to answer it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If that part would be replaced by something more acceptable, would that be enough to salvage that question?

Comment: I strongly recommend keeping this about the content of the question itself. If you have a beef with a particular user it's best to keep that between you and us via moderator flags - going public about that is a bad idea.

Comment: @BoltClock Understood. Let me edit my question accordingly then.

Comment: see also see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: If you really think the question will benefit people, you can always post your own question about it and answer it yourself, then if it's not written too broadly it shouldn't get closed and you can post a link to the new question in the comments.

Comment: @George when advising like that it is typically helpful to refer this canonical guidance: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314272/839601)

Comment: This sounds like exactly the kind of thing that would be great to add to your web site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions that start with *"Is it possible…"* and end with *"…provide me with some starter/sample/example code"* are pretty much guaranteed to get closed.

The only question is, which close reason will be used? There are three good candidates:

1. **Too broad**, on the grounds that a complete answer would be too long for our format, as it would essentially amount to a tutorial for the language/technology. That appears to be accurate in this case; the asker doesn't appear to know anything about Red, so a valid answer could not make any assumptions about their knowledge. That leads to an answer the length of a book.
2. **Off-topic because it asks to recommend a tutorial/book/off-site resource**, for much the same reasons. We either have to write a tutorial here (which is too broad), or we have to refer you to an external tutorial (and we don't do recommendations like that).
3. **Off-topic because it lacks code (*e.g.*, an MCVE) to contextualize the problem**. This is the only closure reason that I could see as potentially invalid here (and it wasn't the one chosen). I include it in this list because it's a popular choice for "do this task for me" questions. Users on Stack Overflow are happy to *help* you implement something in code, but they generally deem code requests to be off-topic. Homework questions often get thrown into this category, but it's not just the fact that they're homework questions—it's that they're low-effort questions with absolutely no context, essentially demanding that others do work for them. Nobody likes being told what to do, especially when they're doing it for free. Showing what you have so far goes a long way towards both providing context and indicating that you're willing to do some of the work yourself.

If you think the question can be salvaged, then don't hesitate to propose an edit, even going so far as to completely rewrite it if necessary. Better to rewrite it and have it reopened than for it to sit around uselessly closed. After being edited, it will automatically be placed in a review queue where other users can assess whether it merits reopening.

(Well, not in this case. [Only the *first* edit after closing is eligible to bump a question into the review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/366904), and [that edit was already made](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45259483/3).)