# How to handle incorrect tag on questions already on hold

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, closed-questions

The past few days I've tred to clean up the [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) list - some people don't read the tag info and put questions for [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) in there.

I ran into a few that are already "on hold" (one of which was my fault).

My question: should I edit the tag, thus putting the questions in the Re-open queue? Or just leave them to clutter the [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) list until they disappear?

Comment: If the re-tag  does bring the question in front of the right audience and you think it has a chance to be answerable I would certainly re-tag, assuming possible other issues with the post are addressed/edited as well. if the post is closed and has no future in ever being open I would leave it, specially if it will be picked-up by the roomba.

Comment: @rene Understood and thanks.

Answer (score 9):

As long as it's a tag-only edit, there's no problem in you editing it, since only body edits put the question in the reopen queue according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/4284627) (emphasis mine):

> Currently, this means that a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue when it is...
>
> - ...Edited **(body edits only)** within 5 days of closure by the author. Or,
> - ...Edited **(body edits only)** within 5 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to close it. Or,
> - ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month. We're still tweaking the exact thresholds for these.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this - it's a bit old, but I assume still accurate. OTOH @rene 's considerations are true - not a one of them is salvageable. The only reason IMO for going to the time and trouble would - possibly - be that others wouldn't think this kind of thing is on-topic. But when posting questions newbies who mis-tag aren't going to see the list. Or does anyone reading this think that such "clutter"  is a problem?