# Advice on raising a flag to re-open a question

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions

I recently came across a question, which was closed as too broad years ago. 
However, I found it quite interesting and given that much progress on the topic
has been made since it was asked, I would like to write a response.

I really feel I can answer the OP's question with very specific examples but the
question admittedly is a bit broad. However, I feel it can be improved 
considerably with some editing.

Is it appropriate in this case to flag the question for moderation intervention
in order to ask moderators to re-open it?

Note that at the time I am writing this here I have not yet crossed the 3000
reputation threshold in order to cast a vote to re-open the question.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question about flagging it, but if you are going to suggest it be re-opened, do the edits to the question first. While it's too broad, it won't be re-opened, so if you can edit it to make it not-too-broad, that's surely the first step into getting it re-opened.

Comment: Just ask the question yourself, ensuring it is now *not* too broad.

Comment: [The help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) explains how to get a question reopened (although I can't say I quite follow the reasoning behind only flagging it if a mod closed it, since mod closure isn't usually all that different from non-mod closure). Also, don't make an edit that would invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Link to the question in question?

Comment: @Dukeling: I first thought it might be left over from a time when mod closures could only be undone by a mod, but if that ever was a thing, it must've been a long time ago. Maybe I was mixing it up with deletion. Also, I'd say that invalidating existing answers is OK *if* those answers are clearly off-topic themselves. For example, an existing answer recommending a bunch of off-site resources (and nothing else) isn't a reason not to edit out a recommendation request.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions. I have now incorporated these into a 'formal' answer.

Comment: When you edit a closed question it will be placed in the reopen queue anyway. No need to flag for moderators in this case.

Comment: @BDL A closed question is only placed in the reopen queue upon the first edit by a user who neither voted for the question to be closed nor flagged the question. Subsequent edits do not place it in the reopen queue. See [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572) and [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since no answer has been offered yet, I will try to consolidate the suggestions
provided in the comments and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) in what I hope it will be a helpful post to future readers.

The suggestions, so far, can be summed up as follows:

- Ask a new question, this time properly written to ensure that it is not too broad.
- Edit the current question sufficiently, until it meets the required standard *before* flagging it for moderation intervention.
- Leave a comment on the current question itself explaining why this should be
  reopened.
- Ask in the meta site people with at least 3000 reputation points, to 
  vote to reopen the current question if they feel this is an appropriate action to take.

I will keep updating this post as new comments come in but others should feel free to provide their own comprehensive answers if they wish.

Comment: I'm not so sure flagging it for moderation intervention should be used unless it's locked. From the help center, "If a moderator (user with a ♦ symbol after their name) closed the question, then you may flag it for moderator attention".