# Stop automatically sending edited questions to the reopen queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, edits

I understand that when a question is edited, it is (according to some rules) automatically sent to the reopen queue.

I suggest replacing this with doing it manually. Have some button that says "send to reopen queue" or something like that. The reason is that very often questions gets closed for various reasons, and then the user gets advice on how to correct it. More often than not it takes a couple of edits before it's in an ok state. Both because they misunderstand the advice, or don't do it well enough, but also because they often do it incrementally instead of whole edits. So in most of the cases, it's fairly pointless to send it to review after the first edit.

And in a lot of other cases, other users make minor edits to older posts, like indenting code, correcting spelling errors, and such. Also here, it's quite rare that they make enough changes for a reopening. So it's pointless that it gets sent to the queue.

Furthermore, I think this is something that anybody who has the edit privilege should be able to do. Or maybe it should be an ability at a higher privilege level. I also might consider that it could be an idea to allow users to do this multiple times. But I'm not sure about those details, so please look at the bigger picture of this suggestion. Possibly it could require the reopen privilege for everybody except OP.

This should only be possible for an editor after the edit.

And this should be something that's separate from reopen votes. If you want to send it to the reopen queue without an edit, you have to use your reopen vote.

I read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256572/6699433) and it says that questions enter the queue because of edits in three cases:

- When the author edits it within 70 days of closure
- When another editor edits it within 70 days of closure, provided that the editor has not flagged or close voted the question
- When the question is sufficiently popular according to some magic numbers.

Only the first two are relevant here, and note that questions only enter the queue once per closure because of edits.

This leads to questions entering the queue when they are far from ready, as explained above. So I think that it would be a good idea to allow the users to make edits while explicitly saying that it's not ready, by not pushing the button.

This leads to a very bad scenario. Consider a user asks a question that gets closed. The user makes an edit, it ends up in the review queue, and it doesn't get reopened. Now it does not matter which edits OP is making, and has to wait for a kind person that votes to reopen. And in a vast majority of these cases **they don't even know how this works**. Many of them are beginners that do not even know that this queue exists. Others have heard that it enters that queue on edits, so they trust that this will happen when they edit. I belonged to the latter category until recently.

When you click the button, you could have a confirm box like this:

> Are you sure you want to submit this question to the reopen queue? Don't do it unless ALL issues have been rectified.

Also, for obvious reasons, it's **imperative** that the UI is **very** clear that pressing that button is required for reopening.

If tuned correctly, I think we could both increase the amount of questions that get sent to the queue that really get reopened, and fewer questions that don't.

TBH, I have stopped caring about the reopen queue, because there are **tons** of questions with edits that obviously do not make it ready for reopening.

As an additional thing, currently you can very easily see which questions you have accepted an answer for. You could also do something similar to this, so that you can easily see if a question is in the review queue or not. In the past, you got reminders to accept answers if you had not done so. You could have some reminder like that, that gets sent out after a day or something, for instance

> Your question was closed because . You have edited it after that, but you have not sent it to the reopen queue. The question will not be reopened unless it enters the queue. Remember that you should only send it to the queue if you have fixed the question enough to comply with the requirements.
>
> Do you want to send the question for reopening review? (Y/N)

EDIT:

I'd like to add a comment from zcoop98

> Re: "And in a vast majority of these cases they don't even know how this works" - Ideas surrounding this topic have been proposed before, and normally one of the arguments made to the contrary is that OP's would just always send their edits to the reopen queue. But... **that's exactly what happens now, with the major exception that many OP's inevitably don't realize it's even happening.** This lack of instruction leaves room for significant improvement over the current system, IMO. –

Comment: Related: [Now that the Edit Question button for closed questions is more prominent, it's time to stop non-OP edits from submitting to the reopen queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398340/4642212), [Upcoming Feature: New Question Close Experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394871/4642212).

Comment: closed question **must** be checked, if a user changes and hopefully corrects his mistakes, sometimes the edit is not enough, but it must be checked **anyway**

Comment: @nbk I don't think they need it. The only thing needed is that the user basically cannot miss that his is required for entering the queue.

Comment: @klutt we close many dupe, and other not correct questions, but when you read the text, there is clear stated, that the user can edit and make his question better. So what use should it have, when nobody check it out and reopens it.

Comment: @nbk Yep, it's no use then. But let's face it. Users who would not understand how to use such a feature are typically the users who writes bad questions and makes bad edits. If you don't want your edit to be useless, use the feature I suggested. Simple.

Comment: your feature is only necessary if someone fiexed typos or formatting, with really changing anything, but the user who should have edited the question it is vital to get his changed question, evaluated. it is a learning process, so he should get more changes to rewirte

Comment: @yivi That proposal is for edits to cause the post to go to the queue *only* if the OP edits it. This proposal is for anyone to be able to send it to the queue, but only by manually opting to do so. Seems like a different proposal to me.

Comment: This is a duplicate. It should have been posted as an Answer to [Now that the Edit Question button for closed questions is more prominent, it's time to stop non-OP edits from submitting to the reopen queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398340/12695027)

Comment: I suggested something similar over at MSE when they announced the review queues overhaul: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347101/571958

Comment: `And in a lot of other cases, other users make minor edits to older posts, like indenting code, correcting spelling errors, and such.` Any **cosmetic** edits on old posts which are already closed should be thoroughly discouraged, I suggest flagging the editor's behaviour  if they continually bump old posts because their pet hate are comma splices.

Comment: Re: "*And in a vast majority of these cases they don't even know how this works*" - Ideas surrounding this topic have been proposed before, and normally one of the arguments made to the contrary is that OP's would just *always* send their edits to the reopen queue. But... that's *exactly* what happens now, with the major exception that many OP's inevitably don't realize it's even happening. This lack of instruction leaves room for significant improvement over the current system, IMO.

Comment: @Mari-LouA To that, I'll say that users with < 2k rep should not be able to edit closed questions. If people want to spend time fixing those, it's their choice, but it shouldn't waste time in the edit review queue.

Comment: this recent announcement at MSE looks related: [Changing the question reopening experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367231/165773)

Comment: Yes, I think this one should be [tag:status-complete] at this point.

Answer (score 40):

I like this idea, but with a small change.

The purpose of sending questions to the reopen queue is to ensure those questions get a fair shake at being seen and answered a second time around. As you said, a lot of these edits are not worth sending because they are cosmetic edits (example, fixing typos, formatting code, editing tags) and therefore are not likely to change the status of judgement for that question’s closure upon further review. But we should still allow users to make these edits, rather than discouraging them from submitting just because it wasn't worth sending the question to the queue for.

After reviewing feedback from folks in the comments, I would suggest **showing a second button under the question while editing if it was previously closed**:

[image]

The button says “Save edits and vote to reopen”. Thus the original “Save edits” button will no longer push the question into the reopen queue.

The assumption here is if a user thought their edits were worth reopening the question for, they would vote to reopen themselves. This not only pushes the question into the reopen queue, but now one person has already “reviewed” it, so the question gets processed that much faster. Win-win?

If misuse is a concern, we could opt to show this button only when OP edits their own question, and have edits from everyone else not affect the queue at all.

PS: If a user has already exhausted their votes when clicking the second button, it still goes to the queue

WDYT?

Comment: I don't think it's better with more false positives. Very often when this is discussed, people seem to think about it like it was a real trial when someone can be sentenced to a long prison punishment. I think it's reasonable to give this responsibility to OP and other editors. However, only having a checkbox could be a good thing, but the default should be NOT sending to the queue.

Comment: @klutt I think the difference between the default option to be sending to the queue versus NOT sending it is that the latter is more harmful to the question, especially if the editor is not educated as to the consequences of checking that radio button before submitting their edit. If you insist on this option there should be some clear method to encourage/educate users in the use of this checkbox when required.

Comment: I'm one of those who believes in giving people responsibility along with the help. But yes, more guides on how to do it would be good. 

But think of it. Edits only triggers the queue ONCE per closure. Why? Probably because the queue would be filled beyond belief without that, and OP had NO way of fixing it.

Comment: I dislike obscuring what the effect of that checkbox is. If the only point of the checkbox is to avoid automatic review, it should just say so. For example I most certainly would not consider fixing code to be cosmetic, but it is often not enough to salvage an otherwise incomplete MCVE.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi how about this: perhaps if the question is closed, there can be another button next to "Save edits" that says "Save edits and vote to reopen". If the user clicks the latter button, they automatically vote to reopen and send the question to the queue. I'm assuming if a user thinks the question is worth reopening, they would vote to do so themselves.

Comment: I like this solution because it drives the process, it is immediately obvious to both OP or the editor that there is an option for this edit to vote to re-open and that I should consider if it is worth it. It also firmly describes the fact that re-opening is a democratic, it is not automatic. It also allows me to save my edit, either so I can resume somewhere else or because I have contributed, but I know its not enough to re-open.

Comment: Related, from a *long* time ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183233/215468

Comment: I actually think the check-box is better than another button. What makes you think everyone will not just *Save edits and vote to reopen*? True, the same can happen with a checkbox, but I believe it reduces the misuse

Comment: Perhaps as others said you can make the button available to just OP, and prevent edits from anyone else from sending the question to the queue. That buys into the idea that only the OP can save their shinking ship. The majority of non-OP edits are formatting or tag arrangements anyway, so I'm not against that idea. @Tomerikoo

Comment: @cs95 Now with that I agree ;)

Comment: I dislike this because in reality, the asker probably doesn't understand what a reopen is or why they would vote for one. Implicit is better than explicit.

Comment: How about making this button one chance and OP only? When clicked a confirmation appears: "You have just one chance for your edit to be reviewed and as result the question reopened. Please make it count: do it only if you are absolutely sure the close reason is not apply anymore and all requests in comments are fullfilled.".

Comment: I like this idea, but what if instead of "Save edits and vote to reopen", the button matched the privilege level of the user. <250, always "Save edits and flag to reopen" which creates a review task, >= 250 "Save edits and vote to reopen" on their own posts, >= 3000 always "Save edits and vote to reopen"? This could be the default and the other button could say "Save edits only".

Comment: Question: is it misleading to show such a button to an OP who has edit privileges but not reopen privileges? Does their vote still count? Should the text be different in that case?

Comment: Here's my mock-up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zO4u.png

Comment: Would this new button be displayed to the author?  If it is then it doesn’t really change the current workflow.  Authors already make edits that do everything except address the reason their question was closed.

Answer (score 11):

You kinda nailed the root problem here midway through your post:

> And in a vast majority of these cases they don't even know how this works.

Save for an embarrassingly small group of exceptions, *nobody* knows how this works. Not really. [I mean, it's really terribly complicated](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/why-was-this-reopen-review-item-invalidated/3351#3351)...

At the start of all of this, it was pretty easy to explain. One might say something like...

> if your post is closed, someone with close vote privileges can reopen it. Do what you can to make them want to. If you earn 250 reputation, you can reopen it yourself.

That's small enough to fit in a comment. Imagine trying to explain the entirety of the reopen process to someone in comments now, without delving into "lies for children".

Those halcyon days ended with the close of 2008 and the introduction of the voting system. Now it took 3 people to reopen, which meant at least 3 people with close-privileges had to *see* the question. An awful lot of questions were barely getting enough visibility to be closed in the first place; there was effectively NO chance that they would ever be reopened.

**Enter: review.** This was the complexity meant to fix the problems caused by the previous increase in complexity. The only problem was, how were questions supposed to be eligible for review?

The most obvious solution was... The one you proposed here: some sort of button that folks could press to throw the question into the queue. Only problem is, folks were already pressing a button like that: the "flag for moderator attention" button. And, uh, the results were not... Great.

You're assuming that folks are inadvertently sending questions into the queue. That probably does happen, but... I kinda suspect it happens a lot less than you'd hope. My reason for thinking this is simple: everything we've ever done around here to try to make it more obvious how to put questions up for reopening has resulted in more questions being thrown into the queue. Folks who know their questions are half-baked tend to not post them at all; they don't post them, let them get closed, and then wish for the opportunity to do some serious editing.

Indeed... The big problem to solve here hasn't changed since SO was launched, no matter how much complexity has been shoveled on top of it: **asking good questions is hard and most folks don't know how to do it.**

Personally, I would like to see most of this complexity stripped away; it has done very little to solve the root problems and has become a massive distraction and source of fatigue. While folks are worrying about communicating the mechanics of review, they're *not* working on communicating the essential details of what makes for a good question. While folks are reviewing, they're not editing. **And while folks are stressing over how to get their questions reopened, they're not thinking about how to get their questions into an answerable state.** The complexity is counterproductive. The utility of closing and reopening are inversely proportional to how much thought has to be put into the process vs the needs of the questions themselves.

And until most of that is stripped away, no little UI tweaks are likely to make an appreciable difference.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the basis of the question: queuing questions for reopening after an edit creates problems.

My own issue of concern is about what to do with suggested edits, made by low-rep users and entered in the "Suggested Edits" queue,  for changes that improve the communication of a post but **do not improve its technical merit**:  edits for readability, spelling, grammar, punctuation, code indentation improvements as well as fixing code snippet preparation or markdown corrections for example.

When these edits suggest genuine improvements they seem to readily gain three approvals, *even for closed questions*. I have even seen a suggested but cosmetic edit for an open question approved after it became closed.

Assuming that three review approvals of a suggested edit do in fact put a question into the re-open queue, I would like to see a button in the review queue for an "Accept & leave closed" option.

Answer (score 3):

To rehash [a previous answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395911/5211833):

Why not fix the ways posts get into the reopen queue, by e.g. not allowing edits by others than the OP into pushing it there? If only cosmetic edits could've made a post on-topic, it shouldn't have been closed to begin with. It's not like the reopen queue is ever overflowing.

Another thought on this would be to let every *N*-th edit by OP, or every *K*-days when edited, a maximum of *M*-times etc, push the question into the queue. Care would need to be taken of course to prevent abuse.

As to your thoughts on adding a button: I doubt it'd work, except as a red flag on a bull. Of course you want your question to be reopened if it has been closed, because you asked a perfect question in the first place! Giving the OP access to that button would be pretty much as pointless as pushing it into the reopen queue on the first edit.

Comment: I'm not happy with "cosmetic issues should not be enough to close it". Some cosmetic issues are not enough, but if a user, new or old, posts something completely broken, mispelled, without taking the time to format it and make it easier for others to help, then there is enough ground for closure. If you want to get good, articulate answers, design a good articulate question!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion, but I think it can be easily simplified so beginners understand what the UI is talking about.

Note that you can edit any question - you can also edit questions that are not closed. Also, you can edit for any reason - not only for reopening.

So, make the UI do the following:

```
If (OP editing own question) and (the question is closed) and (it's first time we do this), then:
    Display a message near the place where it says "Edit Summary":
        Vote to reopen this question (checkbox: ☐/☑)
```

Possibly add an explanation in fine print, which mentions that "this if your only chance to reopen your question".

Also, if OP has reopen privileges, it should make OP vote for reopening (so only 2 other votes for reopening are required). Such "advanced" users should realize that doing a minor edit is not worth spending your reopen vote, so they won't check the "vote" check-box.

Also maybe it makes sense that non-OP can also send a question to the reopen queue (or vote to reopen) using this feature.

Comment: I don't think you should need to use reopen votes. However, you should be able to speed up the process by doing so.

Comment: That is, users should have two options - "send to reopen queue" and "send to reopen queue but also speed up the process by voting"? I don't get it.

Comment: No, you should only have the "send to reopen queue", and it has nothing to do with reopen voting. But if you have the reopen privilege, then you can also cast a vote separately. But that's a completely separate thing. One thing I really hate here is when privileges REMOVES things I could do in the past. For instance, I really wish the dup hammer was optional.

Answer (score -1):

Oh my gosh. Not that there isn't a fair amount of useful info in this discussion, and yes there need to be some controls on a site like this, but... after reading through all this, isn't it at least possible that all y'all are making this stuff wayyyyyy too complicated? For pete's sake!

Comment: Yes. But to be fair, it's already too complicated. Far, far more complicated than most folks realize. It was already too complicated 12 years ago...

Answer (score -12):

Your suggestion to give users the power to flag for reopening is fatally flawed because we cannot rely on them to be honest enough to use that power responsibly. As the author of a question, your number one priority is getting that question answered, so of course you're *always* going to click the "reopen plz" button. And since users don't read, for non-author editors the only net effect will be to put another click between them and submitting the edit.

I believe that the underlying issue is allowing non-authors to edit closed questions, because how is it possible for anyone but the person who wrote that question, to panel-beat it into an answerable state? If it's so poor that it was closed, **anyone else editing it is doing little more than guessing at the intent<sup>1</sup>**, which at worst ends up transforming the question into something the author did not intend (yes I have seen this happen, no the author was not happy). Imposing your will on someone else's question in a misguided attempt to help them, when the only person who can help them is themselves, **is not helpful**.

Prevent anyone but the author (and obviously moderators) from editing closed questions, and the reopen queue problem goes away entirely.

---

<sup>1: This is a fact, please stop trying to argue it with me. You might be able to make a *better* guess at the meaning than others, **but it is and always will be only a guess**. Compilers don't deal in guesses, neither should the users of this site.</sup>

Comment: That's just silly. We're continuously told that if we see a post as being clear while others are confused, we should just edit it to reflect that clarity. If the post author disagrees they can roll it back. With this you're basically requiring that everyone writes perfect English.

Comment: I fully agree that I want to upvote twice, but regarding your last paragraph. Instead of *allowing* only OP to edit, only *send it to the reopen queue* for OP's edits. This way, non-authors can still make grammar edits but they will simply not make the question enter the queue...

Comment: @Scratte Did you ignore the second sentence of my second paragraph?

Comment: Just because three people agreed that a question is incomprehensible, we should not assume that there can’t be a user out of the millions who still understood it and will fix it. Regarding the OP’s editing abilities, yes they *might* always click on “send to queue”, but why is that a reason to force sending every edit to the queue?

Comment: Sorry, but “This is a fact, please stop trying to argue it with me.” can’t get anything else but a “-1” as response. It’s unacceptable, regardless of the topic. Further there is a reason why there’s a “Vote to Reopen” option *even without editing a post*. Just because three people managed to close a post, it’s not a proof that the post truly is incomprehensible. But I’m fine with the idea that an edit by other people does not trigger a review, as long as I can still click on the “Vote to Reopen” after the edit. Just don’t post opinions as facts.

Comment: @IanKemp No. I didn't ignore that. I've seen post being closed for nitpicks as well as just disagreement about a post being clear or not. You're saying that other users cannot edit a post into a reopen-able state. That is not true. Some of those posts were, upon an edit (from someone else), later reopened. Of course it takes a user's willingness to do it. And if you really believe that it takes mind reading to see clarity, can you explain how apparently moderators can do that?

Comment: @Scratte If a question is being closed for a nitpick, that in my mind is an abuse of the close system by certain users, not a problem inherent with the question itself. As for mods, I expect them to be editing to remove vandalism or similar, not as an ordinary part of their workflow, because they're implicitly as unable to discern someone else's intent as any of us.

Comment: Now we're back to which posts are OK and which are not. One calls it clearly unclear, someone else calls it a silly nitpick. But you want to ensure that they're all clearly unclear if a close voter says so. Since it's closed, it can't be fixed by the "it's just a silly nitpick"-say'er. It will be empowering the closing of a post to a point that is not constructive.

Comment: I must say you have some good points here

Comment: First paragraph +1, second paragraph -2.

Comment: +1 for compilers don't guess. -1 for the same argument: compilers _care a lot_ about spelling, format, formatting and being precise. Formatting matters.

Comment: Your subnote #1 incorrectly assumes both that the closure was valid in all cases, and that the only valid edit to reopen a question hinges on changing the intent of the question. There are also hundreds of examples of users editing other user's questions into a position which gets them reopened.