# Don't cause the reopen vote of the user, whose edit pushed the closed question into the reopen queue, to invalidate the review

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, edits, vote-to-reopen

The current behavior is like this:

1. A question gets closed
2. A user edits the question pushing it into the reopen queue
3. That *same* user later votes to reopen it
4. The reopen review is *invalidated*

This also affects the author of the question (while a user needs [3000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to vote to close/reopen someone else's question, they only need [250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) to vote to close/reopen their own question). This can diminish an OP's chance to get their question reopened.

The behavior is based on edits and flags, since votes to close/reopen are internally also just flags. In many cases this mechanism is useful and prevents abuse.

In case of edits and votes to reopen the potential abuse would be to push a question into the reopen review queue twice, once by editing, once by voting to reopen. It's all not as easy as it sounds, though. [Shog9's answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3351) to (3) describes what you'd have to do to abuse it:

> So the question'd have to be closed immediately, then you'd have to cast your reopen vote pretty quickly thereafter, the question would have to go through review promptly, get no more reopen votes for four days, and then you'd have a bit less than a day to make your edit and hope the review went your way... 'cause on day 5, the task would once again become invalid.

I suggest to change the behavior. It depends on what is easier to implement but possibilities are

- ignoring reopen votes and allowing the loophole (preferred by Shog9 ("In spite of this obscure loophole, I kinda prefer this option: it's dead-simple."))
- introducing checks for the actual case to be prevented

---

Sources:

(1) [When is a review task “completed” or “invalidated”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164288)

(2) [Why is the Reopen queue invalidating tasks when a reopen vote (to reopen) comes in after an edit (by the reopen voter)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295062)

(3) [Why was this Reopen review item invalidated?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3348)

Comment: It is best the system doesn't have surprises. This behavior surprised me and it is infuriating for a user if they do all the things our guidance tells them to do and then the end result is hindering getting good answers on an improved question.

Comment: I'd say Shog9's option seems to be the best one - one needs to be pretty damn inventive (and motivated) to land in the window of opportunity for the loophole to take effect for little gain (certainly not worth the trouble). Plus, an intentional abuse can be spotted and reported (if that can even be called "abuse").

Comment: @OlegValter I think it's possible to send a post to the reopen queue multiple times, no? Just wait for the reopen vote to expire and cast a new one. I've seen it mentioned that this can be done by the same user over and over, so I'm not sure how exactly this current "feature" would be preventing "abuse" by closing any so-called loopholes.

Comment: @Scratte - I am not sure I follow what you mean here? Isn't the problem with the current behaviour invalidating the reopen review task, not with sending posts to the queue multiple times? I meant that the hypothetical loophole does not seem harmful, so the behavior seems safe to reevaluate.

Comment: @OlegValter I meant that the loophole that the current functionality seeks to prevent, isn't prevented. A user can still send a post to the queue multiple times. Hence, there's no reason for it to work the way is currently does. It just brings frustration with its surprising behaviour.

Comment: @Scratte - so, we do not disagree then? I was talking about the potential loophole only in a sense that even if it matters, its effort/reward ratio is so low, that it should not be a concern if we are to improve the flow for well-intentioned users.

Comment: @OlegValter We are in agreement :) I just wanted to add that the loophole isn't even closed, because when I read the post by Shog9, I spend quite some time trying to figure out how exactly it was closing this loophole, hence the justification for even having this frustrating functionality.

Comment: so as it is already in the reopen queue why did the user vote to reopen it. with 3k rep, you should know it better, and the question should be automated deleted.

Comment: @nbk Why should it be deleted? If it's edited to be a fine Question. If it's your Question that you edit to get reopened, why would you not want to vote to reopen it? Note also that it's impossible to know if a post is in the queue until it's already left the queue. There's no entry in the timeline while it's in the queue.

Comment: with 3 k reputation, you sholuld ahve leant how the site works. if you donä#t know it , you know where to find that onformation, so this action must be punished as 500 downvotes are not implemented a deletion seems right to me

Comment: @nbk Users can vote to reopen their own post at [250 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) (is this a case where you didn't know how the site works? :-). I'm also not sure that punishing a user by deleting their now fine post just because of what they didn't previously know, but have since learned, is a constructive way of moderating users. You can step it up to deleting entire accounts at 10K if they make a mistake.. that'll teach them! :P At least that way we'll have new blood here at all times ;)

Comment: if it was a new user it can happen that you really don't know about and never read here in meta about what to do when you post is closed, but we are talking about someone with 3000 points, so he is around for a while, so he could have know should have knwn must know how it works. else you pay the price. it is a bug without question, but still 3000 points without knowing is bad

Comment: @nbk I disagree. I did not know that voting to reopen a post would kick it out of the queue. I'm sure this came as a surprise to a lot of users. I fail to see not knowing that is so horribly bad. We're not all knowing about every little quirky detail of the underlying business logic that is working on the bits of 0's and 1's that make up the site. That would be a full time job with a working brain of perfect memory. I'm sure not even developers know it all. I know that a lot of users don't know that editing a closed post puts it into the reopen queue. Even fewer know that is only happens once.

Comment: The 5 day timeframe for edits pushing questions into the reopen queue mentioned in the quote included in this post is no longer accurate. That timeframe has been extended to 70 days as of probably more than a year ago. It was progressively increased to that value over time. Please see [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/271271) for a description of the criteria for which edits put questions into the reopen queue. IMO, the difference between 5 and 70 days for body edits pushing into the reopen queue doesn't materially affect the arguments for this change.

Comment: @Makyen - missed that one, thank you! So, the only real difference is in how long the window of opportunity stays open and that's pretty much it?

Comment: I may miss something here, but isn't the first surprise in that flow at step 2? I never understood why an edit (moreover by a third party user) would trigger an hidden and unrelated task to push the question into the review queue. If I want to have a question reopened, I click the button labelled "reopen", I don't enter a konami code hoping for something.

Comment: @Kaiido It seems that [Should questions be added to the reopen queue as soon as they're edited by the original author?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157584) caused the implementation of that feature ("He also mentioned that questions almost never get reopened once they're closed. Should more questions be added earlier to this queue. I think that after a question is closed, if the original author makes a substantial edit to the question, it should be eligible for reopening."). That edits by non-OPs should cause this is [debated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398340/11682469).

Comment: @JeanneDark still I don't understand why the edit is the trigger for this action. Why don't we just present the "reopen" button to OP, maybe even locking it until such an edit occurs, I don't mind. From my point of view, having a clear "reopen" button being the only way to trigger this action would solve all the hacks required now to avoid the weird timings thing Shog talked about, since OP has the power to push their question to the queue when they want, no need to *let them polish their multi-edits* and the impromptu double vote thing at hand here would also be solved.

Comment: We are going to investigate and see how this fits in to our current roadmap work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm happy to report that as part of our [future changes to the question reopening experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367231/718314), this bug will no longer occur.  The older logic was complex and buggy, and we've replaced it with something simpler that guarantees the edit will enter and stay in the review queue even if the user has voted to reopen the post.

I've also created an automated test that reproduces the problem exactly. The test fails in the old reopen queue workflow, but passes in the new reopen queue workflow. I can confirm that Shog's steps to reproduce were correct (thank you!). The flow of the automated test is:

- A test post is closed
- A test user then edits that post in a way that would put it into the reopen queue

  - In the old workflow, this happens with an edit to the body within 70 days of the post's closure during the next queue sync
  - In the new workflow, this happens with an edit that is significant right after editing
- The reopen queue is synced
- Later, the same test user adds a flag for reopening the post
- The reopen queue is synced
- Both the reopen review task and the reopen vote should still exist and should not have been invalidated

This automated test helps us show that the problem no longer exists while also helping us prevent this problem from appearing again in the future.

I'm going to mark this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but please note that this bug will still occur until the [review workflow changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363552/718314) have released, approximately in the next couple of weeks.

Comment: So, what will be the new logic? If it has a substantial edit or a vote to reopen and the review task is not older than 4 days?

Comment: @Braiam That *sounds* correct, but I'll defer to the future release post that will have all of the details when we launch.

Answer (score 12):

> The current behavior is like this:

Not *quite*...

Sorry to be pedantic here, but I just had to correct an edit to [an old answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078), and I suspect there's some misinformation floating around.

(Ok, I still occasionally read the SOCVR ([Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)), so I *know* there's some misinformation floating around)

This bug is somewhat more complicated than just "if you vote and edit it invalidates the review". I went into detail on this in [the answer you linked](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/why-was-this-reopen-review-item-invalidated/3351#3351), but to summarize:

- The edit has to be what actually put the question into review.
- The reopen vote has to come *after* the edit has already put the question into review - this means after the edit is submitted *and* after the queue is next synchronized (this may have changed and probably will change in the future; used to be every 5 minutes or thereabouts).
- There cannot be any other reopen votes older than 15 minutes *when the queue is synced* - that's what makes the *vote* ineligible, while the vote also makes the edit ineligible.

In other words, it's a bit harder to hit this bug than it sounds. Not that that makes it any less crappy; to avoid it with certainty, you either have to already know it exists before you edit, or you have to possess information about the state of review that is not easily possible for you to possess. **That is entirely unreasonable!**

Back when I first encountered this, I checked for other occurrences; it was very rare. It might be more common *now* though, especially on Stack Overflow: [changes to closing at the tail end of 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff) resulted in a significant increase in reopen vote effectiveness *and in voting* - if that result held over time (I have no way of knowing), then it stands to reason more folks would hit bugs related to reopen votes. In other words: even though this requires a fairly specific set of circumstances, those circumstances might exist more often now than they once did.

**I would strongly encourage the team to actually investigate this** (or just exclude reopen votes from invalidating the task *and* the 15 minute waiting period - both are based on assumptions made almost 9 years ago now, are very unlikely to be needed anymore, and make the query unnecessarily complicated).

But for the rest of us, it's not worth worrying about too much; if you want to be extra-sure to avoid it, just get in the habit of voting immediately *before* submitting an edit. And note that edits made *from* the reopen queue are recorded at the same time as the associated vote, and thus are also immune from this bug (even if something else were to remove the initial trigger that enqueued the post).

Comment: I would assume this mostly hits users that are fairly new to the site. They've edited their post and is waiting to get it reopened. After some time they try to figure out what more they can do and ..hits this :( I believe they'd be unlikely to go and search meta before voting to reopen their own post.

Comment: Could be; no way to know. It's a shitty bug; it punishes the folks who put in the most effort. 

Comment: Another curious thing is that the first post I noticed this on had gotten a second reopen-vote, by another user that never edited the post, an hour after the post was kicked out of the queue. That reopen-vote didn't cause the post to re-enter the queue.

Comment: Yeah, that's because only the first (active) vote will put a question into queue, and the original vote was still active. Happens a lot with close votes too; never figured out a good solution to that that didn't greatly increase complexity.

Comment: And here I was thinking SOCVR was the single source of truth ... thanks for still watching our back.

Comment: "There cannot be any other reopen votes older than 15 minutes when the queue is synced" that was also my understanding, which was why I got embroiled in a big argument when I said "I don't care" when I edit vs vote to close.

Comment: Here's the thing, @Braiam: this sorta stuff barely matters for very active folks like yourself (and probably most of SOCVR) - it's unlikely you'll hit it, a drop in the bucket if you do, and you know where/how to get help if it does occur. But... It's yet another barrier for folks who are trying to learn the basics of the system, yet another obscure and non-intuitive pitfall, one of 1k little cuts that add up to block their hope of success.