# Why was my suggested edit that added a tag to a question rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29393374) to a question about the NEAR protocol that was later closed because of missing details or clarity. My edit added the [blockchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blockchain) tag. The question is about a blockchain, so the blockchain tag seems to be correct here. However, the suggestion was rejected by two reviewers on the basis of the edit not improving the quality of the post (one rejection before, one rejection after closure).

Was my suggested edit rightly rejected? Why? What could I have done better?

Comment: There's a phrase (in American English at least) -- "polishing a turd". It refers to the act of trying to make something bad look better, when really that bad something should be flushed down the toilet. That's the case here. That question was not going to suddenly become answerable because the [blockchain] tag was added -- it needed information from the OP, so there's really no use in wasting reviewers' time with an edit that didn't fix the underlying issues.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question is low quality and lacks a lot of details. Your edit didn't solve this problem. Please do not edit posts unless you can fix **all** major problems.

Also note, that in general edits on closed questions push the post into the reopen review (which only happens for the first edit after closure), effectively preventing the original author from fixing their question and get it reopened.

Comment: The edit would not have pushed it into the review queue

Comment: @Dharman: Why not?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue

Comment: @BDL Thanks for the explanation! The first rejection happened before the question was closed (I added this detail in my question now too), but the first part of your answer still applies for that case. Just for clarification: Adding the blockchain tag (or any other fitting tag) to a question without major problems would be fine, correct?

Comment: @sk_pleasant: Yeah, sorry, I missed that your edit happened before the question was closed. About adding tags: Try to fix all other issues you find too (like typos, capitalization, code formatting, ...) and make sure that the tag is really relevant.

Comment: @sk_pleasant as long as the edit addresses all the other problems with the post (like removing noise, fixing formatting, etc) or if the post is perfect otherwise, yes. Oh, I see I am the echo today :)