# Should this question be edited, closed or what?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, editing-help

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620531/maven-pointing-to-jre-instead-of-jdk) seems to be a mess (even if it's quite upvoted) and I can't decide on how to proceed. It has at least following issues:

- it is not explaining the actual problem in a meaningful way, just "maven isn't building my .war file correctly"
- it is focused on output of `mvn -version`s Java home output, which is completely unrelated. (The confusion seems to stem from Mavens confusing way of printing `Java home`, which I clarified in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279586/java-home-in-maven).)
- it was asked in 2013, so there's *probably* no way to get more information about the situation
- the problem won't *probably* help anybody else - though it might, if the question were more clear
- the accepted answer says that `java.home` property should be changed, which is untrue as it *cannot* be changed directly. It can be changed only trough JAVA_HOME, which seems in this case to be already correct making it unrelated to the issue

Should the question be edited so that unrelated Maven pointing... information is removed? Should it be closed based on non-repeatable problem? Or based on not containing enough information? Or just downvoted? Should something be done with the answers that wouldn't relate even to the question after editing? Even if question would be closed (and it probably should be), based on [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253077/should-we-edit-questions-that-will-be-definitely-closed), it might be worthwile to still edit it to make more sense - but I'm not sure how exactly.

--

the question just again [got a comment again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620531/maven-pointing-to-jre-instead-of-jdk/17620644?noredirect=1#comment44051438_17620644) by someone who is confused by the discussion, and yes, I would be too. I can't vote anymore since I've already voted on it and that has been declined. It irks me to have this kind of a question drawing attention for all the wrong reasons. I don't see how anybody going through the discussion would think that it makes sense as it is.

--

Update: there has been now ~4 months since asking for clarifications without any feedback, so it doesn't seem there would be any. I guess this question should be closed. (cannot do that myself, as I've already voted to close before, but hopefully rest of the community can)

--

Another update: I was now able to cast my close vote as "unclear what you're asking". I'd hope others would join me in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the OP a chance to fill in some of the blanks on the question; most notably, what errors they saw (this is important for others who might have a similar message), what workaround they tried, and other things.

[They're still somewhat active](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158730/jay) on the site, so you've got a *chance* to at least reach out to them in a comment.

As it stands though, I'd be tempted to close it as "unclear what you're asking".  There's simply not enough information to go off as it stands.

But at least give the OP a chance to fill in some info; give it a chance to be salvaged.  It *could* be a good question if it is given a chance.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this sounds reasonable.

Comment: Putting a question on hold doesn't prevent the asker from updating the question. My understanding is that the policy is 'close em quickly' and then if they get fixed up, great. If not, they get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely close the question as soon as possible as it is highly likely to confuse other users.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would call for closing that question out, but I would definitely ask the poster to update the question to reflect the new status. The information being given is good, and would be helpful to people who are having a similar issue. If they document all the steps they take in debugging the issue, future users can see all the possible causes, and go through the same process of elimination, thus saving a lot of work that has been done by others.