# Is it useful to edit a question I will vote to close?

Tags: discussion, edits, vote-to-close

Most questions that get closed have problems in addition to the close reason. (Spelling/grammar, code formatting, tag issues, etc.) If I'm voting to close a question, should I fix those other problems?

I think the advantage to editing is that it could help the OP get started with their own editing to improve the question to the point that it could be reopened (if there really is a worthwhile question in there somewhere), and the disadvantage to editing is that making the question look like less of a mess could prevent or delay the question from being closed as I believe it should be.

Are there other factors I should consider when deciding whether or not to edit, or is editing something I'm voting to close just generally considered to be a waste of time?

Comment: Sure, why not. Not only will it improve the question, it will bump it up on the active list so it can get closed/improved/answered faster.

Comment: @KevinB Why would you want to go out of your way to actively draw attention to crap questions, instead of questions that would actually merit it?

Comment: depends on how "crap" they are. If it *can* become non-crap, even if it would require the op including more information, i think it's worth it.

Comment: @KevinB So then, contrary to your first comment, you don't think you should always edit the question.

Comment: Of course not always, i didn't say always. It should only be edited if it can benefit from being edited.

Comment: @KevinB In response to the question, "should I edit questions I vote to close" you said, "Sure, why not", which implies that you should always edit them, and not "edit them if it's a salvageable question", which is what you said in your second comment.

Comment: Came here to ask this and saw your post. I think the usefulness lies in making it easier to tell if the close vote / flag is wise. When someone posts a 3 paragraph mumble bundle with no punctuation, it wastes the time of other users as they try to determine if the flag was justified. It does create a strange race condition, though- will the edit be approved first, or the flag?

Comment: If the question has a pending edit then it's important to deal with that before closing it. See my answer for details. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you feel the question is fundamentally likely to be salvaged into a good question, sure, feel free to improve it.  If it's not likely to actually be salvaged, you're just wasting your time at a minimum, and potentially the time of others, by polishing turds.

Comment: Though sometimes even _polishing turds_ makes them clearer to be such, and gets them removed faster (just from my guts and experience).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why go out of your way to provide extra attention to bad content, pushing out better content to do so?  If the goal is to get bad questions closed faster use appropriate tools for the job, such as the CV queue, rather than editing.

Comment: The question is about doing _both_ actions, not either one or the other.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, and I'm saying you shouldn't be pointlessly editing questions just to get them closed, even if you also close vote.  If you think it merits closure, vote to close it, but making pointless edits to draw attention from other questions to this bad question so you can hopefully get people to close it isn't productive.  Rather than performing a productive act and a harmful act, just perform the productive act..

Comment: I... don't see how this question is asking for that in the least bit.

Comment: @KevinB πάντα ῥεῖ said as much in his comment, which is what I was replying to.

Answer (score 18):

I find myself editing questions that I'm inclined to vote to close quite often.

If the formatting is so bad, that it's painful to read and with a few keystrokes I can improve the readability (and not an overall quality), I just do it.  It hardly improves the site, but spares some inconvenience for other readers/reviewers.

Comment: ^^^ pretty much this. If it took me like 5 minutes to dig through a wall of text and figure why it is close worthy, I rather spend a few more seconds to break it into readable paragraphs to save other reviewers time. Sometimes such a cleaning edit also helps to find how it can be salvaged but this is unfortunately rare

Comment: Interesting. I don't edit, but sometimes when it is the general language/structure of a question suggesting that I go for "unclear" I'm concerned I have no chance to "re-vote" if the thing is tidied by the OP but is still nonsense, so I don't attempt to close early. If it is clearly just rubbish I close it straight away, whatever it looks like.

Answer (score 8):

It's really up to you. Editing takes time. Your time is valuable. You need to decide whether it's worthwhile to use that valuable time to edit a post that you want closed.

I will note that one of two things will happen due to your editing: either the post will still need closing, or you will improve it to the point where it does not need closing. The latter is a wonderful outcome and is a worthy goal arguing in favor of editing in and of itself, but of course doesn't happen often. If on the other hand the former happens, it's highly unlikely your editing the post will fool people into thinking the post should remain open. Close-worthy problems are generally more structural than that. So you shouldn't worry too much about accidentally preventing a post from being closed when it should be.

One argument in favor of editing such posts (IMHO a very good one, and the reason I'm posting this answer) is that by editing the post, you have provided a clear example to the author of the post of what they *should* have done. Many people will ignore this guidance. Again, it's up to you to decide whether it's worth your time to try to help. But then that's the case for *all* of Stack Overflow. There are a lot of ungrateful, careless, lazy people visiting this site looking for other people to do their work for them. Yet, we still make an effort to try to help, knowing full well that even if the question is a good, well-presented one, our efforts may well go without any thanks or acknowledgement.

The point is that we're trying, and that some of the time we actually get the result we're hoping for.

One more time: it's really up to you. Only you can know how much patience and stamina you have for the often thankless job of trying to help other people on the Internet. But certainly it *can* be worthwhile to do so, and that includes editing a post that may be on its way to the trash bin. There is still something to be gained; if not the redemption of the post itself, then at least possibly the improvement of the author of the post.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's helpful. If it's a duplicate, I would avoid altering the wording too much, but the tags should always be edited if they are poor. This helps the question reach people in the CV queue.

Sometimes, questions stay open on the merit that they *seem* to be like they could be about programming. You could also leave a comment in that case, but edits bump the post. Of course, I can't stand trying to fix something that can't be fixed, so I don't edit blatantly off-topic things.

If the question is at least somewhat on-topic (meaning OP editing may fix it), then you have helped their question out. This makes the site a better place.

But you have also done something much bigger and better, you have helped the OP. Many people, especially those with English as a secondary language, greatly appreciate edits.

Answer (score 3):

#### tl; dr:

Don't edit a question after it's closed. And don't cast the final close vote on a question that has a pending edit requiring approval: clear that pending edit first.

---

If a bad question is on the verge of being closed but it has a pending edit requiring approval then it's a good idea to perform an edit action that will take it immediately out of the edit review queue. Otherwise, there's the risk that the pending edit will be approved *after* the question is closed, and that edit will automatically put the question into the reopen queue.

If the question is unsalvageable junk, then there's no point sending it to the reopen queue. And I guess there's the risk with borderline questions that robo-reviewers may vote to reopen it after a cosmetic edit makes it look nice and shiny. (Even if such questions don't get enough reopen votes, a positive reopen count slows down Roomba operation, IIRC).

However, I'm more concerned about questions that need to be closed but which are nevertheless potentially salvageable with some work by the OP. As I said above, editing a question after it's closed puts it into the reopen queue. But that *only* happens on the first edit, subsequent edits do **not** put the question into the queue.

So we don't want such questions entering the queue before the OP has had a chance to edit it themself. Not only does such premature queue entry waste reviewers' time, it also means that the question is unlikely to be re-opened in the event that the OP does actually salvage their question.

Answer (score -12):

Always edit; always improve the site.

Comment: even spam? *evil grin*

Comment: @KevinB Good catch, spam is special and you should never edit or comment it

Comment: On the contrary, spam should be edited by complete replacement so that it is drivel instead.

Comment: @Joshua NO!!! NO!!! NO!!! NO!!! Editing spam away means that it's won't get spam flagged to death and used to nuke the spammers account and IIRC train the automatic spam filters.