# Why doesn't Stack Overflow awards points on just answering questions?

Tags: feature-request, answers

Stack Overflow awards reputation when there is an upvote on your answer or if it is chosen as a best answer, but it doesn't award reputation just for answering.

I think there needs to be a reward (even if it is only 2 points) for answering questions. This will motivate the others to answer the question in their way, irrespective of if there is already an answer or not.

Comment: Why would it? What if the answer is **wrong**? Or someone posted spam? We should give them reputation for that? Can you imagine the number of terrible answers this would produce?

Comment: I believe there is always moderation for that.

Comment: The point is that would encourage people to post _anything_ everywhere they can to get magical rep. We do not want to encourage a flood of crap posts. That's a huge waste of moderation time.

Comment: What you are suggesting means that moderation will **not be able to keep up**.

Comment: As if the janitors (ah, moderators) don't have anything else to do.

Comment: Reputation is part of the moderation system. Giving away reputation like candy makes it meaningless and breaks moderation. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/476

Comment: I can't even tell if people are being serious with these proposals anymore. Whatever.

Comment: @BoltClock at least we can still get a good laugh out of it, yes? `:D`

Comment: You should accept @Cupcake's answer as that is the correct one.

Comment: @HeroFTime in case you're wondering, that's a joke. Plz don't accept my answer. I already got what I came for. That sweet, sweet rep `:D`

Comment: [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com) is a prime example of such a system in use. Enough said.

Comment: That would create a moral hazard and some might even spam the whole site to farm points or create a script/bot/whatever to do it automatically. This could also create a distributed DDoS unintentionally if a lot of devs start to do this. (worse case scenario)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Um, no. You get rep if you post an answer *and it is correct/good/worthwhile*. You should not get rep for posting an answer that is not helpful in any way shape or form. Seems pretty obvious.

In fact, people are answering *too much*. In particular, people are quick to answer extremely low-quality questions, thereby encouraging them and contributing to [a significant downturn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/560648) in SO's general awesomeness.

Answer (score 47):

Can I has rep plz? KTHKS :-======))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Should I get rep for this?

Comment: Of course, you should.  Here you go!

Comment: For making the point? Sure.

Comment: I feel like downvoting for the sms lingo, though.  (I know it's deliberate.)

Comment: Don't forget that it's URGENT.

Comment: It's too bad MSO imbues you with no rep whatsoever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Offering a bounty wouldn't help either.  Would it?

Comment: @devnull: I guess not

Comment: [Why was this answer downvoted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive)

Comment: Here you go sir...

Answer (score 29):

Haha, [@Mat's answer is great](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253236/456814)! I would just like to expand on it by posting another answer.

Comment: I would like to take this opportunity to comment.

Comment: @Mat I would like to upvote your comment, except I wasted all of my upvotes on [the other comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253233/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-awards-points-on-just-answering-questions/253241#comment12493_253236) `:P`

Comment: 

Comment: IMHO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Cupcake Why not [ask a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead?  I haven't exhausted my comment and post upvotes yet :P

Comment: @Mat Your comment is not constructive.

Comment: [Why was this answer downvoted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive)

Answer (score 14):

Did you know that you can post more than one answer to a question? 'Cause I just did. More rep plz! :D

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you with a comment.