# Is moderator removal of comments requesting clarification of downvotes a thing now?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731884/do-amd-loaders-need-a-way-to-initiate-module-resolution-other-than-define) and it got a downvote, so I posted a comment requesting clarification, hoping to learn what was wrong with my question so it could be improved.

Later, I came back and the comment was gone. I've added the comment again.

Is removal of this type of comment a thing now, or was that just some weird anomaly?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive

Comment: @Habib, thanks... looks like overwhelming support for these comments being constructive. I wonder why someone would remove it.

Comment: I have seen those comments getting removed and I don't agree with that policy.

Comment: There is a point that can be made about such comments being downvote magnets. For instance, if you have a blatant, obvious error in your question and naively ask "why?" when you get downvotes, chances are you will get more. In this situation, removing the comment can be seen as a service to you.

Comment: Telling about the obvious error would be the best service.

Comment: Just downvoting because someone doesn't know what's wrong is a bit.. unreasonable, isn't it?

Comment: Might not be a moderator thing though. Might simply have been flagged as not-constructive.

Comment: @Bart 200+ people think it's constructive. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive

Comment: @Bart are you saying that flags can automatically remove comments? I thought a moderator had to do that.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying. Not single flags however. I don't know the exact count necessary though.

Comment: I think 6. Searching ...

Comment: @Bart pretty sure that wasn't the case here, the question barely had over 6 views at the time

Comment: Fair enough, could still be a moderator then I guess. But disappearing comments in general are not necessarily a moderator action.

Comment: @Bart you might be mixing this up with spam / offensive flags. these do remove after 6 flags and raise a mod-flag (IIRC)

Comment: @Trilarion: Some peaople think it is an indication the OP actually cares. Others think it's just noise. Most probably no longer participate in such meta-posts at all.

Comment: Not sure if "not constructive" flags have the same effect @Vogel612.

Comment: @Vogel612: no, enough flags of other types also result in auto-deletion.

Answer (score 34):

Deleting noise has been a "thing" for years. And this is noise:

> Downvoter, could you please explain the reason for your downvote? If this question can be improved, let me know how to improve it

Your question currently sits at +5, with 6 upvotes and 1 downvote - the vast majority of people who've voted on your question thus far have considered it useful. The *one person* who downvoted it won't be notified of your comment and is unlikely to return and see it.

Worse yet, if someone actually *did* have a useful comment, yours is taking up the 5th slot on the question, meaning it would be hidden by default.

So someone flagged it and a moderator removed it.

I've gone further and removed *all* of the comments, since at this point none of them are still relevant. This makes room for any future commentary, should any be needed. Remember, [comments are temporary...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: Thanks for removing those other comments, I agree they were no longer useful. Now that those other "hot slots" are free, I'd like to put back the comment requesting clarification of the downvote, in case that person does come back, so I can figure out how to improve the question.

Comment: Why? As I said, there's little chance the voter will even return... And if he does, *he already knows he's downvoted* - the system indicates this without your assistance. If you have doubts about some part of your question, the place to raise those concerns is *in your question itself* - don't fixate on the voting, focus on the question.

Comment: Maybe you're misunderstanding the nature of my comment. It wasn't supposed to inform the downvoter that they had downvoted, it was to *request clarification on the nature of the downvote* so I could improve the question. The only doubt I have about the quality of the question was raised by the fact that a downvote was cast, so ideally, I'd like to hear what it is that person thinks is wrong with it, and if I agree that it's a problem, I can fix it.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: Basically to sum it up, don't do that. That's what Shog9 is telling you. It is noise. Buck up and move on.

Comment: @staticx I'm not convinced it's noise. As I understand it, the purpose of comments is to seek clarification of questions and answers. If the comment were answered, by the downvoter or anyone else, with something indicating why the question could be perceived to be of low quality, then the question could be clarified and improved. At that point both comments would be noise and should be removed.

Comment: You don't have two comments though, @Dagg - you have *one*. One which offers no information and poses a question to someone who isn't there to read it. If some future reader sees a problem with your question, perhaps he will comment - you could certainly invite feedback in your question - but there's no value in commenting to address an anonymous departed downvoter.

Comment: @Shog9 are you suggesting that if I amended the question with something like "I see this question garnered a downvote, if anyone has ideas about how to improve it, let me know," that would be less noisy than a comment? To me that seems like something better suited to a comment since it's *about* the question rather than *part of* it.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: You got one downvote and 2 favorites. What is wrong with your question? Asking for feedback wouldn't help. People will provide if necessary

Comment: @staticx I have no clue what's wrong with it, that's why I left the comment in the first place. How do you know asking for feedback won't help? I've had people ask "why the downvote" on questions I downvoted, and I let them know why.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm suggesting, @Dagg - I'm suggesting you forget about the vote. If you're interested in suggestions for improvement, [focus on *that alone*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post/37123#37123) - but really, I don't think you've any reason to spend more energy on it; your question has been largely well-received - if *you* don't see the need to make further changes, then (unless someone volunteers a suggestion) why worry about it?

Comment: @DaggNabbit: No, what I am saying is why is this even an issue in the first place? You have tons of rep and you should know by now that asking for reasons for downvoting is not encouraged. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252906/2591612

Comment: @staticx I had no idea it was discouraged. I rarely use SO any more; the only reason I posted this there was because I hoped to get feedback from certain people, one of whom saw it and answered. I certainly don't hang out on meta.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: I will have to take your word for it but you have been a member for over 4 years.

Comment: @staticx check my recent activity. The quality of questions and answers on the site has gotten progressively worse over time. Anyway, this entire time there has been a distinct pattern of people asking for clarification of downvotes, and many times they do get answered.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: Yes, I saw that you have been sporadically active the past seven months. Just because people ask for clarification, doesn't mean that those comments don't eventually get deleted. I have flagged comments from years ago that just got removed yesterday. It shouldn't set any sort of precedence.

Comment: @staticx deleting six year old comments is one thing, deleting a comment the *day it was made* is another. If someone leaves a comment on their own question, maybe it's there because they think it has a chance of helping them and should be left alone.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: It has about much chance as being answered as asking a random person on the street on NYC

Comment: Well, I'm not going to argue about this any more. You guys do what you like, flag and delete away. I just wanted to know if this deletion was becoming a pattern or just a freak occurrence. Now I know.

Answer (score -21):

Yes, apparently it's a thing now.

As Habib pointed out, this type of comment has been discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/). He also indicated noticing a pattern of removal of these comments. The community seems to be in overwhelming agreement that such comments are in fact constructive, but of course there are those that disagree and consider them to be "noise."

C'est la vie.

Comment: The wonders of statistics. One day 200 think something is constructive, the next day 10 think it isn't.

Comment: @Trilarion this answer was designed to farm downvotes using my mad meta reverse psychology skills. Being a thing is bad, and it needs to have downvotes to reflect the badness.

Comment: There are many thousands of meta readers, @Trilarion - and many more Stack Overflow users. Voting is best taken with a grain of salt; often how an opinion is phrased matters more than what the opinion actually states.

Comment: Asking why someone downvoted in a comment is a waste of time.  The downvoter doesn't get notified, and since voting is anonymous, he has no obligation to respond anyway.  I personally never respond to requests for clarification of my downvote, since it almost always leads to an argument.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have responded to every single one that I've seen. For those people, it wasn't a waste of time. I don't believe it ever started an argument, either.

Comment: Good for you.  You're apparently an outlier.

Comment: @RobertHarvey maybe, maybe not. It would be interesting to run a search for comments matching "why downvote" and take a sample of how many had some response, either from the downvoter or from someone else explaining possible reasons for downvotes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey another thing that doesn't make much sense is the conflicting arguments that the downvoter will never see the message and that it almost always leads to an argument. If it almost always leads to an argument, the downvoter almost always sees the message. If the downvoter almost never sees the message, it should almost never lead to an argument.

Comment: Now you're reaching for straws.  The purpose of Stack Overflow is to get answers to programming questions, not debate endlessly about votes, comments on votes, explanations about comments on votes, or moon phases.  *They're all irrelevant to the primary mission.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey how am I reaching for straws? Please explain how these two arguments can logically co-exist.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah, I didn't think so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey anyway, regarding the "primary mission" of SO, the point of my comment was to develop an idea of what was wrong with the question, so that it could get better answers. To that end, I think my goals were in line with the "mission." The mission of meta seems to be a different one entirely. I simply wanted to know whether the deletion of these comments was a pattern or a one-off thing, and look where it got us.

Comment: Yeah, it got us into a lengthy and protracted discussion that far exceeds the importance (or lack thereof) of that single downvote.  Time to move on.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you're still missing the point. This post wasn't about that downvote. It was about the *deletion* of downvote comments.

Comment: @Shog9 This is also my impression. Unfortunately SO makes everything so dependent on the voting score (for example if something is shown in black or in gray) but seeing such inconsistencies in voting behavior - makes the focusing on scores a bit silly. We could discuss the same topic tomorrow and probably would end up with a different order of answers.

Comment: Meta is probably the single best argument against allowing open-ended / subjective questions on SO, @Trilarion ;-) That said, you do here what you do in any discussion forum: you read the responses and make up your own mind.

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey's first comment.  My latest (read: one of my few) explanations behind a downvote lead to [this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265664/questions-regarding-popular-tools-like-github), complete with someone calling me a name for stating my interpretation of SO's policies against the mentioned question.  Now I know to *really* think before explaining a downvote.

Comment: @Jamal, thank you for explaining your thinking instead of throwing silent "me too" votes around. In my opinion, the viewpoints that downvoters rarely see such comments and that such comments often start an argument with the downvoter are conflicting, as I mentioned earlier. It could be one way or the other (or neither), but not both.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: It's still not something I would consistently do, especially if it's quite clear that the question is horrible (such as a gimmetehcodez question).  I *could* still explain downvotes when something useful could come out of it, but most of my downvotes are for real crap anyway.  And I don't think I need to explain each of those.