# Action to take when a certain user has a fundamental misunderstanding of the norms on SO

Tags: discussion

***Edit***: The question [Is asking reasons for downvote in comments non-constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826) is not a duplicate. It discusses whether querying the reason behind downvotes is a legitimate move (which I would agree with, as it **is** constructive most of the time), something this question does indeed reference, but does not investigate.

*The main topic here is a case where asking for a reason behind a downvote happened in an obviously unaccepted way, and it implied a fundamental misunderstanding of the norms here.*

*These two are completely different discussions.*

---

This is happening now, as I'm writing the question.

### Summary:

1. User of 3 days posted a low-quality, also *slightly* off-topic answer regarding the question (but on-topic regarding tags),
2. When faced with downvotes, user went on a modest rampage (most of which has been cleaned up by now):

> Mine is definitely the easiest one and will 100% work. [...]
>   Bunch of salty dudes here who don't know basic jquery. Hilarious. [...]
>   heyyy keep downvoting me because your old and have terrible suggestions for this guy. [...] Remove the down vote now.

I'm interested to hear the adequate course of action here, as this is the indication of a fundamental misunderstanding of what the deal should be on SO, IMO something a Flag will hardly improve on. I could Flag all of these comments, but I fail to see how it would remove the behavior.

### Additional thoughts

Regarding flags, I certainly wouldn't find this *offensive*, and I'm also not sure unaccepted behavior such as this should mean the removal of an otherwise contributing user.

Now otherwise I wouldn't find this a concern, but I'm getting notifications every minute from the same guy going on about how everyone in the world is wrong and he is right with utmost certainty.

**What should be done here?** Flag for moderator attention and move on? Try to start a discussion to smooth things out? (in my experience, the latter rarely leads to results)

---

**Edit** (cleaned up by now):

> Hence why this site sucks. Bunch of Jabronis on here [...] I have a suggestion. Go screw yourself. Deleting my account after the first day for this hack ass community.

Yeah, nevermind then......

Comment: Trying to reason out this behavior in the comments, usually doesn't lead to anything, and I'd avoid it. Just downvote the answer you think is bad, comment and move on.

Comment: @dingo_d I believe you are suggesting the immune-reaction of the SO community will naturally resolve this as time goes by, resulting in the mentioned user either leaving or learning to behave, without requiring any special course of action, right?

Comment: Please don't waste your time on discussions. Downvote the answer, flag comments as offensive and move on. Things will calm down once the nurse has raised the dosage of the medication ;)

Comment: I've removed the link to the post; there is no need to call in the mob here. Please leave this to moderators to clean up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it, I greatly appreciate your assistance -- it seems the mess is cleaned up by now.

Comment: @JohnWhite As Klaus Warzecha mentioned, you're basically wasting your time on discussions. The guy has some anger issues, you can't help it. Just let it die out on its own.

Comment: Looks like he took care of himself!

Comment: Point and laugh at them, offer mild mockery, then give 'em the ol' "good day to you sir"

Comment: If there's a fundamental misunderstanding of the norms, invite the user to chat if they have enough rep. Otherwise try to diplomatically explain it in as few comments as possible, mostly by pointing them to the Help Center, preferably. Of course once they turn ugly like that, just flag it and let it be. Such users are not interested in productive discourse on the internet.

Comment: this is why you should just never comment on down votes; ever.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: By "comment on down votes", do you mean "post a comment on a question or answer that you've downvoted", or "use a comment to explain a downvote", or "reply to a downvote by commenting on whether you agree with it", or . . . ?

Comment: So… Did anyone explained what's their `fundamental misunderstanding of the norms`? Because it seems to me that the user just were trying to get a comment on what's wrong, whilst people kept silently downvoting, which in turn led to the thought that it's something personal. Perfectly fine behavior of the answerer, and absolutely awful behavior of the downvoters.

Comment: sometimes they're really expecting an answer. working conditions, mood conditions and many other factors in which they are make them angry, just like every programmer. try to not vote down! this is sad because you just await an answer and you got down voted and banned of asking questions

Comment: @JarrodRoberson **I disagree. See edit: this question does not investigate whether asking for reasons behind a downvote is an accepted move, but merely references the case.**

Comment: @Hi-Angel I think it's the assumption that the answerer is familiar with the weight and reasoning behind negative feedback.

Comment: @JohnWhite yes, they definitely is. The reasoning is simple: they posted an answer, hence they sure that the answer is, at least, useful. Then they got a downvote: what do they do? What would you do? They leaving a comment of confusion about the accident. But instead of getting a comment with explanation they getting more and more downvotes. So: if the answer useful, but one is getting downvotes — it is definitely something personal! Hence, as their last comment stating, the site and the users sucks, and such.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I'm not so sure about the last part. I began my SO career with a triple-downvoted garbage answer, and I sure as hell didn't take it personally, but instead deleted it. Peer-pressure badge on the first day.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As of right now all the offending comments have been deleted, and the irrelevant rest has been cleaned up by a moderator.

For future reference, don't engage in such a back and forth.

Just leave it at your original explanation (even that is optional), flag offensive comments as offensive, flag unconstructive comments as non-constructive, and ignore the rest. It's not worth it to waste your time trying to reason with someone who has no desire to be reasoned with.

They will either learn on their own or eventually quit.

Edit, an excellent deeper explanation as to why by [Peter Duniho](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho):

> To elaborate just a bit: people who behave like that are potentially trolling, and at the very least immature. Engaging them directly on their behavior just rewards them with undeserved and counterproductive attention. The recommendation here to do basic community filtering (flagging, moderation, etc.) is the best approach, as it fixes the basic content issues without risking encouragement of the problematic behavior that caused the content issues.

Comment: Yes, it was my impression as well not to go full Rambo on him, even considering the greater community. Either way, the mess seems to have been cleaned up by now, either by a moderator (thank you) or the user himself.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: To elaborate just a bit: people who behave like that are potentially trolling, and at the very least immature. Engaging them directly on their behavior just rewards them with undeserved and counterproductive attention. The recommendation here to do basic community filtering (flagging, moderation, etc.) is the best approach, as it fixes the basic content issues without risking encouragement of the problematic behavior that caused the content issues.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for the excellent deeper explaination. I added it to the answer with attribution.