# "Why downvoted?" comments - unfriendly according to the new Code of Conduct?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes, code-of-conduct

I'm sure all of us (or at least many of us) stumbled upon comments like this one

> The person who down-voted the answer, any explanation why ?

Many users, when their answer is downvoted, just either shrug it off and go about their business, or delete the comment, accurately thinking that if their answer got downvoted, then there must be something fundamentally wrong with it.

But then there are users who apparently take it personally and demand an explanation, which, unfortunately, they're not going to get (at least from me).

Usually, when I see the answer that is misleading or I know is not going to solve OP's problem, I comment on it, pointing out the flaws or asking for clarification.

But sometimes, there are answers that are *just wrong* on so many levels, that they're unsalvageable. One might try to comment on them, but you just know it's not going to get you anywhere. And pointing out *many* flaws in such answer will definitely be *unfriendly*. And usually, those are the answers that the author demands an explanation for the downvote.

So the question is: should comments demanding explanation for a downvote be considered *unfriendly*? In my opinion, they definitely should - I don't see why I should explain myself for using the privilege earned along with reputation, even more so to someone lacking the very basic knowledge about the topic.

Comment: ...pointing out flaws is **not unfriendly**...unless you are wrong.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's not unfriendly even if you are wrong (unless you're *intentionally* posting something you know is wrong to mislead people).  But pointing out flaws with a post will be treated as unfriendly by the mods, even though it's an entirely appropriate comment, so the concerns are, sadly, perfectly valid.

Comment: @servy The new code of conduct simply asks that we keep a friendly tone as we point out the flaws in a post. Nobody should have trouble doing that.

Comment: @Rainbolt Nobody should have trouble posting a comment that is widely considered appropriate, reasonable, professional, and not at all rude by the community at large.  Basically no one is capable of writing a comment that a mod will consider friendly enough to not delete (especially if it's in any way pointing out a flaw in anything), given the standards they hold comments to.

Comment: @Rainbolt Unfortunately... reality doesn't work that way.

Comment: @KevinB Well I think it should work that way, because pointing out mistakes in an answer is an important tool for helping people. I took this to main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314014/254466

Comment: ’ to someone lacking the very basic knowledge about the topic.' . I not agree with you. First questions on new topics are often full of pain because nothing works, and often user need to be pointed to right direction. Some days ago I asked about a problem with SSL and SSH, because I stupidly confused the 2 things. Instead of explain me my error and propose closing the question, I got downvotes. Yes. We need explanation. If you have power to downvote you have a bigger responsibility . My opinion.

Comment: For example, I am asking myself why this question is actually at -5. And I am not the author of the question. I do not learn nothing about meta specific code of conduct that the author is violating. So in this specific case downvoting has been no usefull for no one.

Comment: @realtebo From my observations: In meta specifically, voting is usually used to indicate agreement/disagreement rather than as an opinion about the quality of the post (although it can be used for that as well).

Comment: "take it personally": this is a very negative interpretation but it fits into the general mindset of SO. Try to look at it from a positive pov: how can anyone improve if they don't understand what they're doing wrong? SO is the hardest community on the internet to get into, it's frustrating on so many levels because of all that extensive nitpicking how questions are asked and answers given. Those who do the nitpickung should at least help people to understand why they think something was done wrong!

Answer (score 33):

They are still "no longer needed." They can also be unfriendly or rude/abusive, but they aren't always unfriendly or rude/abusive.

Answer (score 19):

> But then there are users who apparently take it personally and demand explanation,

Assuming that they "take is personally" is imputing a motive that I think is unwarranted.  With the same facts, it's possible to construct a much more generous narrative:

"But there are users who are interested in improving their answers and see the downvote as an opportunity for constructive feedback, and request an explanation"

You could probably make up other stories that fit the known data, so choosing one as "correct" seems like a mistake.

> which unfortunatelly, they're not going to get (at least from me).

It is unfortunate if it's a missed opportunity to pass on your knowledge.  I should say that's a big "if" - I'll concede that it can also be an opportunity to get into a pointless fight.

Comment: After the new CoC, it's no longer an opportunity; it's a risk.  There's very little incentive to actually pass on your knowledge now for bad questions.

Comment: Which part of the CoC makes this a risk?

Comment: That a pattern of them being flagged will make a mod think you're a problem, and suspend you.  I see no reason to even entertain it; just downvote, and move on.

Comment: _It is unfortunate if it's a missed opportunity to pass on your knowledge._ - I lost interest in trying to explain a downvote on a horribly wrong answer, when its author replied something along the lines of _my answer is fine, if you don't want to use it, it's your problem_

Comment: I think responding to "why the downvote" comments that appear to be expressed honestly, rather than just attacking the downvoter, can be useful... just don't forget to clean up the mess if it turns out to not be. YMMV

Comment: I have left "why the downvote?" comments in the past. About 50% of the time, I get an explanation and either retract the answer or improve it. Most of the time, improvements get my a flipped vote (from downvote to upvote). Usually when I downvote, I will leave a comment as to why, as specifically as possible, I have downvoted. It's really the only way to improve he community in general. Drive-by down-votes only change the order of the answers; they do not improve SO in general.

Comment: Don't conflate improving/helping users with improving SO.

Answer (score 9):

Your exact example is a question - nothing about it reads as unwelcoming.

> The person who down-voted the answer, any explanation why?

It is, in fact *welcoming* a response from users, inviting them to help improve the answer. While such comments are noise, they're not unfriendly. As others have said, flag as no longer needed. If you feel like responding to the comment (even if you weren't a downvoter) respond by explaining any problems with the post in a helpful way but avoid starting a discussion about downvoting itself.

If you're unwilling to explain, you needn't. We've been repeatedly requested to require explanations for downvotes and declined them because it's your choice how deeply you want to be involved in a particular post. If all you have the time to do is downvote, that's your call.

On the other hand, if the comment read more like:

> - Would the geniuses who felt it necessary to downvote this perfectly correct answer be ever so kind as to explain themselves?
> - Screw the idiots who downvoted my glorious post without explaining - you should all be cursed to live next to a blooming [corpse flower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphophallus_titanum) for a year!

This is a notch up - at least - and may absolutely be flagged as unwelcoming or abusive (unwelcoming in the first case and abusive in the second). This isn't really a request for help improving the post so much as it's a complaint and on top of that it's attacking voters - potentially in an effort to get them to change their behavior, which often has the opposite response.

The thing we'd encourage you all to keep in mind is that every new interaction can go either way but it'd be appreciated if everyone remembers to assume good intentions. A neutral phrasing like what you've suggested can open a dialogue into improving the post that the OP actually participates in and learns from or a response could be met with vitriol like in my examples but, until that happens, don't presume the latter based on prior experience with other users.

Comment: I agree. Personally I would interpret "why the downvotes" as "please give me guidance on how to improve this post" unless there's a clear sign of rudeness. It is not only for the downvoter to reply to, but also anyone else who might be able to shed light on the subject.

Comment: ^ Agree with jrh's comment. *Often* I see a response (or myself respond): `I'm not the downvoter but you can improve your post by ...`. We have to remember comments aren't for conversation or personal disagreements, they are for improving Q&A.

Answer (score 6):

## Those comments are *noise*.

They're no longer needed since you have no obligation to come back and justify how you voted.  Flag them accordingly.

Comment: You've assigned an intention to an action, without knowing if that's the true intention.  The intention might not be a demand for justification.  Many genuinely want to know what about their answer others may find objectionable.  There's plenty of cases that improvements to an answer have been made with such feedback.  Improvement requires a feedback loop.

Comment: What are you on about @AaronLS?  Those kinds of comments have *always* been noise.  If they want to discuss their question they can come to Meta to do so.  If you want those vehicles to be made more obvious, propose suggestions to make those vehicles more apparent to the casual passer-by.

Comment: @Makoto That's a matter of opinion. My opinion has always been that downvoting should *require* an explanatory comment, or downvoting should be eliminated entirely.

Comment: @TKK:  No, this [has been standing policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252906/1079354) for a *long* time now.  Also, [you're never going to see forced commenting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question), *ever*.  Neither of those things are opinions.  Both of them are standing policy.

Comment: @Makoto Standing policy can and frequently does differ from the majority opinion of the user base.

Comment: @TKK:  It hasn't in four years and it ain't likely to budge now, so can we not go off on a tangent to beat a dead horse?

Comment: @TKK Mandatory comments is basically only ever suggested by people with almost no experience using the site at all.  Just about everyone with even a moderate amount of experience on the site is able to clearly see how harmful it would be, and so doesn't support it.

Comment: @Makoto "What are you on about @AaronLS? ... If they want to discuss their question they can come to Meta to do so."  What are **you** on about?  Comments are absolutely an appropriate place for discussing improvements to a question or answer. It's doesn't need to be taken to meta unless it is a question of whether it is being moderated correctly or issue of policy at hand.  **Simple things about addressing downvotes with a response of "It's not clear if you've debugged, please provide results of inspecting local variables when you step through code" don't need an entire meta post.**

Comment: @Servy So different people's opinions carry different weight now? Glad you're making that explicit. (And FYI, this isn't my main account.)

Comment: `Those kinds of comments have always been noise.` To you, sure. Me, I've benefited massively from feedback I've specifically requested. As a result, I've improved answers, many of which have been subsequently well received. Better Q&A -> Better SO.

Comment: @AaronLS:  I maintain that those kinds of comments are noise.  You're not saying anything to convince me otherwise; you're only reinforcing my position given that you state yourself that comments are an appropriate place to discuss improvements.  Given the temporal nature of comments, we really need to get past using them as *the* means to give feedback.  But this does mean that the system lacks a proper mechanism for it, and so we should be bugging Tim Post until he provides one. :)

Comment: @jpp:  I don't know why you think I'm conjuring policy out of thin air.  [It's been this way for a *while*.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252906/1079354)  You may have personally benefit from a commentator obliging your request, but under no circumstance does that mean that the comment is guaranteed good and safe.

Comment: @Makoto, Policy is an action with respect to an input. Think of it like a machine. "It's noise" is an opinion, and anyone and their dog can have an opinion. We shouldn't conflate the two.

Comment: @TKK Sure. Why would you think everyone's opinion on everything should have the same weight?  Someone giving an entirely uninformed opinion on a topic they're not actually familiar should have their opinion treated differently than someone who's actually knowledgeable about the thing they're expressing an opinion about.

Comment: @Servy I think you're conflating opinion in the sense of personal preference with opinion in the sense of a professional opinion. The latter can be objectively weighted; the former cannot.

Comment: @TKK I didn't say that opinions and knowledge are the same thing.  I said that the opinion of someone more knowledgeable about the subject they have an opinion on has an opinion that should be given more weight.  For example, my opinions on the best movie that came out this year should be given very little weight, as I haven't seen many recent movies, or my opinions on how Reddit or Facebook should manage its rules, as I don't really use either, and so my views on how they should work, or how it should be changed, rightly shouldn't mean much to people making decisions there.

Comment: @Servy How the site *does* work is a subject that a person can be quantifiably knowledgeable about. How the site *should* work is not. The people making decisions *can* assign different weights to opinions about how the site should work, but to do so would not be rational unless they intend to maximize something other than utility.

Comment: @TKK: I think the point Servy is trying to make is that with 300 points, one only knows a very limited subset of SO, namely the writing questions/answers/comments side. But people at that reputation level have zero experience in moderating the site which makes it hard to impossible to judge which consequences changes to the site will introduce. Most of the points why mandatory commenting on down-votes is not seen as a good idea is covered in this [FAQ post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin).

Comment: @BDL:  To play Devil's Advocate, they claim that this isn't their main account.  However, the point does stand - there are people with high reputation (north of 30K) who haven't used the site's moderation functionality to its fullest, and as such, would be at odds with some of the policies and goals that the tooling is meant to address.

Comment: @Makoto: Sorry, I didn't wanted to say that high rep users per-se will know how the site works to its smallest detail. I just wanted to say that with a very low rep, it is usually impossible to know them. So if someone can logically explain why something is a bad idea, then this should be considered. (I just realized that I sound like my grandfather when he was claiming that we should believe older people because they know better :) )

Comment: @Makoto "you're only reinforcing my position given that you state yourself that comments are an appropriate place to discuss improvements"  Glad we're in agreement that comments are the appropriate place to discuss improvements.  That's the only thing you could mean by that, because if your position is counter to mine, then my position doesn't reinforce your position.  Unless we're in a alternate dimension where nothing makes sense.

Comment: @AaronLS:  Yes, let's go ahead and interpret what is a typo as us agreeing.  I'll do you a favor and agree to disagree from here on out.

Comment: @BDL FWIW I disagree with "that with a very low rep, it is usually impossible to know [how the site works]", I've been on this site for years, and I've read tons of meta topics, I just prefer to only answer questions I find organically through searching (the front page workflow doesn't interest me), and as per meta consensus (that I don't really agree with), I only ask for information I can't find anywhere else.

Comment: Also regarding this answer itself, I might be inclined to post a "why did you downvote" comment on a question in a low activity tag; a question with a low score is a roomba target, and if I actually put effort into the post and tried to document something and make it helpful I'd be a bit disappointed if that effort was lost without really any justification because of one downvote, FWIW. Though to be fair this is a complaint I've had about SE for a while (especially with selfie Q/A). I'm more alright with answer downvotes because answers don't get auto-deleted.

Answer (score 3):

### I do that *sometimes* when I get a downvote

Not often, but yes, sometimes in cases where I'm quite sure I provided a good answer *or* when I'm actually not aware of what could be wrong with the answer and would honestly like to know. I usually delete the comment if I don't get a response within minutes.

An example of the second case that happened recently: I posted an answer on a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) question and I got an immediate downvote. I was surprised as I thought my answer was valid! I asked for a clarification and I got a simple one (The question was also about [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and I wasn't aware that C++ doesn't support Lookbehinds by default), so I thanked the person who replied and immediately deleted the answer.

So, my own thoughts:

- **It's not unfriendly or rude** unless it has an aggressive tone or *is* actually abusive.
- **It's not *always* "no longer needed":**  It can be useful sometimes. I personally wouldn't flag it unless it's been sitting around for a while (e.g., over 24 hours).

Sometimes when I see a downvote and someone is asking for a clarification, I try to help them if I know what's wrong with the answer, and yes, some people do appreciate the feedback and act accordingly.

If the comment is not aggressive and the answer does show some effort, just let it be :)

However, if the author [doesn't seem to *actually* be looking for a clarification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372374/why-downvoted-comments-unfriendly-according-to-the-new-code-of-conduct#comment620095_372380), then that's different.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how a comment that says something like: "Downvoter, if you can provide some feedback, perhaps I can improve my answer" is technically "no longer needed".  Particularly, only 20 minutes after it's posted.  I've gotten actually feedback from the downvoters before AND improve the answer based on it so that was certainly not "no longer needed".  Sure, the downvoter "may" be long gone and never see the comment so if the comment remains un-responded to several days later, then the comment is probably no longer useful (that's true of lots of comments, btw).

Answer (score -4):

I find that

> The person who down-voted the answer, any explanation why?

is usually an invitation for venting and hostility from both the asker and anyone that feels inclined to answer. These comments are quite unfriendly and places anyone willing to answer on the back-foot; they should be flagged.

---

However, If the asker were to phrase it differently then things are much more likely to have a civil result. For example if I saw:

> I see my post is receiving downvotes but I am unsure why. Can anyone guide me as to what other information is expected of me?

then I would feel guilty to pass up the opportunity to help that person out instead of flagging.

Comment: The thing here is, you're not really answering the question as stated.  Whether or not you'd respond to a comment asking for clarification on why someone was downvoted is *irrelevant* to the matter of if those comments at all are against the CoC.

Comment: @Makoto I can see how my answer to the question was missed. Does the edit help?

Comment: It now answers the question.  I do still find myself respectfully disagreeing with your stance.  Irrespective of the tone, it's still noise.