# Thank you comments should be deemed "not constructive" pretty much like _work on your accept rate_ comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, not-constructive, etiquette

Quoting from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252765/2235132)<sup>1</sup>:

> This comment was flagged as Not Constructive and it was deleted
>   instantly because it contains the word accepting.
>
> Comments with the word accept and its variations are removed when
>   flagged due to the high number of comments we used to get that stated
>   "Work on your accept rate." or "Please work on accepting answers
>   because you accept rate.... sucks".

Could we have a similar *feature* for "Thank you" comments?  It's a nuisance to see comments on all answers in a post:

- Thank you.  This is exactly what I wanted.
- Your solution works well too.  Thank you.
- Thank for for the answer, but I've chosen the other one.
- Thank you, it works.

It'll be great if a *not constructive* flag on such comments could act like a *magic wand* and make this disappear.

<sup>1 Don't attempt to flag [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252761/my-comment-was-removed-is-it-moderation-activity/252765#comment9746_252765), it'll be *declined*.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I was going to ask the same question.

Comment: I expect it was downvoted because someone disagrees that this is a feature request that should be implemented.

Comment: There is nothing more nonconstructive than Not Constructive comment flags.

Comment: @Will Then the reason to flag comments such should go away!

Comment: @devnull: That's my opinion!  We're Opinion Bros!

Answer (score 22):

Accept rate related comments weren't added to the black list just because they were noisy and slightly annoying to run into.  They were added to the blacklist because they were actively destructive, to a rather profound degree, due to the frequency with which users were being badgered for not accepting answers.  People were being driven away from the site because of this behavior.

People are not being driven away from the site due to "thank you" comments posted.

It's also worth noting that it's not unheard of for comments to include the phrase "thank you" while not being strictly noise.  People post comments of the form, "Thank you for taking the time to answer, but this answer doesn't account for [...]."

If you want to flag the comments as being too chatty, you can.  I'm not sure if a mod will actually delete them or not (I would expect not, in most cases), but even if they would, these comments are not so bad that it warrants blacklisting them.

Comment: Just to add some [hard numbers](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/191740/248051/count-of-thank-you-comments#resultSets), the amount of comments that are just "thank you" is quite small.

Comment: I would only add that one of the reasons we have a comment system is to have a place for things like "thank you" to go, so that we can keep them out of questions and answers.

Comment: "People were being driven away from the site because of this behavior" - what? how can you determine that? I really can't see how such a comment would possibly "drive someone away". In general I agree with your answer, but this statement seems not very accurate.

Comment: @BartoszKP How are you so sure that it's *not* possible?  You weren't even a member of the site at the time.  There were lots of people clearly indicating, both in posts themselves, and through other forms of feedback such as meta, that they were very bothered by comments about accept rates.  It really was a very serious problem and evidence showed that people really were leaving over it.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say that I'm sure it's not possible. I was just asking, if it's possible, for the *evidence* you speak of.

Answer (score 2):

Having a question full of "thank you's" can be annoying for someone who want to dive straight into the issue and an eventual clarification in the comments.

But to ban thank you's alltogether wouldn't suit my personal preferences. It would make the satisfaction of posting less of a gain for me. The feeling of having helped someone(sometimes even months after a post) makes me happy and keeps entertained with answering questions and the like. Its that bit of social satisfaction.

But I do agree that the "thank you that resolved my issue!" can become spammy. Maybe a thanks this helped great! button of which the results are only shown to the poster of the answer/question via a notification.

That way the main site stays clean, but a the person who answered can still get some satisfaction know he helped someone.

Why not the upvote button? The upvote button is usually an idicator of correctness of the post, usufullness etc... it doesn't really serve a use as a "thank you" measurement.

Comment: In my opinion, 1 thank you comment is fine, and I agree it feels very rewarding as the answerer. 2 is tolerable, but 3+ should probably be flagged as too chatty and some of them removed (providing they don't provide other relevant information).

Comment: Hence my idea for a button. That way the answers can stay clear